# Avoid implicit 'any' type when using Object.keys in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an Object with keys that I've typed and I want to loop over it and maintain their type, avoiding "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 'ContactList' has no index signature".

I know this has been discussed at length on Typescript's GitHub pages but I haven't found any solutions for what I'm trying to do here. Trying it both with enums and with unions, but I still get the error.

Example with enums ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20Names%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Joe%2C%0D%0A%20%20Bill%2C%0D%0A%20%20Bob%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ContactList%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%20in%20Names%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20contactList%3A%20ContactList%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BNames.Joe%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5BNames.Bill%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5BNames.Bob%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.keys(contactList).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(contactList%5Bname%5D)%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A))

```
enum Names {
  Joe,
  Bill,
  Bob
}

type ContactList = {
  [key in Names]: {
    isFriend: boolean;
  }
}

const contactList: ContactList = {
  [Names.Joe]: {
    isFriend: true,
  },
  [Names.Bill]: {
    isFriend: false,
  },
  [Names.Bob]: {
    isFriend: true,
    },
};

Object.keys(contactList).forEach(name => {
    // turn on 'noImplicitAny' and get error
    console.log(contactList[name])
})
```

Example with unions ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Names%20%3D%20'joe'%20%7C%20'bill'%20%7C%20'bob'%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ContactList%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20Names%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20contactList%3A%20ContactList%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20joe%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20bill%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20bob%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isFriend%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.keys(contactList).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(contactList%5Bname%5D)%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A))

```
type Names = 'joe' | 'bill' | 'bob'

type ContactList = {
  [K in Names]: {
    isFriend: boolean;
  }
}

const contactList: ContactList = {
  joe: {
    isFriend: true,
  },
  bill: {
    isFriend: false,
  },
  bob: {
    isFriend: true,
    },
};

Object.keys(contactList).forEach(name => {
    // turn on 'noImplicitAny' and get error
    console.log(contactList[name])
})
```

Either way, I'm telling typescript "the only keys allowed in this object are from Names" and as far as I understand index signatures, `[key in Names]` should be one, so I'm not sure why I'm seeing an error. Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm a little green with TS still. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds weird... with the union you can write a workaround: `(Object.keys(contactList) as Names[])`. It doesn't work with the enum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `Object.keys` might return more properties than the object actually contains by type, the return type of it is [intentionally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870) typed as `string[]`. Otherwise, it would be pretty common for well-typed code to throw unexpected exceptions at runtime, as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012175/43848).

Therefore you have to make your index type work on strings:

```
type ContactList = {
  [key: string]: {
    isFriend: boolean;
  },
};
```

Or you typecast and hope for the best:

```
contactList[name as Names]
```

Also you could just:

```
console.log(...Object.values(contactList));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid opening it up to any ol' string. I want it to throw an error if something other than my approved "whitelist" of names is in there. (Also I know I could console.log the values in an easier way, this is just a contrived example. Ultimately going into a react project with .map)

Comment: @dramus sometimes it is difficult for typescript to wrap around Javascript's dynmic model.

Comment: If I declare up front that the only keys allowed on ContactList are Names, how can Object.keys() return anything other than Names?

Comment: @dramus `Object.prototype.whyThough = "idk";`

Comment: You might have some *subtype* of `ContactList` which has additional keys.

Comment: Hmm. What about `console.log(contactList[name as keyof ContactList])`? That seems to play nice with the enums, as long as I make them strings, like `Bill = 'bill'`. No errors then. Does that violate some other best practice though?