# Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Title says it all - why doesn't `Object.keys(x)` in TypeScript return the type `Array<keyof typeof x>`? That's what `Object.keys` does, so it seems like an obvious oversight on the part of the TypeScript definition file authors to not make the return type simply be `keyof T`.

Should I log a bug on their GitHub repo, or just go ahead and send a PR to fix it for them?

Comment: I opened and closed a PR today related to this topic.
My PR was only focusing on the case where keys are coming from an enum of strings. In this precise case, it does not seem that inheritance is feasible. I need to double check before reopening it https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30228

Comment: FTR: That ^ PR was never merged

Comment: This question/answer has some good info that is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70420283/990642

Answer (score 236, accepted):

The current return type (`string[]`) is intentional. Why?

Consider some type like this:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

You write some code like this:

```
function fn(k: keyof Point) {
    if (k === "x") {
        console.log("X axis");
    } else if (k === "y") {
        console.log("Y axis");
    } else {
        throw new Error("This is impossible");
    }
}
```

Let's ask a question:

> **In a well-typed program, can a legal call to `fn` hit the error case?**

The *desired* answer is, of course, "No". But what does this have to do with `Object.keys`?

Now consider this *other* code:

```
interface NamedPoint extends Point {
    name: string;
}

const origin: NamedPoint = { name: "origin", x: 0, y: 0 };
```

Note that according to TypeScript's type system, all `NamedPoint`s are valid `Point`s.

Now let's write *a little more code*:

```
function doSomething(pt: Point) {
    for (const k of Object.keys(pt)) {
        // A valid call if Object.keys(pt) returns (keyof Point)[]
        fn(k);
    }
}
// Throws an exception
doSomething(origin);
```

Our well-typed program just threw an exception!

Something went wrong here!
By returning `keyof T` from `Object.keys`, we've violated the assumption that `keyof T` forms an exhaustive list, because having a reference to an object doesn't mean that the *type of the reference* isn't a supertype of the *type of the value*.

Basically, (at least) one of the following four things can't be true:

1. `keyof T` is an exhaustive list of the keys of `T`
2. A type with additional properties is always a subtype of its base type
3. It is legal to alias a subtype value by a supertype reference
4. `Object.keys` returns `keyof T`

Throwing away point 1 makes `keyof` nearly useless, because it implies that `keyof Point` might be some value that isn't `"x"` or `"y"`.

Throwing away point 2 completely destroys TypeScript's type system. Not an option.

Throwing away point 3 also completely destroys TypeScript's type system.

Throwing away point 4 is fine and makes you, the programmer, think about whether or not the object you're dealing with is possibly an alias for a subtype of the thing you think you have.

The "missing feature" to make this *legal but not contradictory* is [Exact Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which would allow you to declare a new *kind* of type that wasn't subject to point #2. If this feature existed, it would presumably be possible to make `Object.keys` return `keyof T` only for `T`s which were declared as *exact*.

---

### Addendum: Surely generics, though?

Commentors have implied that `Object.keys` could safely return `keyof T` if the argument was a generic value. This is still wrong. Consider:

```
class Holder<T> {
    value: T;
    constructor(arg: T) {
        this.value = arg;
    }

    getKeys(): (keyof T)[] {
        // Proposed: This should be OK
        return Object.keys(this.value);
    }
}
const MyPoint = { name: "origin", x: 0, y: 0 };
const h = new Holder<{ x: number, y: number }>(MyPoint);
// Value 'name' inhabits variable of type 'x' | 'y'
const v: "x" | "y" = (h.getKeys())[0];
```

or this example, which doesn't even need any explicit type arguments:

```
function getKey<T>(x: T, y: T): keyof T {
    // Proposed: This should be OK
    return Object.keys(x)[0];
}
const obj1 = { name: "", x: 0, y: 0 };
const obj2 = { x: 0, y: 0 };
// Value "name" inhabits variable with type "x" | "y"
const s: "x" | "y" = getKey(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: However, there is common case when point 3. is excluded, when for example `T` is inferred and is guaranteed to be precise: `const f: <T>(t: T) => void = (t) => { Object.keys(t).forEach(k => t[k]) }`. I have lots of places like that in my code, where I really want `Object.keys()` to return (keyof T)[].

Comment: As arthem also points out, the confusion comes from the fact that 9 out of 10 times you will end up in some way using a type assertion to `keyof T` to do anything useful with the result of `keys`. You might argue it is better to be explicit about it so you are more aware of the risk you are taking, but probably 9/10 devs will just add the type assertion and not be aware of the issues you highlight ..

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue/comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208

Comment: Why can't `Object.keys<T>(c extends T obj)` simply filter the keys on obj (type c) returning keys of T?

Comment: Edited to address "What about generics though" comments.

Comment: I tried your first example, and typescript successfully caught the error, see [playground](tinyurl.com/yyyx9wy4) (playground url too long to paste into comment)

Comment: Uhhm, so apart from the great theory of TypeScript and typed systems, it is impossible to use `Object.keys` with objects, which represent an interface? We are forced to create pointless helper functions, which replace the infrastructure of our language?

Comment: I think this example is good but not very satisfying.

Comment: If anyone has actually been screwed up by type-casting Object.keys(foo) to Array<keyof typeof foo>, where the runtime value from Object.keys actually included more keys than were know at compile-time, Many people would love to see this code as an example. Please share it

Comment: Often, this is solely used to be able to loop through an object but that makes it impossible since ```Object.keys(product).forEach((key) => {
    // do something with product[key] but leads to error 'has type any because string cannot be used to query ...'
  });``` will lead to an error.

Comment: @jperl Exactly same issue here

Comment: I fixed my type issue with this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568423/typescript-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found-on-ty

Comment: Just to be clear, artem's example doesn't *guarantee* that `T` is exact, since the type parameter is still only inferred from the argument's compile-time type, which could be weaker than the object's runtime type.

Comment: Point 2 in your list: "A type with additional properties is always a subtype of its base type", is obviously the correct way to do it. If you ask for which members/properties a class has, you should obviously only get the properties which are defined for that class. And it's not a very good argument against point 2, to say that you uses an internal type system in TypeScript which doesn't support the  strongly-typed superset of JavaScript which TypeScript claim to be.

Comment: Is it possible TypeScript 4.9 could change this with [the satisfies operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator)? It seems like it's a way of guaranteeing an object isn't a superset of an Interface, meaning all Object.keys WILL be keyof the interface. e.g., `const origin = { name: "origin", x: 0, y: 0 } satifies NamedPoint` will refuse to compile, to use your example. Thoughts?

Comment: `satisfies` doesn't do anything to prevent aliasing with a supertype alias, which is the problem. You would need exact types to solve this "problem"

Comment: I'm always upset when @RyanCavanaugh comments on a subject I'm interested in, because it usually means I can't get the feature I want, and he always has a good reason. Good work on being the guardian of typescript that we need (but don't deserve)

Comment: We really need exact types.

Comment: But why the type of `Object.keys({'a': 1, 'b': 2})` is `string[]` and not `'a'|'b'`?

Comment: Because there isn't hardcoded special logic to handle that case (which you would never write in the first place)

Comment: What about for a plain object, not an interface? If I do `const myobj = {"foo": "bar"}`, typescript won't let me modify the keys. I can't figure out a way to extend/modify this in a way that if I did `Object.keys(myobj)` the keys wouldn't be `'foo'`

Comment: isn't there `as const` for this? I can write `const arr = [1, 2, 3] as const`, why isn't there a similar keyword for objects? It would be a perfect fit for this scenario, we could write `Object.keys(obj as const)` and TypeScript will know we are asserting that object to be constant

Comment: `const` doesn't imply sealed; you can have a value whose type matches an `as const`-asserted expression that still has other keys

Comment: Something that doesn't seem to have been mentioned is that JS allows any object to have arbitrary properties added to them at runtime. Even without the logical issues raised here, it would still not be possible to do a static check for the return value of `Object.keys`, since runtime code could have added unexpected properties to the objects.

Answer (score 44):

For a workaround in cases when you're confident that there aren't extra properties in the object you're working with, you can do this:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
const objKeys = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>
// objKeys has type ("a" | "b")[]
```

You can extract this to a function if you like:

```
const getKeys = <T>(obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>

const obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
const objKeys = getKeys(obj)
// objKeys has type ("a" | "b")[]
```

As a bonus, here's `Object.entries`, pulled from [a GitHub issue with context on why this isn't the default](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35101):

```
type Entries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]]
}[keyof T][]

function entries<T>(obj: T): Entries<T> {
  return Object.entries(obj) as any;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a change to typescript but I needed to add an "extends object":
`const getKeys = <T extends object>(obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;`

Comment: The problem is that you can't be "confident" that there aren't extra properties, because Javascript allows any object to have any property added at runtime. `Object.keys` is evaluated at runtime based on the properties present on the object instance, which could be anything, and that's why you have to explicitly cast `Object.keys` to turn off the warning. If you're relying on `Object.keys` returning a specific set of strings it's simply not possible to guarantee with a static type check and that's why it's not supported in TS.

Answer (score 16):

This is the top hit on google for this type of issue, so I wanted to share some help on moving forwards.

These methods were largely pulled from the long discussions on various issue pages which you can find links to in other answers/comment sections.

So, say you had some [code like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAvgbgFAHkkBTYKAOiLCgCcBLIiACgUQEoyAzEagUQENgAC0aMA2gGsiATwA0MAG58ANgFciAXVaoAfBlww4SCdPWoFytbkytsQA):

```
const obj = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  obj[key]; // blatantly safe code that errors
});
```

Here are a few ways to move forwards:

1. If you don't need the keys and really just need the values, use `.entries()` or `.values()` instead of iterating over the keys.

   ```
   const obj = {};
   Object.values(obj).forEach(value => value);
   Object.entries(obj).forEach([key, value] => value);
   ```
2. Create a helper function:

   ```
   function keysOf<T extends Object>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> {
     return Array.from(Object.keys(obj)) as any;
   }

   const obj = { a: 1; b: 2 };
   keysOf(obj).forEach((key) => obj[key]); // type of key is "a" | "b"
   ```
3. Re-cast your type (this one helps a lot for not having to rewrite much code)

   ```
   const obj = {};
   Object.keys(obj).forEach((_key) => {
     const key = _key as keyof typeof obj;
     obj[key];
   });
   ```

Which one of these is the most painless is largely up to your own project.

Comment: I recently banged my head against this and would like to toss one more option on to the heap: convert over to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It's a huge hassle to convert over to Map for supporting old code, but if you're writing something new, it's pretty easy to use it like the `Object.keys` pattern I -- and probably you if you're reading this -- was used to using. `const myMap: Map<SomeType, SomeOtherType> = new Map()`, then later loop over it with `myMap.forEach((val, key) => {... and TypeScript is happy here ...})`

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` has just the same issue 

Comment: Thanks! `Object.entries` is exactly what I needed to do instead. This isn't ranked nearly high enough.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution

```js
const isName = <W extends string, T extends Record<W, any>>(obj: T) =>
  (name: string): name is keyof T & W =>
    obj.hasOwnProperty(name);

const keys = Object.keys(x).filter(isName(x));
```

Comment: +1 but it's just stupid, that we need this workaround. `Object.keys` is already doing exactly that: "The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's *own enumerable property names* [...]" from MDN

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, so I wrote some typed functions.

Knowing that `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` return all keys as `string` I created a `ToStringKey` type:

```
/**
 * Returns the names of the _typed_ enumerable string properties and methods of an object.
 *
 * Note: Limiting Object.keys to a specific type may lead to inconsistencies between type-checking and runtime behavior.
 * Use this function when you are certain of the objects keys.
 */
export const getTypedKeys = Object.keys as <T extends object>(
  obj: T
  // Using `ToStringKey` because Object.keys returns all keys as strings.
) => Array<ToStringKey<T>>;

/**
 * Returns an array of _typed_ values of the enumerable properties of an object.
 */
export const getTypedValues = Object.values as <T extends object>(obj: T) => Array<T[keyof T]>;

/**
 * Returns an array of _typed_ key/values of the enumerable properties of an object.
 *
 * Note: Limiting Object.entries to a specific type may lead to inconsistencies between type-checking and runtime behavior.
 * Use this function when you are certain of the objects keys.
 */
export const getTypedEntries = Object.entries as <T extends object>(
  obj: T
  // Using `ToStringKey` because Object.entries returns all keys as strings.
) => Array<[ToStringKey<T>, T[keyof T]]>;

/**
 * Converts object keys to their string literal types.
 */
type ToStringKey<T> = `${Extract<keyof T, string | number>}`;
```

I do not recommend defining these method types globally. Create separate utility functions instead.

While TypeScript can infer and work with types, it cannot determine runtime-specific characteristics like enumerability.

Answer (score -1):

just do this and the problem is gone

```
declare global {
  interface ObjectConstructor {
    keys<T>(o: T): (keyof T)[]
    // @ts-ignore
    entries<U, T>(o: { [key in T]: U } | ArrayLike<U>): [T, U][]
  }
}
```

I added  // @ts-ignore because ts would tell me this:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol
```

If someone have a solution to get rid of // @ts-ignore without loosing the ability to preserve the dynamic aspect of T, let us know in the comments

If this breaks your code you can do:

```
Object.tsKeys = function getObjectKeys<Obj>(obj: Obj): (keyof Obj)[] {
 return Object.keys(obj!) as (keyof Obj)[]
}
// @ts-ignore
Object.tsEntries = function getObjectEntries<U, T>(obj: { [key in T]: U }): [T, U][] {
 return Object.entries(obj!) as unknown as [T, U][]
}
declare global {
 interface ObjectConstructor {
   // @ts-ignore
   tsEntries<U, T>(o: { [key in T]: U }): [T, U][]
   tsKeys<T>(o: T): (keyof T)[]
 }
}
```