# Typing reduce function which takes generics (noImplicityAny)

Tags: typescript, generics, reduce

I have a function which takes an object and converts its keys to snake cased strings and returns it. I'm using `reduce` to construct the new object but can't seem to resolve this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.ts(7017)

Which occurs on the line `return { ...o, [snakeCase(k)]: evt[k] };` stating that `evt[k]` has the `any` type. How do I resolve this? Are index signatures discarded because this is an empty object even though it has a type which has an index signature?

```
interface StringKeyMap<T> {
  readonly [key: string]: T[keyof T];
}

function snakeCaseKeys<T extends object>(evt: T): StringKeyMap<T> {
  const initial: StringKeyMap<T> = {};

  return Object.keys(evt).reduce<StringKeyMap<T>>((o, k) => {
    return { ...o, [snakeCase(k)]: evt[k] };
  }, initial);
}
```

Comment: which version of TS are you using?

Comment: and what is returning function `snakeCase`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the return type of `Object.keys(evt)` is `string[]` and not `Array<keyof T>`.  This is [intentional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012175/2887218), although a [lot](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15570) of [people](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15627) have [reported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870) this as an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15295).  Anyway, since `k` is just a `string`, then `evt[k]` is not considered safe, despite `k` coming from `Object.keys()`.

The easiest way to address this is via a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) somewhere so that `k` is treated as `keyof T`.  For example:

```
  return Object.keys(evt).reduce<StringKeyMap<T>>((o, k) => {
    const z =  { ...o, [snakeCase(k)]: evt[k as keyof T] };
    return z;
  }, initial); // no error
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: And this is the reason I still think the pragmatic thing to do is to type `keys` as `Array<keyof T>`... 9 out of 10 times (don't have actual metrics just gut feeling) you end up type asserting to `keyof T` anyway. Oh well :(