# Iterate through specified getter / setters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, getter-setter

I want to test the getters/setters on a JavaScript class I've written.  I'm testing my code with Jest.  For brevity I'm attempting to use the `test.each()` API provided by Jest.

Here's what I have so far.

The class:

```js
class MyClass {
  private _propName: string
  private _readOnlyProp: string

  get readOnlyProp() {
    return this._readOnlyProp;
  }

  set propName(v: string) {
    this._propName = v;
  }

  get propName() {
    return this._propName;
  }
}
```

And a test:

```js
// credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/56569217/675177
function hasKey<O>(obj: O, key: keyof any): key is keyof O {
  return key in obj;
}

test.each([
    ['propName', 'testValue'],
  ])('can get/set %s', (prop, value) => {
    const m = new MyClass();

    if (hasKey(m, prop)) {
      expect(m[prop]).toBeUndefined();
      m[prop] = value; // <= error!
      expect(m[prop]).toEqual(value);
    }
  });
```

TypeScript gives me the error:

`Cannot assign to 'readOnlyProp' because it is a read-only property`

Quite right!

What I want to do is filter just the writable properties (either programmatically or hard-coded), and then just test those.  Is it possible to adapt the hasKey function somehow to accommodate this?

P.S. You might wonder why I'm testing getters / setters.  It's because some of them have extra side effects that I haven't included the detail of above.

[Playground demonstrating the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oAcBOAlgG5gAuAptAPr4D2OAcmALbkBc0EphAdgOZZchEhWp5yYACYB5HiHgAFPPQ5deAwX3Klo4qbPlL6ACgCU6QdnGkArnh7RSACwIQAdFT0y5i5TgDcggC+GIIQ2kL0TKzGRKrcBPzmmNjYzq4edIwslAC80ESB2CGaEVnR5GYWqbradg7p7jR+FUXQISUAZjY8wKQEtA5OkADS5PAAPNIAfMa0AEYAVhzSADTQANbjHFvwtJ3QYDzwpjvj0K6b4-vQ0tW1tvZX8BcOC4uBJcCDXNCdtLRoPkeOQAO5wJAoCBmQLfHi-ChcMbwGD5ADalmgACJyjksatMVjEaQAGpgEA2cj4jAAXUCGAA9AzHORfuFSP1+Bhicj3P88ABRMDAJzGXZA6b3bBw36SVnAIG3JbkPpuLSkaSgnhGHDkPCkeAAEXlhBwpFoeGM-1o612pja0p+OlcAHVCKQwPMQHloHKIAqAGQB33ytyg92e70Oi4HYzDCDIq0A23jcxBi4QN0ED1e8jJTE1a1o3Y0xVYvZY6MdUyhIA).

Comment: [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors)

Comment: I've been experimenting with Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: It does indeed: `Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)).forEach(([name, desc]) => desc.writable && console.log(name));` If that does not answer your question, then you need to edit your question to clarify what you're after.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to address that TypeScript error in the question.  Adding the extra check with getOwnPropertyDescriptors works in theory yes but TypeScript compiler still gives the same error message