# Sort an array in React useEffect() with Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I'm setting an array of movie objects in useEffect and want them sorted alphabetically. If possible later I want to add the functionality of sorting them by different properties but for now I just want to get over this TypeScript hump. I have a separate types file where I export my movie interface:

```
export interface Movie {
    comments: string,
    imdb: string,
    mtc: string,
    rtc: string,
    smn: string,
    title: string
}
```

Which I then import in my page

```
import { Movie } from '../types';
```

I call useEffect, request the list of movies from my MongoDB and then want to sort them.

```
const Database = () => {

  const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState<Movie[]>([]);
  const [sortType, setSortType] = React.useState('title');
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Requests.getMovies()
      .then(setMovies)
      .catch (err => console.log(err));

      const types: Movie = {
        title: 'title',
        rtc: 'rtc',
        imdb: 'imdb',
        smn: 'smn',
        mtc: 'mtc',
        comments: 'comments'
      };


      const sortArray = (sortProperty: string): sortProperty is keyof typeof types => {

      const sorted = [...movies].sort((a: Movie, b: Movie) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty] );

return sorted;

      }

      sortArray(sortType);
      setMovies(sortArray);
  }, [sortType])

return (
// Bunch of stuff on the page and then map out the movies like so..

      <tbody>
        {movies.map((movie, index) => (
          <tr key={index} onClick={() => history.push(`/edit/${movie.title}`)}>
            <td>{movie.title}</td>
            <td>{movie.imdb}</td>
            <td>{movie.rtc}</td>
            <td>{movie.mtc}</td>
            <td>{movie.smn}</td>
            <td>{movie.comments}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>

//Bunch of other stuff on the page..
)
}

export default Database;
```

I get the list of movies to show up no problem but sorting them is hard. I found [this](https://dev.to/ramonak/react-how-to-dynamically-sort-an-array-of-objects-using-the-dropdown-with-react-hooks-195p) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568423/typescript-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found-on-ty) and [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-add-to-an-array-in-react-state-3d08ddb2e1dc) but TypeScript keeps giving me errors. On the `return sorted`...

```
Type 'Movie[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

..and on the `b[sortProperty]` and `a[sortProperty]`.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type 'Movie'.

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Movie'.
```

How do I get this to work? I thought sort returned the sorted array, but it returns a boolean? Why can't it sort by a property that is defined in the object and also in the interface?

Comment: you have a lot of issues with your code. i'm working on a solution and i'll clarify everything in an answer post once i'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here we go, i'll try to explain everything as best as i could.

first of all, you need to split your `useEffect` into 2 useEffect statement. `useEffect` hook should only handle one thing.

so your code would look like this:

```js
 React.useEffect(() => {
    Requests.getMovies()
      .then(setMovies)
      .catch (err => console.log(err));
), []}

React.useEffect(() => {
      // your sorting code
  }, [/* dependencies */])
```

the reasoning behind this is, you don't want unneeded action to trigger for every change in your depencies, i.e. you don't want to fetch each time a dependencies change but only when your component mounts.

as far as the issues with your code, the errors have 2 reasons:

- trying to do an arithmetic operation on 2 variables of type string
- trying to read property of an object using variable of type string while your object has no generic keys

also do a change operation through a `useEffect` hook is not the most optimal solution, because you'll need the `movies` state in your dependencies so you get the latest state, but if you do you'll trigger an infinite loop.

the way i do it, is sort once on component mount using the fetched array and then use an event handler function to trigger to subsequent sorts. this way you would avoid any unintended side effects.

so your code would look like this:

```js
const [movies, setMovies] = React.useState<Movie[]>([]);
const [sortType, setSortType] = React.useState<keyof Movie>("title");

 React.useEffect(() => {
    Requests.getMovies()
      .then(sortMovies)
      .catch (err => console.log(err));
), []}

const sortMovies = (moviesParam: Movie[] = movies) => {
    const sortArray = [...moviesParam].sort((a: Movie, b: Movie) => {
      if (a[sortType] > b[sortType]) return 1;
      else if (b[sortType] > a[sortType]) return -1;
      return 0;
    });

    setMovies(sortArray);
}
```

this code does sort your array alphabetically, and does not cause infinite loop.

also the `sortArray` function is not actually needed since you actually using the state anyway so it does not add any value to the code.

if you require further explanation on how and why i did those changes please add a comment and i'll update the post.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I fully comprehend your reasoning and the code is much, much cleaner indeed but the TypeScript error remains. It still highlights ```a[sortType]``` and tells me two things:

1. ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Movie'.``` on the "a" and "b".

2. ```No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Movie'.``` on the "sortType".


We seem to be not defining the keys of the object for TS. Looking into it myself atm but please comment back to see where we're headed.

Comment: i actually tested in a typescript environment and it did not give me issues. are you sure you changed this line `const [sortType, setSortType] = React.useState<keyof Movie>("title");` ?

Comment: D'oh, it seems I forgot that one! I'm still a bit new to TypeScript as you might have noticed. How come we're declaring the keyof in the useState hook? Does it induce that we're using strings as keys because our initial state is a string 'title'?

Comment: we're not declaring, we're setting it as type for our state, that way only strings having the same value is the keys would be accepted in our state.

Comment: also can please confirm my answer so this one would be displayed as resolved.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks again! Definitely one step closer to understanding all the TS definitions :)

Comment: if you want my contact for any further help, just leave a comment and i'll give it to you.