# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type DataType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a basic React app which simply filters an object removing its empty fields.

```
import "./styles.css";

type DataType = {
  data1: string;
  data2: string;
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<DataType>({
    data1: "",
    data2: ""
  });

  // Create temp obj and remove empty fields
  const removeEmptyFields = () => {
    const filteredData = data;
    Object.keys(filteredData).forEach(
      (key) => filteredData[key] === "" && delete filteredData[key]
    );
    setData(filteredData);
  };

  const addEmptyFields = () => {
    setData({
      data1: "",
      data2: ""
    });
  };

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addEmptyFields}>Add empty fields</button>
      <button onClick={removeEmptyFields}>Remove empty fields</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is to convert the function to Typescript, but am encountering the following error on `filteredData[key]`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'DataType'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found
> on type 'DataType'.ts(7053)

I've tried many solutions, some of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568423/typescript-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found-on-ty), but none of them helped with the error.

I've actually encountered this issue on multiple places where I need to get an object at position 'key' (`obj[key]`), but am not understanding what is Typescript actually missing in this type of situation?

A working playground can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-grass-ntyfz?file=/src/App.tsx)

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, so thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type assertion:

```
const removeEmptyFields = () => {
    const filteredData = data;
    (Object.keys(filteredData) as (keyof DataType)[]).forEach(
      (key) => filteredData[key] === "" && delete filteredData[key]
    );
    setData(filteredData);
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

it is always better to avoid modifying the original object

```
type DataType = { [key: string]: string }

const [data, setData] = useState<DataType>({
  data1: '',
  data2: '',
})

const removeEmptyFields = () => {
  const filteredData = Object.entries(data).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, ...(value !== '' && { [key]: value }) }),
    {}
  )
  setData(filteredData)
}
```