# TypeScript - accessing object/map values using strings in strict mode safely and conveniently

Tags: typescript, casting, typescript-types

Consider having an object for translating codes or for internationalization.

```
const statusMap = {
  'A': 'Active',
  'S': 'Suspended',
  'D': 'Inactive',
}
```

Getting values from this object works fine as long as you use the keys `'A' | 'S' | 'D'` explicitly (`statusMap.A`), but when dealing with an unknown string (`statusMap[queryParams.status]`), we get the error *"No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type"*. This works in plain JavaScript, so it's an issue with types. Ideally I would like `statusMap[queryParams.status]` to return `string | undefined`.

What's the most convenient and safe way of accessing object values using any string?

Is it possible to add an indexer to an object like this without creating an interface for it?

---

Here are some solutions I've already considered, but all of them have drawbacks.

1. **Casting the map to an indexed type**

```
const statusMap: Record<string, string | undefined> = {
  'A': 'Active',
  'S': 'Suspended',
  'D': 'Inactive',
}

statusMap[anyString]
```

This works fine, but we just threw away autocompletion (typing `statusMap.` won't get us suggestions for A, S, or D anymore). Another small issue is that `statusMap.A` would result in `string | undefined` even though `'A'` is there.

<s>Moreover, it's difficult to enforce that every team member does the casting correctly. For example you could cast to just `Record<string, string>` and `statusMap['nonexistent_key']` would result in a `string` type, even though the actual value is `undefined`.</s>

edit: [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) mitigates this issue and you can safely use just `Record<string, string>`.

2. **Casting the map on every access**

```
(statusMap as Record<string, string>)[anyString]
```

Works fine, but needs manually specifying the correct type on each access.

3. **Casting the indexing string on every access**

```
statusMap[anyString as keyof typeof statusMap]
```

This is kind of ugly and also unsafe - there's no guarantee that anyString is actually `'A' | 'S' | 'D'`.

4. **Using suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors in tsconfig**

Convenient, but not type safe, this just sidesteps the issue and the option has been deprecated since TypeScript 5.0.

5. **Utility function**

```
function getValSafe<T extends {}>(obj: T, key: string | number): T[keyof T] | undefined {
  return (obj as any)[key]
}

getValSafe(statusMap, anyString)
```

This works quite well, but I don't like the idea of shoving a custom utility function into every single project just to do a basic operation in TypeScript.

---

Is there any better way of doing this?

Similar questions: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968332/how-do-i-prevent-the-error-index-signature-of-object-type-implicitly-has-an-an) uses an interface, but I want to avoid that, imagine having a huge i18n map or even a tree. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568423/typescript-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found-on-ty) uses a more complex translation function, I just want to use object maps like I would in regular JavaScript and still have type safety and autocompletion.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: The reason all of these solutions look clunky is that they are all an attempt to avoid doing what is supposed to be done: sanitise your inputs and handle incorrect inputs explicitly. This is why strict type checking was introduced, and any "solution" that ignores that is kind of meant to look wrong.

Comment: @wonderflame 5.0.4

Comment: @biziclop How do you sanitize input that comes from an API or can be tampered by the user?

Comment: @blade Using type guards, in this case you can create a simple one like `anyString in statusMap`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCuECy8AOMC8MDeAUDDAIIBcMARCcFAJYBuAppQDREwDKFlnKGTMABMmQthwAiPAJJh4tRi3YBfOIjoQAZnSYQYAJSagATkIA80Y3TABzVnChXbAPgDcBAqEiwAtpgFCnFCIKOgYFIYm5gDWTACeIJowUHECiQ4haJgwAD4wABSW1jYwAGT4ygCU9kUuOBwIyFkY7gR+GAFBmWEAdCStADZMsJY4VJSt7Z3BTWEA2pYAuu5AA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @biziclop Could you elaborate on that in an answer? It sounds like a good solution, but `if (anyString in statusMap) console.log(statusMap[anyString])` still produces the same TS error.

Comment: Probably he means something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCuECy8AOMC8MDeAUDDAIIBcMARCcFAJYBuAppQDREwDKFlnKGTMABMmQthwAiPAJJh4tRi3YBfOIjoQAZnSYQYAJSagATkIA80Y3TABzVnChXbAPgDcBAqEiwNnKIhR0DABpJgBPHBgACnhjGwokMABrMBAAdzAASgpYmxgNGCTwkE0YKDCBEocAtEwcZ3wOYyZkYzAyiqYq3JxsXEpLaxtKGAAyUZge62rkWox3ZXcCABsWybAwvyc8-sp3OlKo339ZoNCwmI2toczMxuIEU8wAbXgrxyGAXQWCIA)

Comment: @wonderflame please do, this seems like a good solution, even if a bit verbose. It seems to work without the `satisfies` part or by replacing `(string & {})` with just a `string`, so if you could also explain that briefly.

Comment: which one? do you want type guard or with `(string & {})`? I added satisfies for extra  type checking to make sure that status map is `Record<string, string>`

Comment: Ah, OK, I wasn't familiar with the satisfies constraint, that's pretty useful. I still don't get the `(string & {})` part.

Comment: if you would write `Record<'A' | 'B' | 'C' | string, string>` that would end up with just string, since `'A' | 'B' | 'C'` is a subset of `string`.  With adding `string & {}` that allows us to still see the `'A' | 'B' | 'C'` in the autocomplete and accept any `string` as well

Comment: Basically, `& {}` prevents the compiler from simplifying to just `string`

Comment: Does that fully address the question? Should I write a solution, If yes, which one? or maybe both?

Comment: Sure. Ideally both, having more options is always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest using [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator to type check whether `statusMap` is a `Record<string, string>`:

```
const statusMap = {
  A: "Active",
  S: "Suspended",
  D: "Inactive",
} satisfies Record<string, string>;
```

Option 1:
We can define an object that will be a  `Record<"A" | "S" | "D" | string, string>`, however, if you would try defining an object with this type, you would get `Record<string, string>`, since `"A" | "S" | "D"`  is a subset of `string` and the compiler will simplify the keys to just `string`. To prevent this, instead of adding just `string`, we can add an intersection: `string & {}`. `{}` doesn't bother us, since `string` extends `{}` and the result will be `string` anyway, though it will prevent from simplifying which is exactly what we need:

```
const statusMap = {
  A: "Active",
  S: "Suspended",
  D: "Inactive",
} satisfies Record<string, string>;

const mappedStatusMap: Record<keyof typeof statusMap | (string & {}), string> =
  statusMap;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCuECy8AOMC8MDeAUDDAIIBcMARCcFAJYBuAppQDREwDKFlnKGTMABMmQthwAiPAJJh4tRi3YBfOIjoQAZnSYQYAJSagATkIA80Y3TABzVnChXbAPgDcBAqEiwAtpgFCnFCIKOgYFIYm5gDWTACeIJowUHECiQ4haJgwAD4wABSW1jYwAGT4ygCU9kUuOBwIyFkY7h5+GAFBmWEAdCStADZMsJY4VJSt7Z3BTWEA2pYAuu5AA)

Option 2:
Create a custom type guard to check whether any string is in the `statusMap`:

```
const isStatusMapKey = (arg: unknown): arg is keyof typeof statusMap => {
  return typeof arg === "string" && arg in statusMap;
};
```

Usage:

```
if (isStatusMapKey(anyString)) {
  statusMap[anyString];
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCuECy8AOMC8MDeAUDDAIIBcMARCcFAJYBuAppQDREwDKFlnKGTMABMmQthwAiPAJJh4tRi3YBfOIjoQAZnSYQYAJSagATkIA80Y3TABzVnChXbAPgDcBAqEiwNnKIhR0DABpJgBPHBgACnhjGwokMABrMBAAdzAASgpYmxgNGCTwkE0YKDCBEocAtEwcZ3wOYyZkYzAyiqYq3JxsXEpLaxtKGAAyUZge62rkWox3ZXcCABsWybAwvyc8-sp3OlKo339ZoNCwmI2toczMxuIEU8wAbXgrxyGAXQWCIA)

Comment: Looks great. Would it be possible to do something like the first option directly on statusMap without having to use mappedStatusMap? I suspect not, given that you need `typeof statusMap` in the type definition.

Comment: if you know the keys of `statusMap` beforehand then yes, though the code would be really repetitive. `const statusMap: Record<"A" | "S" | "D" | string & {}, string>`

Comment: `satisfies` is a cool feature, didn't know about that

Answer (score 2):

The problem with many of these approaches is that they just try to trick the type checker into accepting incorrect values and pretending that they're correct. Which is the opposite of what strict type checking was created for. (This is because unlike say in Java, TS type checking doesn't **enforce** type conformity at runtime.)

So we can try to actually check the value of `anyString` at runtime instead, sanitising the input.

In theory this is exactly what the `in` type guard was created for, unfortunately the type checker can't work it out yet when property name is not a constant.

So you need to build a type predicate:

```
const isStatus = (str: string): str is keyof typeof statusMap => str in statusMap;
```

Now you can do:

```
const statusMsg = isStatus(anyString) ? statusMap[str] : undefined;
```

Or even better, instead of returning `undefined`, you can stop processing the input and display an error message. Or use a default `"unknown status"` value. Once you handle incorrect inputs explicitly, the choice is in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `satisfies`:

```js
const statusMap = {
  'A': 'Active',
  'S': 'Suspended',
  'D': 'Inactive',
  'E': 12, // error
} as const satisfies Record<string,string>

statusMap.A // with autocomplete
```

Comment: `let anyString: string = ''; statusMap[anyString]` doesn't seem to work - "No index signature" error