# Expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type - when trying to use a string as an index in an object

Tags: typescript

Why is TypeScript reporting the error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ '&': string; '"': string; "'": string; '<': string; '>': string; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ '&': string; '"': string; "'": string; '<': string; '>': string; }'.ts(7053)

in the following Utils.ts file?

```
export function escapeHtml(text:string) {
    const characters = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#039;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;'
    };

    return text.replace(/[<>&"']/g, function(x) {
        return characters[x];
    });
}
```

Comment: It says why - `x` can be any string (the fact that the regex only matches one of five characters isn't information available to the type system) but `characters` only contains a few properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your `x` argument is of type `any`, while it must be not only a string but a specific string. For example, stupidly enough this works (please don't do this!):

```
return text.replace(/[<>&"']/g, function(x: string) {
    return characters[x as '&'|'"'|'"'|'<'|'>'];
});
```

Your `characters` object is not a `string: string` map, it's an object with 5 properties named `&`, `"`, `'`, `<` and `>`. So if you want to get one of the object property values, the name you pass into `characters[name]` must be one of the 5 possible options.

The correct fix is to define your `characters` object as `string: string` dictionary, which can be done like this for example:

```
function escapeHtml(text:string) {
    const characters: Record<string, string> = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#039;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;'
    };

    return text.replace(/[<>&"']/g, function(x: string) {
        return characters[x];
    });
}
```

The `Record<string, string>` is the key piece here.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568423/typescript-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found-on-ty?rq=1) is probably a duplicate of your question

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue with a `keyof`, but wonder if it is a good style:

```
const characters = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;'
};

export function escapeHtml(text:string) {

    return text.replace(/[<>&"']/g, function(x) {
        return characters[x as keyof typeof characters];
    });
}
```

Comment: You basically did the better equivalent of mine "don't do this" example. There is nothing wrong with `keyof` as the compiler allows it. I just find it better to define map types explicitly, because that way you essentially say in code 'hey, this is not just an object, but some king of mapping'