# Typescript issue with Object.keys index signature

Tags: typescript

I have the following type definitions:

```
interface DefaultConfig {
  state: {
    initialState: AllState;
  };
}

type UserConfig = {
  [K in keyof DefaultConfig]: DefaultConfig[K];
};
// Could also use 'type UserConfig = Partial<DefaultConfig>;'

interface AssignDefaults {
  (userConfig: UserConfig): DefaultConfig;
}
```

I use these in the following function:

```
const defaultConfig: DefaultConfig = {
  state: {
    initialState: defaultInitialState
  }
};

const assignDefaults: AssignDefaults = userConfig => {
  const thisUserConfig = userConfig;
  Object.keys(userConfig).forEach(key => {
    if (key in defaultConfig) {
      const maybeObject = userConfig[key];
      if (!!maybeObject && maybeObject.constructor === Object) {
        thisUserConfig[key] = {
          ...(defaultConfig[key] || {}),
          ...userConfig[key]
        };
      }
    }
  });
  return { ...defaultConfig, ...thisUserConfig };
};
```

What I expect to happen is that `userConfig[key]` should be equal to `keyof DefaultConfig`, as that's what is defined in the `UserConfig` index signature.

However, this doesn't work as `Object.keys(...)` defines its return value as `string[]`. This causes a Typescript error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'UserConfig'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'UserConfig'.
```

It seems Typescript is unable to determine that `keyof DefaultConfig` is also a string.

I know I can remove this error by including `[key: string]: any` to the `DefaultConfig` interface, however I would much prefer not to do this as:

1. These are the only keys and values allowed for the object it represents (e.g. the `defaultConfig` object should not contain `foo: "bar"` as a key/value pair, however this would be allowed if `DefaultConfig` included the index signature.
2. When I need to call `defaultConfig.state.initialState`, I don't want it to return the type as `any`, which is what happens if that index signature is included. Same with if I create a const `const foo = assignDefaults(userConfigObject)` then call `foo.state.initialState`.
3. I don't like using `any` in my type definitions unless absolutely necessary.

Is this a limitation of Typescript or is there some workaround for this?

Comment: For anyone, like me, who finds this and is still wondering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
- Object.keys(userConfig).forEach(key => {
+ (Object.keys(userConfig) as (keyof DefaultConfig)[]).forEach(key => {
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution here as it does work, however I would like to know if there is a proper way to handle this as this does appear hacky to me