# When using enum as object, "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'", why?

Tags: typescript

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwPJQCbCgFQE8xg4BvAKDjgFkBDKAa2HgF44ByGgQQCUBpAKL4OAGipwAMgEtU0tp0kBJGkpHiAvhQoYARgCtgAYxgA6ZoQDOACiy4CxYAEpTqOmGsxHcVgD44RhCIlhAANsCmoRAA5rY4eEQkANpeJAC6Tk5AA) is the TypeScript playground example for this question, which only has the bare minimum required for this question.

Here is the real world example of where this comes up:
I have an enum

```
export enum OrderType {
  Market = 'MARKET',
  Limit = 'LIMIT',
}
```

And then I have an input field

```
export const TypeInputInner = ({ onChange, value }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Select style={{ width: 150, margin: 5 }} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
      {Object.keys(OrderType).map(type => (
        <Option key={type} value={OrderType[type]}>
          {type}
        </Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

There is a TS error on that `OrderType[type]` part:

> Error:(16, 45) TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

Why is this? Isn't the enum just an object?, ie

```
{
  Market: "MARKET",
  Limit: "LIMIT"
}
```

Where do numbers come in here?

Btw, I know that if I use `type as any` the TS errors go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is that [the return type of `Object.keys(obj)` is `string[]` and not `Array<keyof typeof obj>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript).  This is the desired and intended behavior because TypeScript cannot be sure that an object has *only* the keys it knows about.

If you know for sure that your object only has known keys in it, then you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that it can treat `Object.keys()` as a more restricted set, as in:

```
(Object.keys(OrderType) as Array<keyof typeof OrderType>).map(type =>
  console.log(OrderType[type]) // okay now
);
```

---

The reason it was complaining that `type` isn't a `number` is probably because `enum` types have a [numeric index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) in order to implement [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) for any [numeric](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) values in your enum.   Of course the example here is purely a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) but I guess they put numeric indexes on every enum object type:

```
const hmm = OrderType[123]; // string
```

Anyway, when `type` was just `string`, `OrderType[type]` is `any` because there is no string index signature, and the compiler was warning that the only index signature on the object is numeric.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwPJQCbCgFQE8xg4BvAKDjgFkBDKAa2HgF44AiGgQQCUBpAKL4OAGipwAMgEtU0tp0kBJGkpEUAvhQoAKDACMAVsADGMAHTNCAZz048REgEo4da3G5QodQgB4rEABmcDDEwEGY9gRhAHxO5qh0YDqhJHCsMRImEIjWEAA2wOb5EADmdrjRJADaqcAAui4A9E1wEIw+cIgQAO4UTgDc2tm58AAWqOjsWJWOwNUAjABMAMz1A3AtcNYwUNKIpXCAfBuAKLsUQA)