# type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown || or how to let typescript assign Type[key] = SameType[key]

Tags: typescript

I have this helper function:

```
getAndAssignToObject<T>(key: string, objectToAssign: T): Promise<T> {
  const data = await AppStorage.get<T>(key);
  Object.keys(data).forEach( dataKey => {
    // @ts-ignore
    objectToAssign[dataKey] = data[dataKey];
  });

  return data;
}
```

and is used in this way:

```
Helpers.getAndAssignToObject<BlockingConfig>(Components.BlockingRules, blockingData);
```

It works as expected but as you can see I have there a `@ts-ignore` that I would really like to remove.

The errorI get when I remove it is :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'   .ts(7053)

and I do not know how to fix it. I tried to give `dataKey` the type `keyof T` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assert that `Object.keys` returns `Array<keyof T>` not `Array<string>`.

```
async function getAndAssignToObject<T>(key: string, objectToAssign: T): Promise<T> {
  const data = await AppStorage.get<T>(key);
  (Object.keys(data) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(dataKey => {
    objectToAssign[dataKey] = data[dataKey];
  });

  return data;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gQQA64GUMkYoBzEALngG8AoeeCjAHgBUA+ACgGtqoUATwCU1AAowkAWwCWaEOw4BuOgF86UNIJRh4AMwCuOjDNRMQGbCmDY0aGWRRskAeQBGAK3CtOvEIOpMGBkUMgAaeCRPb2dbe0dqNlF4CWk5BU5aBkRUTHhgKAwoeABeeCgAdygZLDxCYlIKADpmRT8RFUYudy8wDCaefzQuAqLhcrQcGFJBFkHBJD14TmEmvRIAUSgwAAsRwqgAaX9SjizGRijejFi7BxQAbVGj-wBdUvyDp4PjwVfO+CqYQqbJwDAGGAoT5FFTqOjMKw2O6OZw9bxcABEGIi9EYUGoAEY1MIgA)

The reason this is not the default is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript/55012175#55012175). Basically the idea is that for example `objectToAssign` could have more properties than `keyof T` would suggest and this can lead to runtime errors. In this case you would be copying those extra keys to `data` which is not a problem in this function but might cause issues in other places.