# How can I loop through an object that has defined keys and use the keys to index an object of the same type?

Tags: typescript

In the following, I am trying to get the total value of `value` in pounds. However, this creates an error of `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MoneyType'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MoneyType'`.

```
interface MoneyType {
    yuan: number,
    dollar: number,
    pound: number,
}

const CONVERSION_RATE: MoneyType = {
    yuan: 10,
    dollar: 5,
    pound: 1
}

function totalValue(value: MoneyType) {
    let totalValue = 0;
    for (let moneyType in value) {
        totalValue += CONVERSION_RATE[moneyType] * value[moneyType];
    }

    return totalValue;
}
```

I am aware I can use `interface MoneyType {[key: string]: number}` instead, but is there any way I can keep the key restrictions to yuan, dollar, and pound?

Comment: I just tried this code in a new TypeScript project and it worked as expected, I didn't receive any errors. Maybe this is a problem with your TypeScript config or your call to `totalValue(value)`

Comment: I just copied the code into https://www.typescriptlang.org/play and got the same error?

Comment: This is odd. Here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xfyx1q you can see the code working, I had previously tested it in a local project and it worked as well. In the case of https://www.typescriptlang.org/play indeed it displays the error but if you click the RUN button it executes without errors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 - just cast to any:

```
function totalValue(value: MoneyType) {
    let totalValue = 0;
    for (let moneyType in value) {
        totalValue += (CONVERSION_RATE as any)[moneyType] * (value as any)[moneyType];
    }
    return totalValue;
}
```

Solution 2 - extends the interface from a key/value structure:

```
interface OnlyNumbers {[key: string]: number}

interface MoneyType extends OnlyNumbers {
    yuan: number,
    dollar: number,
    pound: number,
}
```

Also some other suggestions regarding your function itself:

- loop thought CONVERSION_RATE members since the value parameter is less controlled and can have other members.
- check if value[moneyType] is defined before using it to avoid NaN results

Comment: I thought the whole point of having type `MoneyType` was that `CONVERSION_RATE` and `value` would have the same exact structure. Solution 2 was already posted in my question. Solution 1 seems to be OK since I already checked the types before? I also found another solution using keyword `keyof` though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285080/type-string-cant-be-used-to-index-type-unknown-or-how-to-let-typescript-a?rq=1

Comment: The MoneyType interface will just indicate the known properties of "value" parameter. It will no guarantee that it has only those properties since the object can be implementing other interfaces, extending other classes and so on. Also even some MoneyType properties can be undefined/null in the "value" parameter if a cast/type assertion is done.