# Trying to get fromEntries type right

Tags: typescript

I am extending the styled-components module like

```js
import "styled-components";

declare module "styled-components" {
  type Breakpoint = "small" | "medium" | "large" | "extra";

  export interface DefaultTheme {
    devices: { [P in keyof Breakpoint]: number };
    colors: {
      main: string;
      secondary: string;
    };
  }
}
```

I use it here

```js
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";

const breakpoints = {
  small: 576,
  medium: 768,
  large: 992,
  extra: 1200
};

const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  devices: Object.fromEntries<string>(
    Object.entries(breakpoints).map(([k, v]) => [k, `(min-width: ${v}px)`])
  ),
  colors: {
    main: "blue",
    secondary: "red"
  }
};

export default theme;
```

How can I get proper type safety here? 2 issues I'm having:
`theme.devices`:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; [x: number]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ [x: number]: number; toString: number; charAt: number; charCodeAt: number; concat: number; indexOf: number; lastIndexOf: number; localeCompare: number; match: number; replace: number; search: number; slice: number; ... 34 more ...; trimRight: number; }': charAt, charCodeAt, concat, indexOf, and 40 more.
```

And where I try to use it I get all string methods along with the custom breakpoints properties while I would only like to have the breakpoints properties

```js
`@media ${props => props.theme.devices.small}` {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the type of the `devices` property be declared not as `{ [P in keyof Breakpoint]: number }` but as `{ [P in Breakpoint]: string }` (or equivalently `Record<Breakpoint, string>`)?  `keyof Breakpoint` is basically `keyof string`, the names of properties and methods on a `string`, like `length` and `charAt`... not what you want.  And you the values you are using inside `theme.devices` are strings, not numbers.

I will assume this definition of `DefaultTheme`:

```
export interface DefaultTheme {
  devices: { [P in Breakpoint]: string };
  colors: {
    main: string;
    secondary: string;
  };
}
```

---

On to `Object.fromEntries()` and `Object.entries()`.  The type system isn't really expressive enough to guarantee that objects only have known property keys.  Object types in TypeScript are extendable/open; they are not [exact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  If I have an `interface Obj { someProp: string }` and an `interface ObjX extends Obj { extraProp: number }`, and you hand me an object `obj` of type `Obj`, for all I know it may also be of type `ObjX` and has an `extraProp` key.  And for all I know it may be of some other type that extends `Obj` and has all sorts of unknown extra keys.  Thus  [`Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]` and not `Array<keyof Obj>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript), and similarly `Object.entries(obj)` returns `Array<[string, any]>` (or maybe `Array<[string, V]>` for some value type `V` if `obj` is an indexable type).  And `Object.fromEntries()` [is just as weakly-keyed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es2019.object.d.ts#L28), turning any set of entries into an object of type `{[k: string]: V}` where `V` is the union of all entry value types.  The compiler doesn't know how to verify that `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries()...)` turns an object type `T` into some related object type, and so it doesn't even try.

Therefore I'd suggest that you will have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) somewhere to tell the compiler that you are verifying that the types are correct.  In this case, if you find yourself mapping over values and preserving keys often, I might make a helper function with just one type assertion, and you can reuse that function elsewhere:

```
function mapValues<T extends object, V>(obj: T, valueMapper: (k: T[keyof T]) => V) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, valueMapper(v)])
  ) as { [K in keyof T]: V };
}
```

This just asserts that `mapValues(obj, valueMapper)` will return an object with the same keys as `obj` and whose values will all be that of the return type of `valueMapper`.  You can use it like this:

```
const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  devices: mapValues(breakpoints, v => `(min-width: ${v}px`),
  colors: {
    main: "blue",
    secondary: "red"
  }
};
```

And that should hopefully compile without errors.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBO8AuBLA9gO1AW0ogOaSgBmiGuoAogMoBykAHigLABQaWKBp80JAPIAjAFYwUAYWwBnFIgCu0FBkSgA3h1DayFXNW6I0kGQB4AKqAC8oeFgCeAPgAUkQ8ZkAuUAEkeyYVhIU0RIeHBsWHtQAG0ABQoABwIUewBpSHsAGlBzAF1HAEpvdViAa1AuUASMZMRUjPs870sAXwBuLR1ySgN5D1d3E28-AnhA4NDwyOi7exiC4tsHTvYdUDd+kwsXDBLYr1A5IyxCZtzQVtAAH1AAQURkewAZNDLg8yLvGOOuQhz8gtVutNkYTM49hpWksfv1Tjk5nkgRxWhw0exUslQAAhKZlRIYLgoaygABEMlw8FgsFJNzJ+HAaAUuFpt1JCCIkFZZOY8ngpNWHCJvH4JAAIpA+ApYChzAALSD4DRdKAANzQAkOpXilRwuLC+MJ3HOv1Ol2BoGgGFgqi1XW0lK43lNhAt2hkMGw4CQ9mdcNdXQ6KPRVqwclAwjxBKJMhJmjWR0p1O8AFYAOwANiyXQZTNw3kzAA5swmOcRvABOCsAJhL2l5yG8AEZqwAGVsowXsUgKLDKTA4SmJABqVIU20svLc4FjGDEEhyw5cXTnohaddAqrHkAAsvBEnVvM4yi0Yu97BhSLk8oVrI5QMOOLf49pQigFIgcCJxMoAHQ9fQhhkZx7VAb8JF-UEBlXQpfyHZxnDPHJVRvO9ymQ7c9wPAhnFVQoby6W94FjbU0l1UBz0va9vGHc1g3YDhQ3DFAFXwbwJSlGV5UVEgbBfCBIHVTVvCHUdYHHYDIwNaNuBkZC0IAA2cXAuAAWgAdzQcAWO8AASdRVVaRImAUwoNytG1EDtBMHXgJ0yUCcdSQ3d1PSwb1EF9MlQnAUlA07DggA)