# How to convert Enum in TypeScript to array which returns keyof typeof Enum?

Tags: typescript

Following enum

```
export enum Types {
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
    ...
}
```

is converted into array with following function

```
export function EnumKeys<T>(obj: object): string[] {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .filter(value => isNaN(Number(value)) === false)
        .map(key => obj[key]);
}
```

EnumKeys returns string[], but I need it to return **[keyof typeof T]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns `string[]` by design (see canonical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript/55012175#55012175)). You will need to use a type to transform `Object.keys(obj)` into `Array<keyof T>` (I assume for the type of `obj` you wanted to use the `T` type parameter).

```
 enum Types {
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,

}

function EnumKeys<T>(obj: T) {
    return (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>)
        .filter(value => isNaN(Number(value)) !== false); // just directly take the non number keys.
}

let o = EnumKeys(Types) 
console.log(o)
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/AQUwdgrgtsAqCeAHEBnYBvAUMHckgEZgBeYAgGm1wWQCYThbLdhMBfTTAMwjAGMALgEsA9mGABRSFADSIeCgA8sAHwAKEQCMAVgC44ASgxUcAJxACIp8WoDyOkIIB0Aa3koNOowEM0AQVNTb3hFN3gRLjgVAxMWYCcuIQAbARBTNQA3bySIEBIVYCEUADlvYrVi6E00zOzcgyMAQmJSLmyUEAMAbnZOJItgEQYpaDkFNRpUI0w+MRQRfqckkQBzDQMgA)

Comment: Great Solution. Cheers