# How to fix this Typescript validation error

Tags: typescript, object

I have the following declaration:

```
const allTypes = { jpg: true, gif: true, png: true, mp4: true };
```

and later in the code:

```
{Object.keys(allTypes).map((type: string) => (<FormControlLabel 
  control={<Checkbox checked={Boolean(allTypes[type])} 
  onChange={handleFiltersChange(type)}/>} /* this is the line with error */
  label={type}/>
))}
```

Typescript is complaining:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ jpg: boolean; gif: boolean; png: boolean; mp4: boolean; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ jpg: boolean; gif: boolean; png: boolean; mp4: boolean; }'.ts(7053)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's `filters`?  Is this a [mcve]?  I'm guessing the problem is that [`Object.keys()` returns `string[]` instead of a `keyof` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript).  Presumably you can fix this like `(Object.keys(allTypes) as Array<keyof typeof allTypes>).map(type => ...` to assert that `Object.keys` returns an array of key types (for object literals this is safe enough) and then don't annotate the callback function's parameter as `string`.  But I am not sure because I don't I can reproduce this given the code here.

Comment: sorry I have replaced filters with allTypes. I am new to typescript. JS would have no issues here.

Comment: and your solution did work .. .thaknks ... please write this as a formal answer so that i can mark it as accepted