# How do I get the key of a value in a Typescript Record

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here's the code:

```js
export type Period = 'dy' | 'wk' | 'mn' | 'qt' | 'yr';

const periods: Record<Period, string> = {
    dy: 'Day',
    wk: 'Week',
    mn: 'Month',
    qt: 'Quarter',
    yr: 'Year'
  };
```

When I try to do this:

`const key = Object.keys(periods).find(key => periods[key] === 'Day');`

I get an error of course, since `periods[key]` cannot guarantee that `key` is of the correct type. How should I really go about doing this? I thought of an enum but I can't do reverse lookups. All I'm trying to achieve is an input field that displays 'Day' but has a key of `dy` (etc.) and can set the state to the correct key and not the value when the user picks another value.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns `string[]` not `Array<keyof T>` (where `T` is the type of the value passed in). The reasons for this are outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript).

Since your object is probably not going to have unknown keys, you can use a type assertion:

```
export type Period = 'dy' | 'wk' | 'mn' | 'qt' | 'yr';

const periods: Record<Period, string> = {
  dy: 'Day',
  wk: 'Week',
  mn: 'Month',
  qt: 'Quarter',
  yr: 'Year'
};

const key = (Object.keys(periods) as Array<Period>).find(key => periods[key] === 'Day');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=89#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKwoEsIBM4C8cA5LosXAD4kDuA1hdcQLYB2jJAjjB8YlMQDcAKGEBjCKwDO8FNjxSAXHABKwCVFwAeDPNwAaODOysA5gD5CcAN7C4cMsuIARAIbl9duPScB1YMAMnvZsTgCykjAAFsTBcNxOAIoArq6wmLFe-E4AmsBpxMIAviLikjJwdMCIVgAUAPIARgBW6jAAdFWIUrVyOLhSAJRwrlJwAIJQUO46mP3mg+0AZlisuLVdhJZ9CgDaXQC6hARELu7Eg4JAA)

Comment: The problem with that is that `Array<Period>` includes `undefined` and this also gives an error.

Comment: @Sammy where are you getting `undefined` ? The code sample I posted works as is. The array returned by `Object.keys(periods)` should not contain `undefined`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that's because I'm trying to set the key as a value within another function, but `find` may indeed return `undefined` if they value cannot be found. I'll handle that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did the other way around for my needs, and that worked too. 
```typescript
type Period = 'dy' | 'wk' | 'mn' | 'qt' | 'yr';

const periods: Record<Period, string> = {
  dy: 'Day',
  wk: 'Week',
  mn: 'Month',
  qt: 'Quarter',
  yr: 'Year'
};

const key = (Object.values(periods) as Array<string>).find(val => val == periods.dy);
console.log(key); // Returns "Day"
```

Answer (score 10):

I have found myself needing to solve this many times.  I have some utils laying around that help.

This is what I would do.

```
const _periods = {
  dy: 'Day',
  wk: 'Week',
  mn: 'Month',
  qt: 'Quarter',
  yr: 'Year',
} as const;

export type Period = keyof typeof _periods;
export type PeriodValue = typeof _periods[Period];

export const periods = _periods as Record<Period, PeriodValue>;

function keys<T>(object: T) {
  return Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[];
};

const key = keys(periods).find((key) => periods[key] === 'Day');

// Compile error, value not possible.
const badValueKey = keys(periods).find((key) => periods[key] === 'Minute');
```

Answer (score 5):

To expand on [Daniel Raby's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974124/183005) 's answer a little - I have these utility functions for keys and entries which are typed according to the Record<> ...

```js
export function recordKeys<K extends PropertyKey, T>(object: Record<K, T>) {
  return Object.keys(object) as (K)[];
};

export function recordEntries<K extends PropertyKey, T>(object: Record<K, T>) {
  return Object.entries(object) as ([K,T])[];
};
```

Comment: `keyof any` is the same as `string | number | symbol`. Or you could use the built-in `PropertyKey` type.