# Typescript element implicitly has type any with for...in loops

Tags: typescript, for-in-loop, object-property

I have a JSON object imported from a JSON file (with `resolveJsonModule: true`).
The object looks like this:

```
"myobject": {
  "prop1": "foo",
  "prop2": "bar"
}
```

and it's type therefore looks like this:

```js
myobject: { prop1: string, prop2: string }
```

That's very nice but when I try to use a `for...in` loop,

```js
for (const key in myobject)  {
  console.log(myobject[key])
}
```

I get this error:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "prop1": string; "prop2": string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ "prop1": string; "prop2": string; }'.
```

I understand that this means the iterator `key` is of type `string` and not of type `'prop1' | 'prop2'`. But I don't understand why the iterator doesn't get this type because I'm explicitly iterating through the property names of `myobject`. Did I miss a tsconfig property that enables this behavior?
I would like not to do this:

```
for (const key in myobject)  {
  console.log(myobject[key as 'prop1' | 'prop2'])
}
```

Because:

1. I might add new properties in the future; and
2. this seems a bit cheaty, and I feel like there is a better way to do that.

Comment: due this is one item you can't access it through for loop just use `myobject.prop1` to get value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better way to this is:

```
for (const key in myobject)  {
  console.log(myobject[key as keyof typeof myobject])
}
```

In this way, it won't break when you add a property or rename it

Answer (score 19):

Three solutions for typing `for...in` loops, I am aware of:

#### 1. Type assertion

A [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) will force `key` type to be narrowed to `myobject` keys:

```
for (const key in myobject)  {
  console.log(myobject[key as keyof typeof myobject])
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWwJ5ICMArcDALngG94AHGJGgRgsxgEsUBzAGlvpoBMLDOy7wAvgG4AUNIBmSGPAAUydFgDWIXPA458xUgEp4VaabVokEEADoISTsryESYDAG0tOqGnjekOXgMXBoQQP1XUgBdI2lxIA)

#### 2. Declare key variable explicitely

The key variable [cannot be typed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4518#issuecomment-170257096) inside the for-in loop, instead we can declare it outside:

```
let key: keyof typeof myobject // add this declaration
for (key in myobject)  {
  console.log(myobject[key]) // works
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWwJ5ICMArcDALngG94AHGJGgRgsxgEsUBzAGlvpoBMLDOy7wAvgG4AUNIggsAaxC4Ky-ADN4GXDRBIteQiTAZpGpDHgAKdfA458xUgEp4Vae%20Tok8gHQQSJzWRs6mANrqALpuAPSx8ADulopo0uLSQA)

#### 3. Generics

```
function foo<T>(t: T) {
  for (const k in t) {
    console.log(t[k]) // works
  }
}

foo(myobject)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWwJ5ICMArcDALngG94AHGJGgRgsxgEsUBzAGlvpoBMLDOy7wAvgG4AUNIBmAVxRgMbVPDlIkAHgAqAPgAU5eLoCUVafA1IY8Q8nRYA1vA7wMFyleuJUaJAgQADoIJE5jAG1nAF0zH3FpRPktQzxCEhUzIA)

#### Why is this necessary?

`key` in a `for...in` loop will by design [default to type `string`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6379). This is due to the [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out) of TypeScript: the exact properties' keys shape is only known at run-time, the compiler cannot statically analyze, what properties are present on the object at compile-time. A `key` type narrowed to `myobject` properties would make the `for...in` loop an unsafe operation type-wise.

#### More infos

Note: Some linked resources discuss `Object.keys`, for which the same argumentation holds.

- [Why doesn't `Object.keys` return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript/55012175#55012175) - by Ryan Cavanaugh
- [Comment by Anders Hejlsberg in TypeScript#12253](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) - also mentions `for...in`
- [TypeScript#32321](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32321) links to a multitude of duplicate issues
- [Specific comment towards `for...in`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12314) by Anders Hejlsberg:

> I have my doubts about this one. In `for (var k in x)` where `x` is of some type `T`, it is only safe to say that `k` is of type `keyof T` when the exact type of `x` is `T`. If the actual type of `x` is a subtype of `T`, as is permitted by our assignment compatibility rules, you will see values in `k` that are not of type `keyof T`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have an object to be dynamic in the future create a model like this

```
interface PropertyItemModel {
  propName: string;
  propValue: string;
}
```

and in the component you can fetch data by loop

```
export class AppComponent {

  items: PropertyItemModel[] = [];

  constructor() {

    this.items = [
      { propName: "1", propValue: "foo" },
      { propName: "2", propValue: "bar" }]

     this.items.forEach(item => {
        console.log(`name: ${item.propName} - value: ${item.propValue}`)
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I prefer not to rebuild my whole infrastructure which is reliant on this key-value object :)
I might use this one in future projects tho

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why the iterator doesn't get this type because I'm explicitly iterating through the property names of myobject. Did I miss a tsconfig property that enables this behavior?

That's because you can extend an object property and typescript will still consider it a type of the same object. E. g:

```
interface ABC {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}
function foo(abc: ABC) {
  for (const k in abc) { // const k: string
  const v = abc[k];
  // ~~~~~~ Element implicitly has an 'any' type
  // because type 'ABC' has no index signature
 }
}
  
const x = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 2, d: new Date()};
foo(x); //OK, no errors
```

That's because ts considers x to be an ABC type because it has the properties a, b and c.

To fix the error in the function foo, you need to say that k is of the type of keyof ABC.

```
function foo(abc: ABC) {
    let k: keyof ABC;
    for (k in abc) { // let k: "a" | "b" | "c"
    const v = abc[k]; // Type is string | number
    }
 }
```