# Typescript: How to defined type of object key for generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some piece of code like below. I write custom hook with generic type for defined custom type return of my hook.

```
type Return<T> = [T, (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void, Record<keyof T, boolean>, () => void]


function useInput<T>(): Return<T> {
    const [input, setInput] = useState<T>({} as T);
    const [isDirty, setDirty] = useState({} as Record<keyof T, boolean>);

    const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        setInput({
            ...input,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        setDirty({
            ...isDirty,
            [e.target.name]: true
        });
    };

    const resetInput = () => {
        Object.keys(input).forEach((v) => input[v] = ''); //this line i get error
        setInput({...input});
    };


    return [input, handleInputChange, isDirty, resetInput]
}

export default useInput;
```

My generic type `T` is object. But when I loop over this, I get this error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.` How can I defined type of key for generic type `T`? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `Object.keys` function is not generic parametrized, by this reason `v` in the forEach is always string. Here is reasoning why - [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript).

Thats said you cannot narrow type of `v` it will be just string. What you can do is type assertion:

```
 Object.keys(input).forEach((v) => input[v as keyof T] = '')
```

But you will get next error as you don't define that `T` has all values as strings, and you assign to it empty string. This is actually correct error. You cannot assign to every field of unknown object a string.

In order to fix the second we need to narrow the type of value of `T`

```
function useInput<T extends Record<string, string>>(): Return<T>
```

We are saying now `T` has keys and values which are `string` or subtypes of `string`. Because of the fact that they can be subtypes of string we need to do the second assertion after. Why - Subtype can be for example `'a' | 'b'` and such type cannot take empty string value.

```
Object.keys(input).forEach((v) => (input[v as keyof T] as string) = '')
```

But without stating that `T extends Record<string, string>` we would not able to assert property type of such to `string`.

As I said before such implementation has an issue, its risky as if you have object which is for example `type A { a: 'x' | 'y'}` and you pass it to such construct, then you can get empty string in property `a` and this is invalid member of type `A`. But if you work with types which have `string` values only, and I assume you do, then its fully ok.