# Filter generic list from partial object in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

How can I filter my generic list based on a partial object received?

Here is what I have so far:

```
export class GenericRestApiMock<T> {

    protected store: T[];

    public getByFilter(fitler?: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] } & { pageNumber?: 1; limit?: 10 }): Observable<T[]> {

        // filter store object

        return of<T[]>(...);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the objects to match all values in the filter, the solution could be easy enough. You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys of the filter (although, you will have to type assert the result of this is `Array<keyof T>`, see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) ). You can then use `filter` to go over all items in the array, and find the ones where all the keys match:

```
export class GenericRestApiMock<T> {

    protected store: T[];

    public getByFilter(fitler?: { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] } &  { pageNumber?: 1; limit?: 10 }): Observable<T[]> {
        if (!fitler) return of(this.store);

        // filter store object
        let filterKeys = Object.keys(fitler)
            .filter(k => k !== 'pageNumber' && k !== 'limit') as Array<keyof T>
        let filterValues = this.store.filter(o => filterKeys.every(k => fitler[k] === o[k]))
        let { pageNumber = 0, limit = 10 } = fitler;
        return of<T[]>(filterValues.slice(pageNumber * limit,pageNumber * limit+ limit ));
   }

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0wBo4IAzOAXzgqghDgHIoAPAK3WYFgAofpjaRYcAMaE86dHADimAHbZgYgEqZ0MAIJhgAWQhiA1gB4AKgD5E-fnDtwwDGJjHOAJnE3RMALjhmAbQBdAG4bPnsHAFciFTgAc0wYACEATwAxYEJnKAAKCmAYYigAfj8kAIAFOGAFOCNMVMp-ILL-KqCaOAAyOyQwPESAOSiQVGw2gEYQuEJQQqmABhoASj80LFwCYnNgqwRbSPtgKlyAQgKi7BW4KCSoqDrKXJgAC2B0ADovO5WwgQiRzsAHpgXQsjlPDBvORUBwXDBDkDiPACtlsABpRoyAC8KDhCM+DVS6HyhWKKyRQPsnzROVyRjgOKsjLOOLxzAGw1G4ygzB6vVZ7JYcxAhWYNykcC0UCgeFSJmJzUsVMiKPB6KgADU8IQohomXA3h9vtC7rSIdhchAmVY6ZjsZ9MDhsKkGbbwVcoAEjJ12XiID6gitKYDkUlEA5BpgRmNsIbFmRRYVDZNlrQ8Zdiv9qbd7o9yBRdkELGTNTq9RpvnMxJhclyYzz4wAqWbzGAkBux3lwVvJmAAajbYvgIZzdmo4WoQA)