# TypeScript - How to index a class by a string without losing class safety?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following TypeScript code snippet, which compiles and works successfully:

```js
class UserSettings {
  [key: string]: boolean;

  setting1: boolean = false;
  setting2: boolean = false;
  setting3: boolean = false;
  otherOtherSetting: boolean = true;
}

const settings = new UserSettings();

const checkSettingChanged = (setting: string, value: boolean) => {
  if (value !== settings[setting]) {
    console.log(`The setting of ${setting} changed, updating it!`);
    settings[setting] = value;
  }
};
```

However, this code sucks, because by specifying `[key: string]: boolean` in the class, we lose the class safety. In other words, the following code will compile successfully but give a runtime error:

```js
function someOtherFunction() {
  // Oops, I forgot to specify setting 4 in the class definition above,
  // so this code should fail to compile, but TypeScript doesn't care,
  // and now I will get a stupid runtime error
  if (settings.setting4) {
    console.log('Setting 4 is enabled!');
  }
}
```

Ok. So can I remove the `[key: string]: boolean` in the class definition? Let's try and see what happens:

```js
class UserSettings {
  // This is just a "normal" TypeScript class now
  setting1: boolean = false;
  setting2: boolean = false;
  setting3: boolean = false;
  otherOtherSetting: boolean = true;
}

const settings = new UserSettings();

const checkSettingChanged = (setting: string, value: boolean) => {
  // Hopefully, adding this runtime check should satisfy the TypeScript compiler
  if (!(setting in settings)) {
    throw new Error(`The setting of ${setting} does not exist in the UserSettings class.`);
  }

  if (value !== settings[setting]) {
    console.log(`The setting of ${setting} changed, updating it!`);
    settings[setting] = value;
  }
};
```

This code does **not** satisfy the TypeScript compiler. It fails on the `value !== settings[setting]` part, throwing the error of:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'UserSettings'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'UserSettings'.
```

What gives? How can I construct a runtime check that satisfies the TypeScript compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In will not work as a type guard to assert a string is a key of a type. You can create a custom type guard that will perform the narrowing:

```
class UserSettings {
  // This is just a "normal" TypeScript class now
  setting1: boolean = false;
  setting2: boolean = false;
  setting3: boolean = false;
  otherOtherSetting: boolean = true;
}

const settings = new UserSettings();
function isKeyOf<T>(p: PropertyKey, target: T): p is keyof T {
    return p in target;
}

const checkSettingChanged = (setting: string, value: boolean) => {
  // Hopefully, adding this runtime check should satisfy the TypeScript compiler
  if (!isKeyOf(setting, settings)) {
    throw new Error(`The setting of ${setting} does not exist in the UserSettings class.`);
  }

  if (value !== settings[setting]) {
    console.log(`The setting of ${setting} changed, updating it!`);
    settings[setting] = value;
  }
};
```

[Playground Link]([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=17&pln=11&pc=25#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOBlBAXdBLAdgcxgG8AoaaAenOgBUALLGB6AKwFcJ1oxoAiHAeyQBbMCB40AngAcEKYEixTOoSDAEB3UtESZceAIwAuaACN+-EAjA5oAXmgAzUYgDcWndnwAmY2YtWbeycQV3cMTzwAZl9zS2s7R2cENzJ+dFpkAHl05DRdfBj-ePt0JFZk4gBfYmJgfhwObXC9GHscBHU4RFRm-AgACgBKNwdWHGBseugGAGkECUyHAB5qAD5+qWMABSR+GSR0CTmJABpodDAkPAxjakHjKWmYAGt5-gcaaBIyMiQMViQNkeuHOl2u6Dc1Vq9UawAywGeeQiAGFaNZrgATBL9Dx6YwcBT4M4AN1E5UKcRwgzsqy+Wko0AAEnsEKMQCBTlwMRi9Od6DAyjhsEIENA4QgEdpaPxWCAsRAwNgIA4JHzRdRpLJ5IplPwhFIsJYkFosB9+gBCWbzRY43p4M64vqDanfH7pXaddqdACiSF2SH6AAM6KLHXhoO9oAASQhhyrQDH8BBqNLQBAADwYnBBOS6uTtMBUUAAdIHhlooWRTdB+qSQOVoObbPYwxAANphgC6Lq0ZDqDX8xZA-DwQZDTXy4cjMbjYrR+AQGLOrCkGMVvKw6HNZZSP1bHbtnYSdfKu+qlRcQA))

Not however that this is not fully type safe. Basic OOP dictates that you should be able to have in `settings` an instance of a class derived from `UserSettings`, which might not have all boolean values. You can read more about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) as it applies to `Object.keys`, but the same reasoning hold here. While in the general case it is not type safe, you can still use it with the specified caveat.

Comment: That code fails to compile, perhaps because I use TypeScript in strict mode. It complains: `'target' is declared but its value is never read`

Comment: @James fixed it, meant to use the target instead of settings

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the following? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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

Comment: @James that is no longer safe, you are assigning a `boolean | number` to a key that must be either `boolean` or `number`. Nothing is preventing this call: `checkSettingChanged('setting2',  true)`

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help.