# How to use TypeScript with Object.entries()?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've recently began using TypeScript on my own projects, though I'm not sure how I should go about getting my code to work.

```
Object.entries(data[`set_${id}`].tiles).map(([tileType, tiles]) => (
  tiles.map(([left, top]), index) => (
     //rest of code
  )
))
```

TypeScript is complaining that left, top, and index all have 'any' type. How can I go about assigning types in this configuration?

data.json Structure:

```
{
  "set_1": {
    "tiles": {
       "typeA": [[0, 1], [0, 2]],
       "typeB": [[2, 0], [2, 1]]
    }
  }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked best for me:

```
export function objectEntries<
  T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
  K extends keyof T,
  V extends T[K]
>(o: T) {
  return Object.entries(o) as [K, V][];
}
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! I believe it's also possible to change it a bit: `T extends { [key: string | number | symbol]: unknown},`

Comment: Yes, that probably works better, thank you!

Comment: Use `PropertyKey` or `keyof any` if you want a shorter alternative to `string | number | symbol`. They mean the same thing.

Comment: It's crazy that typescript still doesn't understand how to work with many functions. I still have to use this hack today in mid 2023.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work quickly by repeating the types:

```
for (const [k, v] of (Object.entries(o) as [number, any][]))
// typeof(k) === 'number'
// typeof(v) === 'any'
```

Sometimes you have to cast to `unknown` first, though:

```
for (const [k, v] of (Object.entries(o) as unknown as [number, any][]))
```

You can wrap this up into a utility function as well:

```
function objectEntries<K extends (string | number | symbol), V>(o: Record<K, V>) {
  return Object.entries(o) as unknown as [K, V][];
}

for (const [k, v] of objectEntries(o))
// typeof(k) matches key type of 'o'
// typeof(v) matches value type of 'o'
```

EDIT: The reason why this isn't done automatically is explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012175/308237).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Achieved by doing:

```
Object.entries(data[`set_${id}`].tiles).map(([tileType, tiles]) => (
  tiles.map(([left, top] : number[], index : number) => (
     //rest of code
  )
))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set them in this way:

```js
Object.entries(data[`set_${id}`].tiles).map(([tileType, tiles]) => (
  tiles.map(([left: number, top: number]), index: number) => (
     //rest of code
  )
))
```

Comment: Run your snippet ;)

Comment: Why would I want to do that? The snippet isn't a full code and doesn't have typescript installed.

Comment: `([ left: number, top: number ])` is an invalid Typescript syntax. It's not possible to add types within destructuring of an array, object.