# Expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

Sorry for creating another question of this type but even though there are similar ones I am not able to apply theirs solutions to my particular case.

Can someone please help me handle this TypeScript error?

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<RouteName, TranslatableRoute>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Record<RouteName, TranslatableRoute>'.(7053)
```

I am looking for the right way how to solve it not some workaround by destroying type safety. Here is some dummy example of where I hit the problem.

```
type RouteName = 'home' | 'account'

interface TranslatableRoute {
    cs: string;
    en: string;
}

const translatableRoutes: Record<RouteName, TranslatableRoute> = {
    home: {
        cs: '/',
        en: '/'
    },
    account: {
        cs: '/ucet',
        en: '/account'
    }
}

const findRoute = '/ucet'
const findLang = 'cs'

for (const key in translatableRoutes) {
    if (translatableRoutes[key][findLang] === findRoute) {
        console.log(`Found route\'s name is "${key}"!`)
    }
}
```

Typescript playground [link](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BAcgQwLbQLxQOQAWcWeUAPvmgMZWIB2weAUEwJYMQBOAZtdACqc0dAM4AbNMDQAjMRHhJoAbyZQ1UKiIBcUEcE7sA5gG5V6iHR16DdE0wC%20LWqOBR9w8ZJlyFybbAhaTgATAB5fVEwIABooQQ8JKVl5RGQAPihcFXUoIiwdbJz1TR08AHo8aLMiqAtSiuqoeyqc6loEBgLGnJL8MoQqCEYWmtrLPrb6RkbHRyZnPShudmCIzL6BoeYF12W6YIAZYUN1vE1mJm44TigACh2oAGsIECh2NyFRRO8UxREASighTUrG4d3cXy8yQiIgA2s8QABdWF7Q7HRGZbC4VERQHAooLOByAB0YjghluAAMAGL0YJQTipCAAHTwIigdCib3ZACIACRKBH2HkAQkp-xmDiAA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `key` is inferred as `string` rather than `keyof typeof translatableRoutes`, which would be correct in this case.

There's various [complex reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) why that isn't always safe to infer, but the end result is that TypeScript can't give `key` the right type for you automatically.

In addition, type annotations for for-in loops [aren't allowed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500), so you can't manually fix it inline.

Fortunately though, you can provide a type annotation separately. Replace your for-in loop with:

```js
let key: keyof typeof translatableRoutes;
for (key in translatableRoutes) {
    if (translatableRoutes[key][findLang] === findRoute) {
        console.log(`Found route\'s name is "${key}"!`)
    }
}
```

That's a little bit more cumbersome, but it gives `key` the correct type, and ensures that everything later works correctly and safely, with no type casting necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. Now I understand.