# Adding types to JSON object stored locally in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

This is the JSON Object that is stored locally

```
{
"data": {
    "John Doe": {"id":"1234", "username":"johndoe"},
    "Sia Xander": {"id":"1235", "username":"siax"}
  }
}
```

This is the TypeScript file that I have and I have created this function but it errors out

```
import { data } from "../Assets/data.json"

function createData(member: string, id: string, username: string) {
    return { member, id, username }
  }

interface Rows {
    member: string
    id: string
    username: string
  }

const rows: Rows[] = []

Object.keys(data).map(member =>
    rows.push(
      createData(
        member,
        data[member]["id"], //error
        data[member]["username"] //error
      )
    )
  )
```

I get the following error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type "data": {
    "John Doe": {"id":string, "username":string},
    "Sia Xander": {"id":string, "username":string}
  }
}
 No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

"data": {
    "John Doe": {"id": string , "username":string},
    "Sia Xander": {"id":string, "username":string}
  }
}
```

How do I tell TypeScript that "John Doe" and "Sia Xander" are strings?
Or should I change the way I have made the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Why it doesn't work:

This doesn't work because `Object.keys()` can return keys not present on the type of its argument. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/7282573) for more details.

---

### What would work instead:

Instead, try using `Object.entries`:

```
Object.entries(data).map(([member, memberData]) =>
  rows.push(
    createData(
      member,
      memberData["id"],
      memberData["username"]
    )
  )
);
```

`Object.entries` returns key value pairs, so you don't need to do the lookup yourself. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for more information.

---

### Also, you can use `.map` in a simpler way:

The way you're using `.map` works, but you can make it even simpler.

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array, so you don't need to use `push()`.

Instead, try this:

```
const rows: Rows[] = Object.entries(data).map(([member, memberData]) =>
  createData(
    member,
    memberData["id"],
    memberData["username"]
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've been struggling for a while now, I am new to TypeScript. This solution is so clean and simple, just love it.