# Map object entries without using "as"

Tags: typescript

```
const assets = {
  mapTileset: '',
  characterTileset: '',
};
const totalAssetCount = Object.keys(assets).length;

type assetKey = keyof typeof assets;

export class AssetLoader {
  assets: Record<assetKey, HTMLImageElement>;
  loadedCount = 0;
  onAssetsLoaded: VoidFunction;

  constructor(onLoaded: VoidFunction) {
    this.onAssetsLoaded = onLoaded;
    const assetMap = {} as Record<assetKey, HTMLImageElement>;

    Object.entries<string>(assets).forEach(([key, assetSrc]) => {
      const asset = new Image();
      asset.onload = this.onLoad;
      asset.src = assetSrc;
      assetMap[key as assetKey] = asset;
    });

    this.assets = assetMap;
  }

  private onLoad = () => {
    this.loadedCount++;
    if (this.loadedCount === totalAssetCount) {
      this.onAssetsLoaded();
    }
  };
}
```

I want to have typed assets map where keys are limited to the ones specified in another object.

Is there a way to write it without "as" in constructor?

Or any better way to write such code that will map `{key: assetSource}` -> `{key: loadedImage}` while keeping track of how many is already loaded

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/3398839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Use `as` or write a redundant array of keys.

---

The TypeScript standard library's [typing for `Object.entries(obj)`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a7c306f384b89f62df1e410882136b79c0fbbc47/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L34-L44), like its typing for [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a7c306f384b89f62df1e410882136b79c0fbbc47/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L261), returns keys of type `string`, and not `keyof typeof obj`.  This is frustrating to many people, but it works that way [for an important reason](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208): object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extendible*, and not *closed* or [*exact*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

Consider the following code:

```
interface Foo {
  x: string;
}
interface Bar extends Foo {
  y: number;
}
const b: Bar = { x: "", y: 1 };
const f: Foo = b; // okay
f.y; // error, y is not known to exist on Foo
console.log(Object.entries(f)); // [["x",""],["y",1]];
```

An object of type `Foo` is known to have a `string`-valued `x` property, but it is *not* known to *lack* other properties.  Since `Bar extends Foo`, it means every `Bar` is a valid `Foo`, so there could be some `Foo` objects with a `number`-valued `y` property.  Or really, any other unspecified property.  The only property of a `Foo` object that we know anything for certain about is `x`.  So `Object.keys(f)` needs to return an array of *at least* `"x"`, and maybe all kinds of other things.  So that becomes just `string`.

---

There's not much to be done here, then.  The compiler doesn't have a representation for types that it knows have no extra properties.  Its [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) functionality only works for object literals that have not yet been assigned anywhere.  Once you have assigned it to the `assets` variable, the compiler treats it like any other object-typed variable.  It has `mapTileset` and `characterTileset` keys, *and maybe all sorts of other keys*.

If you want to tell the compiler "no, it's just those keys", then you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions); either the way you have done, or at the `Object.entries()` call:

```
(Object.entries(assets) as [assetKey, string][]).forEach(([key, assetSrc]) => {
  const asset = new Image();
  asset.onload = this.onLoad;
  asset.src = assetSrc;
  assetMap[key] = asset;
});
```

They're both the same thing, though: you telling the compiler what it can't figure out for itself.

The other way to proceed is to make up your own array of known keys, like this:

```
(["mapTileset", "characterTileset"] as const).forEach(key => {
  const asset = new Image();
  asset.onload = this.onLoad;
  asset.src = assets[key];
  assetMap[key] = asset;
});
```

This doesn't use a type assertion at all, really. The `as const` there is called a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and asks the compiler to infer the array not as `string[]`, but as a readonly pair of string literals.  The code works without a problem and is arguably safer than your other code: if `assets` somehow *does* get other properties, you won't accidentally use them... but you pay for this safety by having to write a redundant array.

Usually I just use a type assertion, and move on.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200819#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIAeAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL66iSyIoBCcUyEhkIACZk0mHPmQBPUiACuAWwBG0ekwToQFZItJceAXhxFSAIhMAaKaQCMyBvXWawyGKQxZDi2sgD0P5OgA1nCSuDAAdJLefrxQUOhQlpLIwCIg6M6B6QDuIMhgWHypzhqi6LiOZOgANhDh1ejUABQA8ooAVhAIYOEQ4FQQZE0wAJQj0f4A2pMmhBZmALrmM5IW1gsL9LgVGlpwZGQQYCKGeATycAAOACrAtYdgpADkT+YSCAAW3Iist-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-mOwFYZ+RwQVBMGlmQEHpjJ4GoQgRH4vhkibKB2EPLhOmEYYPIkWR2xvrBymylpRy4V6TASJcVAAG5wJA3rpoywFCWcxbWfU9ZOi64AANRhYhwBsk0gVQSFiLIvoyXgmAkKVqFYCFv5VlKRBlb+sFgjSaBTAEPYjBAA)

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! After reading this I ended up writing helper function that just returns keys of T so I can reuse that kind of Object.keys later