# TypeScript: How do I add proper typing to this function with Object.entries

Tags: typescript

Here is the [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCiAWKDeAUMsnAFzJEkkBGFV1JCFAzmFKAOYDaAugNzFGyACat2XQYwC+U5LMLTCCAPYg2yMDi4sAKioBKEALYqAbigC8ybgCIwhk+YgBGWwBpk9x6YsAmWwFlNQ0EXAgKDGwEPGRrBnJKIVp6ZOpmG28jX1cPLwcABSgIFmgLN08sp3887yKSsogA3nc0kjEvYChigBsIMzhwWzSlEiUFQjB0AAcUVDhp2ZFdKEGWGBUoYwAeXWQIAA9IEBEWSmkAPjikkm4AaWRQZABrCHQVGGRdXgB+SIWlis1hstrt7rwrgAfZAAChh0zgq2MLAounBAEo4ldBuh0YIJjAAK4gBBgYBqTSrCxQUrbAwXGFhGIRZAGTzsYGbYwAeRoACsIKT-osIMtVuoQTt6ZiGMUwISoCBkLyBaSAHQQcAcEowjkSrkqwVgdFq4oiQlIGFmi0QIH6rYAORUIggniZeDxikIhAA9D7kDgVAB3UQqZAASU0MxQWmAZ0AvBuAcR3guowMhrUg7esuU6XddGeFc66bHrs1s7m92eKy8YAGpwHqEiC8TGWK4MVSpygl6uSivoXgUEDOlDSa7uiBFuSdjQgCBB6J4euNqxpKazD6UzlbZdNuKWay2IkkslqYbCZA-Lf2usNpsw4cu9FtZAUDnU0q63tc3fFx8QT0hDlBUlQYEg1Qgici1aRhuFLPs3kHZA5wXcJfyEBQJnfaBaSicIGQnTwElSRg6BuYQMgfEdWyuf81RgYAekgKA4TYDgQE4GjkAAQljDi9B8Zw1VABBGxdFgYTYrh0WfGQMMUT0gA)

I am trying to type this function

```js
const reduceTransformNode = (cacheNode, [transformKey, transformValue]) => {
  const { [transformKey]: node } = cacheNode;
  const newCacheValue =
    typeof transformValue === "function"
      ? transformValue(node)
      : traverse(transformValue, node);

  return {
    ...cacheNode,
    [transformKey]: newCacheValue
  };
};
```

I cannot seem to solve it because there seems to be a circular dependency between `traverse` and `reduceTransformNode`

This is one [solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GILWIHIAtJhzMi1SaZPW9AyvtdHL52RdHrM6yAPI0ABWECpwNWEHWD61l5uDrILoTqjuOk7Pm+VLTvyEilJ2v57BB75gNi070oyEAIuhTIIeyi6hOEQ7EjMQSqAY6DMt2BhIR+aAgt+lGsvsUThHc8RCIkDApFOGQUPW-q4mYdwDtOMDAH0kBQAiVp4sgACE6iaDoOQONOoAIKaXIsNJ7C4k24xyMRgSRnSpRkhJ9xnu23IsYq17hK45GMVqNEocZKiKAM059IonBYWZElEoQQA) I found that would work but not ideal.

```
function reduceTransformNode<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(cacheNode: T, [transformKey, transformValue]: [string, any]): T {
  const { [transformKey]: node } = cacheNode;
  const newCacheValue =
    typeof transformValue === "function"
      ? transformValue(node)
      : traverse(transformValue, node);

  return {
    ...cacheNode,
    [transformKey]: newCacheValue
  };
};
```

I don't want to have `any` in the code. Can anyone give this trick TypeScript problem a try

Comment: "I don't want to have `any`", but when I look at the demo I see `((params: T[K]) => any)`.  I doubt you'd be happy if someone called `traverse<MyCache>(cache, { a: () => 1 })`.  Could you clean that up so that I understand what the typings are really supposed to be?  Also, all the code in a [mcve] should be in the text of the question and not just in an external link, as mentioned in [ask].  The playground links are great but do not suffice here (I spent a while asking "what `Object.entries`?" before I realized you left your code out of the question).

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/lm0dqm) what you're looking for?  If so, I'll write it up.  If not, please elaborate.

Comment: @jcalz hi thanks for the reply. Yes I probably shouldn't use `any` as in `((params: T[K]) => any`, the idea is that it is a function that filters the field and returns the filtered items. I just don't know how to type it so I leave it as `any`. And yes `traverse<MyCache>(cache, { a: () => 1 })` it not ok. Also I think you are on the right track. Please finish it. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the use case, but my inclination would be to give things the following types.  First of all, we should decide what the return type of function-like transformed methods should be; `any` is not restrictive enough.  It looks like you want to use a `reduce`-like function, so perhaps the transformations should preserve the type of the input:

```
type MappedTransform<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: MappedTransform<T[K]> | ((params: T[K]) => T[K]); // <-- not any, right?
};
```

Since you're using `Object.entries()` it might be helpful to give define an `Entries<T>` type that evaluates to a union of the key-value tuples for an object type `T`.

```
type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];
```

The `Object.entries()` typings in TypeScript only returns something like `[string, any]` because object types in TypeScript are not "exact" (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12946](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-711172739)) and can always have more properties than the compiler knows about; (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63510124/2887218) for more info).  So if you want to tell the compiler that `Object.entries(transformObject)` only has the entries known about in the type `MappedTransform<R>`, you need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function traverse<R>(cache: R, transformObject: MappedTransform<R>): R {
  return (
    Object.entries(transformObject) as Array<Entries<MappedTransform<R>>>
  ).reduce(reduceTransformNode, cache);
}
```

We are claiming above that `traverse()` takes a `cache` of type `R` and returns a value of the same type `R`.  (This is only technically true for the outermost call to `traverse()` and not the inner recursive calls, so we'll have to use another type assertion inside `reduceTransformNode()` below).

In order for `reduceTransformNode()` to be usable as a callback to `reduce()` above, its typing needs to be be a function from an accumulator of type `R`, a value of type `Entries<MappedTransform<R>>`, and return a new accumulator of type `R`:

```
const reduceTransformNode = <R, K extends keyof R>(
  cacheNode: R,
  [transformKey, transformValue]: [K, MappedTransform<R[K]> | ((params: R[K]) => R[K]) | undefined]
): R => {
  const { [transformKey]: node } = cacheNode;

  // optional properties can technically be present but undefined, so let's deal with that
  if (typeof transformValue === 'undefined') return cacheNode;

  const newCacheValue =
    typeof transformValue === "function"
      ? (transformValue as (params: R[K]) => R[K])(node)
      : traverse(transformValue as R[K], node); // NOTE!
  // ----------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // transformValue is a MappedTransform<R[K]> and not an R[K].  But
  // traverse expects R[K] as its first parameter, so we need an assertion
  // this is probably because in this recursive call to traverse, you are not
  // just converting an initial R[K] to a final R[K].  It's possible that
  // this type assertion is indicative of some problem, but it's hard for me
  // to pinpoint. It's safer than any, at least

  return {
    ...cacheNode,
    [transformKey]: newCacheValue
  };
};
```

We can get better type safety guarantees from the compiler if the value is of type  `[K, MappedTransform<R[K]> | ((params: R[K]) => R[K]) | undefined]` for a generic `K extends keyof R` instead of the essentially equivalent `Entries<MappedTransform<R>>`.  That's so the implementation of `reduceTransformNode()` can be seen as acting upon a single property of `R` and not on a union of all properties of `R`.

As you can see, we have a type assertion in the inner recursive call to `traverse()`. It's possible one can type `traverse()` to work for both the outermost call where the output type matches the input type and inner calls where the output type is a transformed version of the input type... but I couldn't find one in the time I spent on it.  Instead I would use a type assertion with an explanatory comment (like above) and move on.

---

Let's test it:

```
const x = traverse(cache, {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: (node) => node.filter((s) => !thingsToRemove.includes(s))
    }
  }
});
console.log(x.a.b.c.map(x => x.toLowerCase()).join(", ")); // topreserve1, topreserver2
```

Looks good. `x` has the type `MyCache` and the compiler infers that the `transformObject` parameter's `a.b.c` callback is of type `string[]` (which is good) to `string[]`.

---

Again, it's possible that I missed the use case and there are things you need that are incompatible with the typings above.  But hopefully it gives you some direction.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCiAWKDeAUMsnAFzJEkkBGFV1JCFAzmFKAOYDaAugNzFGyACat2XQYwC+U5LMLTCCAPYg2yMDi4sAKioBKEALYqAbigC8ybgCIwhk+YgBGWwBpk9x6YsAmWwFlNQ0EXAgKDGwEPGRrBnJKIVp6ZOpmG28jX1cPLwcABSgIFmgLN08sp3887yKSsogA3nc0kjEvYChigBsIMzhwWzSlEiUFQjB0AAcUVDhp2ZFdKEGWGBUoYwAeXQA+OKSSbgBpZFBkAGsIdBUYZF1eAH5IhaWVtY2t3dPeA4AfZAACiB0zgq2MLAoul+AEo4gcYSdeLD+MgAPTo5DbAC0OOQIBUYFIIHQng4nBwYCeikEhEmMxQAFFwBwSrsDvEbGcLtdbvdHjiXtzPEjeLx5Nw+XcHkFCDAAK4gBBgYBqTSrCxQUrbAx7IFhGIRZAGTzsT6bYwAeRoACsICrXosIMtVuovjs9bCKAYjshimAFVAQMC0jb7SqAHQQVnAEpA83uy3hh1geFwFjIACC3Tg6G2LIk7PmztdFu+er2eyEsMjxRECqQQPrjYgHyTWwAcioRBBPIa8KjFPTVOpiS2kO31pbu73DrrPGcIAAPSAgESZ6X3PVAoQDiCz42moTcRPTrYnG5mt3n4wANTgPQVEF4FFOnhL7xvHt1vwBwNBcE4EhH04QRE0wMBJVexgUAXV4QhvRNcCGFHDR8BsM8PUvdBXwJHsUGkQ590POkSExZAVGmVU1EfZBpigKjoFVEpkDCENIBiEBgDCHoenQZAaBQBiGnAQSFWJaCIFgkAXU8FgVGQPowAAckzXs6IAd2ALRNBwOAwCEYB7gTRkZSwy0HyfKxLGsFSpJkl0VPhAMgxDEiCLItiQmJWTNOiPArOfOI0imWZzO-SzH2C2zrFsRVlRokBbGQNpkCeYELK2IKUAzYEwQhKEIOReFLAOAw4SBQle1hNKKHNLVSgTSLsui3LMwq5FPGqiBUQxLFOytXQmQAQiECi8UmqacQOAA-eaFsWpbltm8asSy+82vOTM4DQN4XSnH9Or+EkRHw4lBmK3hIxIAAhCS1o1OBGpQFdZhVDrflITMdMzWDtWJArgIgSAoHkxTNJQWSXRJb7SigJLHq0YAfszBiVBoOAaH4wSHTgBVSnODjtEzYoECDFhgAsNjHx6TRFIa6BSk8W4FVIYpzse20CeJUctVVEBOFh0AdOAOjjvp0hkBk8Xfhu5AAElVLRlQWEp7GUC0AykZJzRGTh5i1RDFGiZEHiDKplAZQU4xhMYjXjE8GgJPOZXkH0qAzq+ZBbaRxTplAaYVFAMAbqVtTkBYOAYGgPTLsGMlSGJPoM0MoRXODP0SEjHOPN7VpGFPFrjBwvC-ICiAcqEBQJmCMdkGXQ5Ge1CADXCTwElSRg6Cz9IKCqgjSoOHrI1gnpQZBFgh+QEbkcFvQfGcSNQAQJ9exYIEp9qmRq8UIc0JUPpIx6FROCBZdIzgSMaEjBBI2MBZz-Ai+HAAGRUSGoGwJrYVrW1g5AECWov80QUQcCJeG5QzRUWKJA6AfhCBAA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Really appreciate it! There is just one thing I forgot to mention in the description, which is that the transform function we have here, which in your solution has this type `((params: T[K]) => T[K])`, the `params` here can only be an array, i.e. `(node) => node.filter((s) => !thingsToRemove.includes(s))` here the `node` can only be an array. Also the result of this function is also going to remain as an array, i.e. `newCacheValue ` is an array. It is possible to add this type assertion for this function?

Comment: Ideally we can provide a second generic type in addition to `T` in `type MappedTransform<T>`, for example, `MappedTransform<T, U>`, here U is for the type of the array which is exactly  `node`'s type. I am not sure if it is possible to do that. But really thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: Possibly, yes!  But I don’t know if I can commit to putting more effort into this answer for a while.  My hope in posting the solution code as a comment was that any missing use case would be exposed then, and the question scope would stabilize before I wrote up an answer.  Now that I have written one up, I’m less inclined to dedicate more resources to scope creep.

Comment: That's totally fine. Thanks for the effort. I really learned a lot from it. Just wondering if there is any quick fix we can do to assert that `node` is an array of any kind? Thanks for the answer really appreciate it.