# What's the cleanest way to tell typescript that each element of Object.keys(foo) is really a key of foo?

Tags: typescript

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoG2YEMBcMAjADRY4BGhATGTjMIQMwYC+A3BhgPIUBWAU2BQAdAGsBATwgAKBCACUIhACcAormAALGRMkoAfOnLZ5AbT0BdANTXOrBUA)

```js
const foo = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {
  foo[key]++; // error: expression of type 'string' can't be used to index ....
})
```

There must be multiple ways to solve it. I'm looking for a recommended way with least impact on readability. Thanks!

==========

Edit:

Bonus: would be great if I can still have autocompletion when I type `foo.` in my codebase.

Comment: `(key: keyof typeof foo)`? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript for discussion.

Comment: [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoGMCGAuGARgBosYAjAgJlO2AIGYMBfAbgw1ElgGsBTAJ4QUMAPLkAVn2BQAdPyG5hAHgAqAPgAUIAqoCUKdTE0BRAB5QATjhnKFIODFXEY0SwEswAc3V6A2gC67Jzg0PCIANKCwqgKEJoIIHrBXBAgADZ8sukgXgmR0ckwAPTFMH4ARDgVLhXkNTAVwBUBQA) is the solution from the github issue linked in that related question. It uses `Extract` to get all keys that are assignable to `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript provides no way to express this at the time foo is declared because somebody might later add additional properties to `foo`, for instance by:

```
let o: any;
o = foo;
o.x = 'hello';
```

Then, `Object.keys(foo)` will also return `x`, but trying to increment `'hello'` is probably not what you intend ...

More generally, in typescript, an object may always contain surplus properties, because this is what allows you to do:

```
interface Person = {
    name: string;
}

interface Student extends Person {
    university: string;
}

let student: Student = ...;
let person: Person = student;
```

That is, TypeScript can never be sure that an Object has no surplus properties, and that's why `Object.keys` returns `Array<string>` rather than `Array<keyof typeof foo>`.

In your case, I might do:

```
const fooKeys = Object.keys(foo) as Array<keyof typeof foo>;
```

right after declaring foo. That way, we take a snapshot of the keys we intend to iterate over before anybody else has a chance to modify them. Then, you can do:

```
fooKeys.forEach(key => {
    foo[key]++;
});
```

Comment: Accepted this answer, but note that [ZYinMD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63794568/8238314) is good too (and cleaner) if you write the loop at the same time when the desired value of `foo` is produced / imported / declared.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```js
(Object.keys(foo) as (keyof typeof foo)[]).forEach(key => {
    foo[key]++;
})
```

This isn't automatically done for you, because in theory it could be unsafe, but I played with various scenarios and couldn't produce a working demo with a runtime error.

Comment: You can find such a scenario if you follow the link from jonrsharpe's comment on the question. Briefly, the problem is that someone could do: `let o: any = foo; o.x = 'hello'`. That is, objects are allowed to have surplus properties in typescript, which is why Object.keys might return a key not present in the type of foo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way would be to add a type to `foo`.

```
const foo: { [key: string]: number } = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
```

Comment: This allows for example `foo.d = 1`. Foo's exact type would be `{ a: number; b: number; c: number }`

Answer (score 0):

Type foo as a [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```js
const foo: Record<string, number> = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};

Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {
    foo[key]++;
})
```

See the [updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGAlApqATgEwDzRYCWYA5gDQxgCuAtgEbpYB8MAvDAN4BQMfMAQxQBGcr370UAJjH8YwFAGZuAXwDc3bgHl6AK0xQAdAGt0ATwgAKBCACUhhFgCiA4AAtLps+1Y85NgG0vAF0AalCNFVsgA)

Comment: This also fails due to `foo.d = 1` being possible. The exact type of foo should be `{ a: number; b: number; c: number }`

Comment: @MikeS. true, depends on what the OP actually needs, the way the question was asked made me believe they were handling a dictionary like object