# Dynamic type error- type is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

```
    type CardId = 'slot1' | 'slot2' | 'slot3';
    
    interface CardInfo {...}
    
    interface Card {
      [_:CardId]: CardInfo
      getByName: (name: string) => CardInfo | undefined;
    }
```

Now, if I call it like this:

```
   const myCard: Card = {
      slot1 : {
        ...
      },
      slot2 : {
        ...
      },
      slot3 : {
        ...
      }
   }
```

I got some error like this:

```
Type '{ slot1: { ... } ... ' is not assignable to type 'Card'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'slot1' does not exist in type 'Card'.ts(2322)
```

Why is that?

---

EDIT

Here are my attempts on [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJwCYEklQLxQOQGcA2A9sAIzZQA%20OBxATOVXkcAMzkBQAlgHbAQIAzOAGNo8ZCm4DCUAN7soiqAIQQAjgC4o3AK4BbAEb8ANAqXc4eiFtzAEPAOamlUPXADW1nKEhlK38Ah6f2wfCDZ2AF8uXn4hUVhEdHkXAG1PEC1xVCQAXSykyWkzRQcIYAAhEAA5Sy8ACgsrGztHAEpMAD5EiSkZKh1uJAgBHggkAG4o9nYAelm7EChgGTdPKE5gZcDjKBQoAHdOfHwoIlxoYAALaAFB4WBOQm52MKgAeTBH59xMHEI-IxCMEgREeHxBCJoJ9vtwAErqHScVRWXhyMy4QhWCqEQj4LQGXH4CBwbhTRSYqwAZVa3AcLXsdKm0TeMKe8MRyIgqOAvywKSg6QgSx4Hy%207Nw%20TFsIRaiRKIgvHJUDKlRqdS0jQ1UFsjIcHQw3V1jn8g2Go2442ZQA)

Comment: There is a misspelling here.  (name: stirng) -->   (name: string)

Comment: @AliBektash sorry, that was a typo, my question stays the same.

Comment: Can you please create a TypeScript playground. It's much easier to click in.

Comment: @dwjohnston good point, I will do that right now

Comment: Judging by the type error you've got on the playground, the type error you've got is this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037941/typescript-object-indexes

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJwCYEklQLxQOQGcA2A9sAIzZQA+OBxATOVXkcAMzkBQAlgHbAQIAzOAGNo8ZCm4DCUAN7soiqAIQQAjgC4o3AK4BbAEb8ANAqXc4eiFtzAEPAOamlUPXADW1nKEhlK38Ah6f2wfCDZ2AF92GLDYRHQsACUIYUJkAB5xVCRjeIkpQgA+KAAyOTMHCGAAIRAAOUsvAAoLKw1be24HAEpMEuzJaX8dbiQIAR4IJCioGPY07ltXEGyoLTWseUUaUi1tpRV1LRI8s0U2rwAiaUIrs5c3Ty0rsJIrs0iHpV3affPlKpNFBTnMXJcXrd7mClE9rm8PoovjCAbsWP8XEdgaCARCoDdCHdvoo4S8EZ8zpVqnVGu0oK0mn0MCUDopVMAdAhuBUXIosVoAJwC4nmJovOASiXQgEkjzwwLvAHRJFmGLRdhAA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript object indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037941/typescript-object-indexes)

Comment: did my answer fix your issue?

Comment: You guys are awesome! I came back late, thanks it helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type CardId = 'slot1' | 'slot2' | 'slot3';
    
interface CardInfo {

}
```

## Method 1

##### using Type Mapping

In order to work, you need to make sure you use **type** keyword for Card.

`interface Card` ❌

`type Card` ✅

```
type Card = { [key in CardId]: CardInfo;} & {  getByName?: (name: string) => CardInfo | undefined}
```

## Method 2

##### using Typescript Utility Types.

```
type Card = Record<CardId, CardInfo> & {  getByName?: (name: string) => CardInfo | undefined}
```

*for more details, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html*

```
const myCard: Card = {
  slot1 : {},
  slot2 : {},
  slot3 : {}
}
```

now if you try to make a card like this, it will give you an error.

```
const myCard: Card = {
  slot1 : {},
  slot2 : {},
  slot3 : {},
  imNotASlot: {} // invalid key type ❌
}
```