# Populating a Record with concurrent promises

Tags: typescript

Example code:

```
type I = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const is: Record<I, null> = { 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': null}

// replace with any async processing function of your choice
function asyncRandomize(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), 1000))
}

const irandomized: Promise<[I, number][]> = Promise.all(
    Object.keys(is).map((i: I) => 
        asyncRandomize()
            .then((v): [I, number] => [i, v])
    )
)
```

Is there a way to make `irandomized` have type `Promise<Record<I, number>>` instead of `Promise<[I, number][]>` without going through `any`?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you will need a function that works like [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), although the TypeScript typings for that function will result in something a little too wide for your liking (you might get `Record<string, number>` instead of `Record<I, number>`.  If you don't mind using type assertions you can just do that:

```
const irandomized  = Promise.all(
   (Object.keys(is) as I[]).map((i: I) =>
      asyncRandomize()
         .then((v): [I, number] => [i, v])
   )
).then(z => Object.fromEntries(z)) as Promise<Record<I, number>>;
```

You're not using `any` there.

---

If you don't want to use type assertions in your code, you can make your own function like `Object.fromEntries()` whose typings are a little more specific (although type assertions or the like need to happen inside the implementation of that function).  Here's one possible function that might work for you:

```
type Entry = readonly [PropertyKey, any];
type ExtractSupertype<T, U> = T extends any ? [U] extends [T] ? T : never : never;
function fromEntries<E extends readonly Entry[]>(entries: E): {
   [K in E[number][0]]: ExtractSupertype<E[number], readonly [K, any]>[1] // TS 4.0-
   // [K in E[number] as K[0]]: K[1] // TS 4.1+, easier syntax
} {
   const ret: any = {};
   for (let entry of entries) {
      ret[entry[0]] = entry[1];
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Note that when TypeScript 4.1 is released and introduces [mapped type `as` clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336), the `ExtractSupertype` formulation will be unnecessary.

You can take that and hide in a library somewhere.  The idea is that `fromEntries()` should be able to turn a strongly-typed array or tuple of entries and turn it into a strongly-typed object:

```
const foo = fromEntries([
   ["x", Math.random()], ["y", new Date()], ["z", Math.random() < 0.5]
] as const);
/* const foo: {
    x: number;
    y: Date;
    z: boolean;
} */
```

You can see that instead of just getting `Record<string, number | Date | boolean>`, you actually get the specific properties associated with specific types.

Armed with that, you can do something like this with no more unsafe type assertions:

```
const iKeys = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
const irandomized = Promise.all(
   iKeys.map((k) =>
      asyncRandomize()
         .then(v => [k, v] as const)
   )
).then(fromEntries);
```

Note that I changed `is` to just an array of its keys.  You weren't doing anything with its values anyway, and the compiler sees `Object.keys(is)` as `string[]` instead of `I[]` (and for good reason, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)), so I opted to cut out the middleman and use a strongly-typed tuple of keys instead.

Anyway you can verify that `irandomized` is of the type you expect:

```
/* const irandomized: Promise<{
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}> */
```

and that it works as you expect at runtime:

```
irandomized.then(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)));
// {"a":0.9961594084980729,"b":0.015675814053288217,"c":0.1783156372032898}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=4.0.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxA9mpBvAUE-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-NFmbE+sWjs9gcjj3ztA-ncHhBnq8IO9PjKfpObmMgaDsbiobCEXCkThUcRSEh-YHYtQ-CB+sBdLE+SdSApiABpNmaaJEAW8Y-IX0AD0DBACAAZW0J9fxUJ5NAAVSMagniQCBAN1JQoHzWIAH4jRgy1kIIVD0L5J5LWwxDzAgW5agoqjeGbdoq3yP0AyDaAVF9JCUJxdCrxvO9TxYohBQMUZdUDYMpFPQ1cA8PkX3EfZfT5BMLT5OEBQFaQAKA9owIgkgFiUlSFAFTReKEfi5I-GIBQMPkYUtdMnhApAABYQThABaFp0zkhTT2U-sLR5F81I06RQocrwfGctyQRhABqTQIC6YNam6AgQH-Q9sDRIQRAzAhpE-YwsBcXgPDyNBalGXRZyQwSygqMTWKgbkZM1HY+RaoT1Mtagevs78USHWcRx2FM+HRAqqswagfQGM9WtGPkWj5AAif91s0DdwjBDsJlMo11qIbbRyQAARYEuyOjahjO3b9pVMAvhUJA4RBABWAUcEtLo6nyghxl4TwACoAYxfIMGkDr8H-WxzQUCqPCIaQroI5H8CGaQWAwOrohTJBQc8KbAfEN92WMDaQDO9aWFp+B1r+9DpoIXhWfELdVQgAlqHHUlyRaMQKagEUxU+ZllzlLpFWVXFhi7DUtRdUZritPlmVtZmIZER18GRZ1wl1UYFrAJaJOBtNwY5rEOwVpRplmKNYaiBHE0xpAWDd1YPfgb2kcPIxib4W3nvt7Ujb1acdauEldDQbJRgAKRA6kADkQREIMcjEPIiFEpFLfTLB1ppyQPoATgrgA2GFPor1y4QADlcium7hAB2AAmCv1Dp9by48uvq47z6m5hRvPoAZi7pum67mEO77xnB8Xpup+Hqfu7hGem7btwgA)