# Assign properties from an object to another object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I two objects with many properties. I want to copy properties from one object to the other only if it's defined.

Here is the object interface:

```
interface Settings {
  locale: string;
  currency: string;
  style: string;
  isDark: boolean;
  // There are more fields here
}
```

The two objects are defined like this:

```
const settings: Settings = {/*assign all fields here*/}
const settingsChange: Partial<Settings> = {/*change some fields*/}
```

Now I need to assign the fields in `settingsChange` to `settings`, I am trying to do this just like I were to do it in javascript

```
Object.entries(settingsChange).forEach(([key, value])=>{
  settings[key] = settingsChange[key] || settings[key]
})
```

Here is the typescript linting error I receive:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Settings'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Settings'.ts(7053)
```

How do I solve this ? I know that `Object.assign` would work but `Object.entries` gives me more freedom to apply whatever logic I need.

Comment: You can just do: `(settings as any)[key]` to bypass the type error

Answer (score 1):

```js
settings = {
  ...settings,
  ...settingsChange
};
```

You can do something like this if you need to do some logic on the values:

```js
settings = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(settings).map(([key, value]) => {
  const newValue = (settingsChange as keyof Settings)[key] ?? value;
  return [key, newValue];
})) as Settings;
```

Comment: This is just like `Object.assign`. I want to use `Object.entries`. It's not a javascript problem. It' a typescript problem. I kind of need to give the right types to make `Object.entries` work

Comment: Thanks for your attempt but this still is not the solution. using `as any` to overcome typescript type checking is never a typescript solution.

Comment: You will need to typecast, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript
If you prefer you could typecast the key to be `keyof Settings` instead of using `any`. I will edit my answer to show this