# How to have typescript check for valid object property names

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript and have an object defined with different people's names:

```
const data = {
   John: someTypedVariable,
   Alex: someTypedVariable,
   Anna: someTypedVariable,
   ... hundreds more added over time
}
```

If I were to try and access `data.missingValue` it would correctly fail to compile.

If I try to iterate the object:

```
for(const key in data){
   const item = data[key]; // error
}
```

> `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ John: ....`

I can change `data` to:

```
const data: Record<string, someTypedVariable> = {
    ...
}
```

but then I'd lose the typings which would allow errors like `data.missingValue`.

So is there a way to guarantee a valid property without explicitly defining a list of keys, like:

```
type keys = "John" | "Alex" | "Anna" | ...hundreds more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to iterate over the object's keys with `for..in`, assert that the key is a property of the object after defining it:

```
for (const key in data) {
    const typedKey = key as keyof typeof data;
    const item = data[typedKey];
}
```

(or inline it, if you don't use `typedKey` again)

Another option, to retrieve both the key and value at once, is to use `Object.entries`:

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, item]) => {
  // ..
});
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this behavior, while frustrating, is intentional.  Object types in TypeScript are not [exact/closed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) and so the compiler does not know for sure that `data` has *only* the keys it knows about.  [This question/answer about `Object.keys()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) explains in more detail.