# Recursive object literal in TypeScript with generics

Tags: typescript

Say I have an object:

```
{
  ItemA: {},
  ItemB: {
    SubitemA: {
      SubitemB: {}
    }
  },
  ItemC: {}
}
```

I would like to define a recursive type in TypeScript for the objects with the same structure using generics. I don't know how to do it correctly, I tried this:

```
type Items<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Items<T[K]>|{};
};
```

Then in my code I would like to have type checking:

```
function doSomething<T>(items: Items<T>){
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(items)){
     // For Typescript v is undefined here
     if(Object.keys(items).length > 0){
        doSomething(v)
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the generic represent here? And how do the keys change for every level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you're running into here is that `Object.entries(items)`'s typing does not generally return a strongly-typed array of entries corresponding to the known properties of `items`.  Instead, returns `Array<[string, unknown]>` (that is [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#unknown), not [`undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#null-and-undefined) as your comment mentions).

This is because TypeScript's object types aren't [*exact*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  A value of the type `{foo: string}` *must* have a `string`-valued `foo` property, but it *might* have any other properties of any other type.  The canonical SO question/answer about this sort of issue is [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript), where `Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]` instead of `Array<keyof typeof obj>`.

So, technically speaking, the compiler is correct to say it doesn't know what `v` is there.  I don't know what you're really going to do inside of `doSomething()`, but it is technically possible for the recursive call to hit non-`Items` properties where `Object.entries()` gives an error.  For example:

```
interface Foo {
     a: {}
}
interface Bar extends Foo {
     b: null;
}
const bar: Bar = {a: {}, b: null};
const foo: Foo = bar;
doSomething(foo); // ERROR AT RUNTIME! Can't convert null to object
```

The compiler accepts `doSomething(foo)` because `foo` is of type `Foo`, which matches `Items<{a: unknown}>`.  But it turns out `foo` is also of type `Bar` (which `extends Foo` and is therefore a valid `Foo`).  And when you call `doSomething(foo)` you will hit a runtime error, because `Object.entries(foo)` returns at least one entry you didn't expect.

---

If you are not worried about such edge cases, you could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to give a stronger type to the return value of `Object.entries()`:

```
type Entry<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T]

function doSomething<T>(items: Items<T> | {}) {
     for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(items) as Array<Entry<Items<T>>>) {
          console.log(k, v);
          doSomething(v); // okay now
     }
}
```

The type `Array<Entry<Items<T>>>` is probably what you imagine `Object.entries(items)` to return assuming that `items`'s type were exact/closed... `Array<Entries<Foo>>` is, for example, `Array<["a", {}]>`.  This will cause the compiler to infer that `v` is of type `Items<T>[keyof T]` which is going to be some kind of `object`.

Again, this doesn't prevent the edge cases like `doSomething(foo)` mentioned above; it just assumes they won't happen.

---

Also, if you didn't notice, I needed to widen the type of `items` from `Items<T>` to `Items<T> | {}`, so that recursive calls can be seen as safe by the compiler.  Hopefully that is acceptable to you.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsDOAeAKgPigXigbwFgAoKU0gbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMyjQF0AuWeMnRVuWAD74AvgG5iM4sVCQoAUTrAATiHRZceKFVoNmbTjwC0Afn5UANFxHcok8iY5duCouwCudAMbANKwMACasAMqsCBDAABb0AOY6ABQ0gkj8cIiomFASeJIAlPjEZKTsrBpQKf4hSMAGjPYAbk7uAPIARgBWEIEAdBDqGjQQSGkZJQCGSFAAghoa09pqmtrZQpgYGCWEJOWHdXRIrAA2EANnrIkpzVAtRbIHh2ThUTHxSSmPZeWSUDkXno8A07Gm-mgADFWKxSi9SNN+IUgUQQRAwRDoAAhabVCAAD3gdFCcxhcP2hy6-DoPjOZ2ekmIxwaUC6eP4uOqeiRUns1KgtPp8iILMalVY-HJODZeOe72isQSdFuEqeUAA9BrVAAlHUdHUAQigAGFpnQAOSNY4tDGNIVnKDAOGsXr9YBeBWfZW3SnlTbzZGSWx-MibbHI0OvKARHxddKIQPw6Mp2PxwQRqRR15MhHOEN5zYmoNyIpeIA)