# Iterate over object's keys and values in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, iteration

In plain JavaScript we can iterate over object props and values like so:

```js
const values = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
```

In TypeScript this syntax is wrong because the TS compiler is displaying the following message:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type Object.

Is there an alternative way not using Map<string, T> to do it and get the value of each key?

I encountered this problem while building an app using React and TS and I have in my state an object which I need to do something like this:

```js
const stateJSX: HTMLParagraphElement[] = Object.keys(obj).map(key => <p>`${key}: ${obj[key]}`<p>);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can easily use it with some help of `keyof` operator:

```js
const test = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj: T) => {
 return (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).map(key => obj[key])
}
```

You should asure TS, that `key` variable could be used as index for `obj` argument

Comment: You may want to note that `Object.keys()` does not return `Array<keyof T>` automatically because [it is not generally safe to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)

Comment: @jcalz , yes You are right. I have read related github issue. It is better to use with immutable objects. Btw, do you now the better way to use Object.keys with TS? I know, we can do it with typeguards inside map function, but I think it is a bit overhead

Comment: This is the only answer that actually discusses how to do this in TypeScript.

Answer (score 7):

## [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

To use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), (as indicated in the original question), you can add a typecast indicating that the object is an indexable type:

```js
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${(obj as {[key: string]: string})[key]}`);
}
```

Or use a typecast on the `key`:

```js
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key as keyof typeof obj]}`);
}
```

## [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) may be used without `map()` as follows:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate over both the keys and the values:

```js
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.entries`

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`))
```

Comment: This answer is really near to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375054/10952503) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69757191/10952503)