# Typescript: remove keys from generic object

Tags: typescript

I'm currently attempting to write a higher order function `without` that will return a new object without the keys passed into the returned function.

I can't see a way to get the key in the reducer to be of `keyof T` as `Object.keys` returns a `string[]` not `Array<keyof T>`, if it did I think it would solve this. Am I missing something obvious with the types here that would solve this?

```
const without = <T>(object: T) => (...parts: Array<keyof T>) => {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce((acc, key) => {
        // `key` is of type `string` not `keyof T`
        if (!parts.includes(key)) {
            acc[key] = object[key];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {} as Omit<T, typeof parts[number]>);
};

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const result = without(obj)('a', 'c');
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCxAV1gXhgHgCoB8AFCAEYBWApsFAFwx4CUMmBMRAdFwA4CGATlAj0Agv368AnjgDWlSSABmDAs1YwA3gCgYumP0pQ0-MDADyFalA5zJEEpZqMOBgCZpglIkV7BgAGhhbNTZtPXCYBGUiAEI%20QQgOBDBgABs0V0p7YOYwiPzfYABtWwBdFhgyKhoS%20VKAbh18mABfJvyDIxMYQsbwlsCNFp6IcwBbJHxAqEluSiUYeKEisDQx0kp%20UtVGlsatUEhYKoqNHvoARkDSegAmQOB6AGZWxsPofSy0VKx4JFQMA5yIwiAByXigwKg4Cgxj1IA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` will return `string[]` for reasons outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript). You will need to use type assertions to make this work.

```
const without = <T>(object: T) => <K extends keyof T>(...parts: Array<K>): Omit<T, K> => {
    return (Object.keys(object) as Array<keyof T>).reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (!parts.includes(key as any)) {
            acc[key] = object[key];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {} as T);
};

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const result = without(obj)('a', 'c');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCxAV1gXhgHgCoB8AFCAEYBWApsFAFwx4CUMmBuA0jJQB5SVgATCDADWlAJ4gAZg2IA6BQAcAhgCcoEegEFVq5eJzsCjegHkAtknwAaGEZZsA3gCgYbmKspQ0qsDCKmFNRQcmLiECRBNMzKwjp6BmHSsoxyngJowJRERMrAwLZhzKwwLu7lMAgyRACEKuoQcghgwAA2aAKUEWEwsb1g4ozMZRWjecAA2mEAuiwwZFQ0UxLTANyuozAAvhujnt6+vfnr5Vu2jlu9wkzrW+vOoJCwC3OOvfQAjLak9ABMtsB6ABmbbrR7QDxdNCtLDwJCoDCRciMIgAcmUqNsqOAqMYqyAA)

Beside the assertion to `Array<keyof T>` I also changed the type of the initial value of `reduce` to `T`. This is order to allow the assignment `acc[key] = object[key]`. `T[keyof T]` will be assignable to itself, but `Omit<T, typeof parts[number]>[keyof T]` will not be assignable. `T` will then in turn be assignable to `Omit<T, typeof parts[number]>`

Comment: You'll also need to introduce generic parameter in inner function, otherwise `typeof parts[number]` won't work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCxAV1gXhgHgCoB8AFCAEYBWApsFAFwx4CUMmBuA0pQJ4QyUAeUSmAAmvAIIAnSQEMuOANbcQAMwYFiAOm0AHGZKgR6nHo3oB5ALZJ8AGhhQuOyqph6DEANpg0l0pUkAXTZWGABvACgYaJhJSig0STAYInMKaihNJR4SdJpmGQlpOUVlNUJGTTiRNGBKIiIZYGB7bOZQyJiumAQ1IgBCd0NNBDBgABs0EUoIIjbmTu6lpuBPbMCWGDIqGjXuQIBuKKWYAF9jpbiEpJgVo67T+zDT294mI9OjiNBIWG3NsK3egARnspHoACZ7MB6ABmM5HH7QWIzNDjLDwJCoDC5ciMIgAchkBPsBOABMYByAA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir this makes sense and finally understanding why `Object.keys` returns a `string[]` is invaluable, thank you!