# TypeScript - How to filter the object?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make the right typing for the following function:

```
export function filter(obj: any, predicate: (value: any, key: string) => boolean) {
    const result: any = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((name) => {
        if (predicate(obj[name], name)) {
            result[name] = obj[name];
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to preserve the typings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more specific information about use cases, I'd be inclined to do something like this:

```
function filter<T extends object>(
  obj: T,
  predicate: <K extends keyof T>(value: T[K], key: K) => boolean
) {
  const result: { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] } = {};
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).forEach((name) => {
    if (predicate(obj[name], name)) {
      result[name] = obj[name];
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

We want `filter()` to accept an `obj` parameter of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type `T extends object`, meaning that you will only filter object-types and not primitives, and you want the compiler to keep track of the actual key-value relationship as `T` and not widen it all the way to `object`.  The `predicate` callback will therefore need to be something that accepts `value` and `key` parameters that are applicable for `T`; so we make it a generic  callback in the type `K extends keyof T` of the `key` parameter, where the `value` is the corresponding property value type `T[K]`.  See the documentation for [`keyof` and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) for more info on that notation.

For the result, we want to return an object whose properties are the same as `T` but optional, since we don't know which properties will actually exist.  This can be represented as the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{ [K in keyof T]? T[K] }`, also known as [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

One issue is that I had to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that I expect `Object.keys(obj)` to be `Array<keyof T>` (an array of the keys of `T`) instead of just `string[]`.  This expectation may be violated, which is why `Object.keys()` returns `string[]` in the first place; see [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) for an explanation of that.  I think it's reasonable to make this assumption here, but I'll show you a way it can lead to runtime errors if the assumption is violated.

---

First let's test the desired behavior:

```
const obj = filter({ a: "hello", b: 123, c: true }, (v, k) => k === "b");
/* const obj: {
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: number | undefined;
    c?: boolean | undefined;
} */
console.log(obj); // {b: 123}
```

That looks good; the compiler is happy with the parameters to `filter()` and returns a value with optional properties.

Here's the bad case:

```
interface Foo {
  x: string,
  y: string,
}
interface Bar extends Foo {
  z: number;
}
const bar: Bar = { x: "hello", y: "goodbye", z: 100 };
const foo: Foo = bar; // acceptable because Bar extends Foo
filter(foo, (v, k) => v === v.toLowerCase() ); // compiles fine, but
//  RUNTIME TypeError: v.toLowerCase is not a function
```

The compiler does not realize that `foo` has a `number`-valued property because we've widened `bar` to `Foo`, but the `predicate` callback really relies on `v` being a `string`.  This compiles, and you get a runtime error.  If this possibility concerns you, then you might want a more strict typing of `filter()` that forces `predicate` to really take values of type `(value: unknown, key: PropertyKey)`, but that will be more annoying to use.  It really depends on use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgHgCqIYAemYAJgM6JwBGAVhtAHwAUAsAFCLX0BcieADSduABywYyMCAENM-HAGlCJDOSoBrDAE84wAawBuM1CAz88AbUUBdQYi3b+igJSIAvE0Q04cVBhkwTjcAbxFECAQKKEQJChB0fhDEa0QYJEc9ARsAfgtrG0QAXw9EEKKAbnCWAHl6RigAOkcKFlo6NxkqAEEsLBltHEz9PCYXRuA4LABRGQgACxYWMBkAWww3TzLw7hh9FnFJaTkMNvpLFfW7REuN0J3uWIx49Au1jEL3Hjo3q6quR5FcJFFz-bgSKAgLBIOIJKD-IEcSJgaLfUoodDYFjJGT8ABE8wwqFQcDx9ho-AAjAAmADM9gg-CgWDMxXsLEM9g0my8Gg87i+eJoeNBnAA9AAqCJRGLtJIPGR5RDRLDpADmiAAPohwGQMCgwJIwY8aEqwCBVjRsFqdeR9ekjQ8IEqfH4Akhtbr7YayAjEBKxZxkRQ3Y0SWqzh0KogxWKyhTEDTaYjOOlMFhgHMMIgAGK+bYAoj8FXq4QApzK5mlziItPYTMQbMAIRkWBUpEoufzYQBAC9+ObLdgEUGZd5W-wW22vski4gCUSSWTEBW8WrfGQaNoMMv+4mAAz74r-YMxSZwfh5uClGit6OxxBzRuiKAyGj+byMGQgCjN1vttROyvTgMXTFhz3ZTkHB5RBDH5L5DEaKA4AAGTgAB3bAAGEulONxQRjONIlWUQ0GeZAHXJEAoHFONAF4NwBSncQAAlABVAA5PAAEkAFlpgEbRRAwaY+imfhEOQtDMKwHDfzSKgwDgGIZGQcBoHgIIOCAA)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I indeed need a general solution, and I suppose there is no way to overcome this disadvantage. I've found and tested the [lodash filter function](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter) and it has the exact same problem.

Comment: I assume it's better to make the following predicate typing:  `predicate: <K extends keyof T>(value: T[K], key: K) => unknown` (like in the array filter method).

Comment: I guess it depends on the use cases you want to support.  If you want to support truthy/falsy return values from the predicate instead of strictly `true`/`false`, then sure.  That makes sense in a lot of cases.  By restricting to `boolean` you make it harder to misuse `filter()` (e.g., `(v, k) => console.log(k === "b")`, oops, I returned `undefined` or something) but it's also more annoying to use with truthy/falsy things (`(v, k) => k.length` has to become `(v, k) => !!k.length` or something)