# Why does typescript not narrow down a type in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have created this simple snippet of code which is a basic representation of what I am really trying to do while working with React Contexts and Reducers.

I have 2 objects containing functions. 1 for creating. bird/s and one for creating fish; all of which return strings.

I then have a third function which can take a string as a parameter and simply console.logs it

Essentially, what i am doing with the following snippet of code is combining the 2 objects, passing their returned string directly as an argument to the display function and wrapping the display function in another function.

```
type OneOf<K> = K[keyof K]; //converts into a union

//object 1 containing functions to create birds
const birdCreatorFunctions = { 
  createBird: (type: { color: string; weight: number }) =>
    `I am a ${type.color} bird and I weigh ${type.weight} kgs`,
  createBirds: (amount: number) => `I am a flock containing ${amount} birds`
  
};
//object 2 containing functions to create fish
const fishCreatorFunctions = {
  createFish: (type: { color: string; weight: number }) => `I am a ${type.color} fish and I weigh ${type.weight} kgs`,
  createFishes: (amount: number) => `I am a school containing ${amount} fish`
}
// third function which takes a string as a parameter
function display(payload: string) {
 console.log(payload)
}

//combination of both fish and bird objects wrapped in display function
const displayFunctions: {[key: string]: (payload: Parameters<OneOf<typeof birdCreatorFunctions & typeof fishCreatorFunctions>>[0]) => void} = {}

//combines both fish and bird creator objects, creates a new function 
//which contains the bird or fish functions wrapped inside the display function, and 
//stores this new created function inside of the displayFunctions object.
Object.entries({...fishCreatorFunctions, ...birdCreatorFunctions}).forEach(([key, func]) => {
  const newFn: (payload: Parameters<typeof func>[0]) => void = (payload) => display(func(payload));
  displayFunctions[key] = newFn
});
```

For example. If I wanted to create a flock of birds and log the output with the shortest code possible, I would have to do this:

```
display(birdCreatorFunctions.createBirds(3));
```

With the new displayFunctions I have created, I can now do this:

```
displayFunctions.createBirds(3);
```

My problem is, Typescript isn't narrowing the type while "compiling" the possible scenarios through the forEach loop and hence I am getting error ts(2345).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhGAzAPAaQHxQLxTQbQGsIQB7JPAXQG4oB6OgY1LgDcIAnYAZygEs4wUlACGUAK5w%20LALAAoeQ1IAjAFYRGwKAEYozQSIECA5lCSTN0uLyF6OEEcGjK%20HACbd5%207lpfuAwvaOpBwAYhbAVry4AN5Q8lB2Dk4AQq5uAFxQABSgkFlxzAA2IVk%20HCa0AO4QfMYAFsBZcOIAtsqcUAC%20AJQ4GAmJUAAGAJKiraJQACQxeRAAdMUhXVB%20bqJwG%20M1dfUzc%20CLuw3Aq4TG3MMANIOMQanp3FnZIq2kkk1QLe2cfdhYMYTKZIEqMQh6FjAQxSOCmWZvD6CVbrK6DeRdaiKOgqdSaKAAJkhBiMcLMESiUFs92S0CQfG49S8LB8ZgZ9UCyRC4TglhZOCgMTuDwgoXZL3mBUhJQ4ZWAFTh1Vqp2abQ6HG6-0B4zeU1m8yWpBlq3pjM22ygJ32%20qOCytZygFyutzkiRpjlF7IgzxyiM%20qt%20HC1Ix1kzE3EY9VIRuJ0NJ8JifuRbMZwwx2Kp9XS5N5kRYlqzkapImIvHD8pMojLUDAIg4bwgTg48nMuasUDcDLARREIGytZAJREmSg5RMfSFru8RsWJWM-d7Q7cPXTCjkDGY7QEjnb5DWpGA%201N%20xEWzW2dxGh4lvrYEgGwEHa7PZAOb5cGZ1i0ne43d7PPfH0YiIEg5QVYxKBeAclyyAAFOsGybbgUHgRBUHmPd1k5YIwgpfkADIqSOPdj2woRcLbFkMAwfAAAZKGDVhSD4NxVliLp5GxTcXAQXhlAPI92XNc93CSHCoEvTRuGuMSnGrBAqjfPM4Hidc6CqQt9n0ONrEzZwLw1Y8lMpKpb3vfhrBY6BD2gH8-1fVt3xk08NmxHwQm9TMGW%20CBFPdJwNkc5SLO4KyJIoGyn1-F8AOU3hJOABZ5BgNQrwWCBBAqb1shiBY8tIh5uTw6wZLyhYsMKijAN6BYkBCABRERI2ybIQJAGTHIY-pBTuFktAU0I4CgxdSGHOCENaRtOGQjCKEcmj6MY5iNlwBdB1G5dursl9skctalx6HosVdKL7NiqI2soAUBo-ORemOoA)

I am only just getting started with typescript, but from what I understand, typescript is complaining that it "cannot" differentiate between whether I am passing a number or either of the two `{color: string, weight: number}` objects. However, considering that I am using the parameters of the function which is being iterated through the for loop to define the payload, at any given time, the payload for the functions are going to be equal.

How can I fix this error, or at least tell Typescript that the payload is the correct payload for the function?

even doing this inside the for loop throws the same error:

```
const newFn: (payload: Parameters<typeof func>[0]) => void = (payload) => func(payload)
```

I understand that at compile time `func` is a union of all four functions and therefore payload is a union of all 4 parameters, but shouldn't typescript narrow down the union as it "knows" that's what will happen inside of the for loop as each "union" will have to get evaluated into a single type?

Comment: What happens if you use a `for( of )` loop instead of the `.forEach` member? I note that the `.forEach` function is effectively obsolete since `for( of )` was introduced in ES6.

Comment: Disclaimer: i didn't read the entire question. `Object.entries` has the issue, that an object may have more properties, than typescript knows - e.g. an interface of `{ a: string, b: number }` is nice, but `{ a: '', b: 0, c: { penguin: document.all } }` fulfills it, and the extra would appear in `Object.entries`. See e.g. [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208)

Comment: @Dai Same Error, no difference.

Comment: PS: I won't flag this as dupe, as i didn't read it entirely, but it's very likely [why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) (same principle for `Object.entries`).

Comment: @ASDFGerte I am aware that this is a common problem, what would be the recommended way to iterate through an object's keys and values without having that problem? I stole the Object.entries idea straight from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries so I was expecting not to face that problem

Comment: You can make a generic version of `Object.entries`, which asserts the type is exhaustive, i think some examples were mentioned in the above links. However, note that this can and will explode, if the type passed in isn't exhaustive - the generic version would kind of assume that (and its implementation usually uses some assertion or cast accordingly). I think the underlying issue is, that there is afaik (currently?) no way to type something as "sealed", in a way of "yes this is everything in there, and nothing will ever be added".

Comment: The more i read the code, the more i fear my "best guess" (while being valid in the general sense) is not fully on point here though :/ The error isn't about the related key, but before that.

Comment: Yeah, my initial hunch was wrong, and i seem to have missed some details about type inference for `Object.values` and `Object.entries`. Sorry about that. The explicit error you run into on the playground is this: `func` is any one of the four functions. Now, if `payload` is "one of the possible parameters", that doesn't mean they match. Therefore, when you call `func`, it asks for an argument that is "everything at the same time", which `payload` isnt.

Comment: `typeof func` is still a compile-time operation, so `Parameters<typeof func>[0]` still gives you the union.  In order to get the correct arguments the `key` and associated `func` needs to be generic and you need to make an assertion about the type of the `key`.

Comment: `displayFunctions` needs to be a mapped type where the function arguments match the key.   Right now you can do `displayFunctions.createBirds({color: "", weight: 5});` which you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: As a mention: `Object.values` (and presumably `Object.entries` as well) is generic and assumes an exact type in the value part, due to [a mistake](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43265). That got me confused for a while, the signature already has more than it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's ignore the `forEach` loop for a second and just look at the `displayFunctions` that we are creating.  You can call:

```
displayFunctions.createBirds(3);
```

Ok great.  But you can also call `createBirds` with any arguments so long as those arguments are assignable to *one of* the display functions.  This doesn't give us any error, but it should:

```
displayFunctions.createBirds({color: "blue", weight: 5});
```

This problem is related to the problems inside the loop.  You have defined the type of `displayFunctions` such that any of the functions accepts any of the arguments and you are doing the same with `newFn`.  The type of `func` is a union of the functions so `payload: Parameters<typeof func>[0]` is a union of the arguments.  We don't know that the `payload` type matches the `func` type, so you can't call the union of the functions with the union of the arguments.

---

Let's start by properly typing `displayFunctions` as a mapped type.  We want to make sure that `displayFunctions.createBirds` can *only* accept `createBirds` arguments.

```
// utility type takes a map of function and converts it to their display versions
type ToDisplay<T extends Record<string, (...args: any) => string>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => void;
}
```

We say that for each key of the original object, the value is a function that takes the same arguments but returns `void` instead of `string`.

```
// combination of both fish and bird objects wrapped in display function
const displayFunctions: ToDisplay<typeof birdCreatorFunctions & typeof fishCreatorFunctions> = {};
// ^ this is now an error because we are missing properties
```

But now we can't initialize it to an empty object or assign arbitrary properties on it.  Both of these things are good as they guarantee type-safety of the object, but it means that we need to make some assertions in order to build the object.

---

When we set a property on `displayFunctions`, we need to know that this `key` is a valid key of the object.  We also need to know that the `func` matches this `key` and that the `payload` matches this specific `func`.  As explained in the comments, Typescript purposefully does not return specific types on `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` because the runtime object could have excess properties which are not included in the type.  So we need to make an assertion.

```
const buildDisplayFunctions = <T extends Record<string, (...args: any) => string>> (functions: T): ToDisplay<T> => {
  // need to assert that the empty object is the final type
  const displayFunctions = {} as ToDisplay<T>;

  // mapper needs to be generic to ensure matching
  const setFn = <K extends keyof T>( key: K ) => {
    const func = functions[key]; // type: T[K]
    // I am using spread to allow for multiple arguments
    // Must exclude `never` to avoid error: Type 'Parameters<T[K]>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
    // So I am using a default value of `[]` instead of `never`
    const newFn = (...args: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : []) => display(func(...args));
    displayFunctions[key] = newFn;
  }

  // need to assert that the keys are `keyof T` and not just `string`
  (Object.keys(functions) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(setFn)

  return displayFunctions;
}
```

Note: if you don't want to spread the `args` then you need to ensure that the each function cannot require more than one argument with `<T extends Record<string, (payload: any) => string>>`

---

Now we can create your `displayFunctions` for birds and fish.  We are able to call `createBirds` with the correct arguments, but we get an error when calling with arguments for a different function!

```
const displayFunctions = buildDisplayFunctions({...birdCreatorFunctions, ...fishCreatorFunctions});

displayFunctions.createBirds(3); // ok
displayFunctions.createFish({color: "blue", weight: 5}); // ok
displayFunctions.createBirds({color: "blue", weight: 5}); // error
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NVnkMN)

Comment: Wow! very impressive answer and extremely detailed! Typescript never fails to amaze me, I am in the process of converting my entire application to TS so i guess i'm in for a ride! Thanks again!