# Typescript interface object keys

Tags: typescript, interface

How in typescript create interface of array of key value pair from another interface keys.

[typescriptlang sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=53&ssc=2&pln=45&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDUCGAbArhAPDANFBAfFALxQDeAUFNVANbwBcsA3FTQG6oZMKsC%20rCgEsAdsAgAnAGZIAxtABiEJMDQSIAZ3JtqAdwAWECCg1MRaALYAjSaxpRZAexSOJTDcAmiA5nZpg5WiRvTQB%20d08fAG0AXX4KYTFJGXkoAGEkCW17CyRzFNV1NygPLxFfHSgLRwATYwiyivspZULNJiUVNU14xPFpOWgMiQAlCABHDA9smlz8uTbi0p8-amq6lAaVypau9Q1wqAAFTOAhVExK%20yi4RC4sACIDIxMHvHNrSQI8W%20R0R6cLgkbxKkXK31g8D%20GEwDwCsiCIQ0IOW5ViBBilQIvScImmUlcNQUjlkaFM6UyJBmazyaAK3WKDwJEhqb0q63qUCZJLJbOarW65Mo9nsz2M5IAjAB2HBXGiA1xMJ76ITiPk0PiygQJXHTKwWXQADQAzExhlThbNafSikr9bp1WtapyHibHVBdm0hXK9IZxUwJQBOWUi%20XORVcqwoQLu%20zwxHtKBRB4AZQADAAOFMAWRBqczABUFHn0xmCwBxEtpwMAJgArA8YiGNVrBFI0CJZGdHCIoGB1AF1MMxpNNMAABSyTJmzIASmpDh703Uo48M9GEymwAtPqq1oWDKYU4kADo5nSD0Vm6GOZsHJkz86UNeRZ7BUwAPJWABWEC7J4gMQvE0ScHzffZZzPJAwHHcconoEA8E4f4YnnYgiHHMgEKQ%204%20FnWcX21Sp1EKXsVy3HEl2cCATxcbxx37CBBwgYdNzHcdmSJHkNHw1hdWo2jHHoxjmNY1cJ3tE1eKAA)

A have next interfaces:

```js
type KeyValue<K, V> = {
    key: K;
    value: V;
};

interface Features {
    wheels: number;
    color: string;
    packages?: string[];
}

interface Car {
    manufacturer: string;
    model: string;
    features: Features;
}
```

Next, create variables using this interfaces:

```js
const fordFocus: Car = {
    manufacturer: "ford",
    model: "focus",
    features: {
        wheels: 17,
        color: "white",
    },
};

const bmwX3: Car = {
    manufacturer: "bmw",
    model: "X3",
    features: {
        wheels: 19,
        color: "black",
        packages: ["S08SM", "S08TF", "S08TG", "S0925"],
    },
};
```

I want to send this variables to server.

Request data should have next schema:

```js
interface CarRequest {
    manufacturer: string;
    model: string;
    features?: {key: string, value: any}[]
}
```

Now i declare features manually, but i want to do it by utility interface.
Like this:

```
interface FeaturesRequest<T, K in T> {
  [n: number]: {key: K, value: T}
}
```

Function that prepare request data

```
function prepareCarRequest(car: Car) {
    const request: CarRequest = {
        manufacturer: car.manufacturer,
        model: car.model,
        features: Object.entries(car.features).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value})),
    };

    return request;
}
```

I don't understand how i should declare requestData that it pick keys in Feature interface and transform it to KeyValue automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your interface into key-value type with a rather simple [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```typescript
type InterfaceToKV<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: { key: K, value: T[K] }
}[keyof T]
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mA7Mkw)

But the `Object.entries`' type is [more generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012175/3388225) (discussion is about `Object.keys` but the same applies to `Object.entries`) and will not allow you to assign `string` to your key literal types.