# Ignore "unique symbol" in typescript when using "keyof typeof" with Object.keys()

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I am trying to display all the values in my current redux state but I am getting errors involving the `unique symbol` type and I am not sure how to resolve it.

Object.keys() says it's returning `string[]` but `keyof typeof state` includes `unique symbol` so `.map()` doesn't work. I added a `.filter()` clause but that didn't help.

This works fine when run in javascript but typescript screams and refuses to compile.

Simplified example:

```
const state = useAppSelector(state => state);
return (
    <div>
        {Object.keys(state).filter((x: keyof typeof state) => x instanceof String).map((x) =>
            <div>
                <label>{x}</label>
                <div>
                    {Object.keys(state[x]).filter((y: keyof typeof state[x]) => y instanceof String).map((y) =>
                        <span>{y}: {JSON.stringify(state[x][y])}</span>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

How can I correctly type this?

**EDIT:**

I attempted to use the `Omit<>` utility type:

`Object.keys(state).map((x: Omit<keyof typeof state, symbol>) =>`

But this still results in an error when accessing the state via `state[x]`:

`Type 'Omit<"auth" | "developer" | "errors" | "info" | unique symbol, symbol>' cannot be used as an index type. ts(2538)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#description) only returns strings according to the spec, so your `.filter()` call isn't doing anything to help. The reason why `Object.keys()` doesn't return `keyof T[]` is pretty thoroughly covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012175/3696076).

---

Having read the linked answer, and understanding that using `keyof` for these types of situations is unsafe, there are two approaches using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

The first safe version is to cast the value types to `unknown`, and use a typeguard whenever you need the actual type:

```
// Object.entries throws on null/undefined
function isEntriesCallable(arg: T): arg is Record<any,unknown> {
    return arg !== null && typeof arg !== "undefined";
}

const state = useAppSelector(state => state);
return (
    <div>
        {Object.entries(state as Record<any, unknown>).map(([x, stateX]) =>
            <div>
                <label>{x}</label>
                <div>
                    { isEntriesCallable(stateX) ? Object.entries(stateX).map(([y, stateY]) =>
                        <span>{y}: {JSON.stringify(stateY)}</span>
                    ) : <span>null/undefined</span>}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

Pros/Cons are that all the value types are now `unknown`, and you have to call a typeguard if you want to narrow them. In your example, `JSON.stringify` accepts `any`, so having an `unknown` value doesn't actually impact anything. Any future edits to the code will force the developer to use typeguards if they want to call anything that requires a type besides `any` or `unknown`.

---

A less safe version suffers from the excess property issues highlighted in the linked answer. However, if you know the type is exact, this will narrow `stateX` to the union of the string-key property value types of `typeof state`. It uses a cast to a mapped type that does what you were intending with `Omit`. The provided typeguard also allows some type narrowing on the `stateX` value types to exclude values on `stateX` that are primitives or null so that you don't bother calling `Object.entries` on primitives/null.

```
// Extract an object containing only string property keys
// guarantees your type will match `{[key: string]: T}` for the
// argument to the Object.entries type definition.
type StringKeyedObject<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
    [Key in (K extends string ? K : never)]:  T[Key];
}

type NonObject = number | string | boolean | symbol | bigint | undefined | null;
function isObjectLike<T extends object>(arg: T | NonObject): arg is T { return arg !== null && typeof arg === "object"; }

const state = useAppSelector(state => state);
return (
    <div>
        {Object.entries(state as StringKeyedObject<typeof state>).map(([x, stateX]) =>
            <div>
                <label>{x}</label>
                <div>
                    {isObjectLike(stateX) ? Object.entries(stateX as StringKeyedObject<typeof stateX>).map(([y, stateY]) =>
                        <span>{y}: {JSON.stringify(stateY)}</span>
                    ) : <span>{JSON.stringify(stateX)}</span>}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

Pros:

- utilizes your own declared types for inference/narrowing.

Cons:

- unsafe typecasts that may cause errors from unhandled object properties that don't exist on the type definition.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a frustrating issue. I used the second solution since things are better typed and my redux store isn't using partial types. Because I am using eslint I did have to add a rule of `"@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off"` so it wouldn't throw an error about `object` which I think should be a warning anyways.