# Working with key/values in typescript (e.g. setting default values)

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface Options {
  num?: number
  bool?: boolean
  str?: string
}
const def: Options = { num: 3, bool: true, str: 'test' } // default value
function normalize(opt?: Options): Options { // returns given values or if none, defaults
  if(opt === undefined) opt = {};
  for(const k in def) { // we iterate over keys of an object
    if(opt[k] === undefined) opt[k] = def[k]; // and read/write the object at these keys
  }
  return opt;
}
```

This is just an exemple, but the general pattern is we want to iterate on an object's keys and do something generic, like perform a check, or in this case use default values.

The code above is invalid typescript for two reasons:

- first, keys of an object (as in `Object.keys` or `for..in`) are not `keyof` this object, but instead string. This is unfortunate, [but necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript).
- second, since the key is dynamic and typescript doesn't captures the fact that it's the same on all terms of the expression, the assignment does not work (see comment by *jcalz*)

So to fix this, we have to write the loop as:

```
for(const k in def) {
  if(opt[k as keyof Options] === undefined) {
    opt[k as keyof Options] = def[k as keyof Options] as any;
  }
}
```

So problem solved. But is there a better solution ? Something less convoluted, more readable, etc.

I'm not interested in `Object.assign` or deconstruction. I know about them, but sometimes you have logic to perform and have to write it "by hand". And I feel like typescript is getting in the way instead of helping me there. So maybe there's a better pattern to use.

Comment: Sounds like `Map<Key, Value>` is all you need here. And then you can use `for(const [key, value] of map.entries())` for type safety

Comment: This means that all keys have the same value-type though. Which is not always the case

Comment: Can you show an additional example that can reflect why deconstructing would not be the best solution?

Comment: Not sure how to do conditionals with deconstructing. It works for unset keys, but what if you want to treat null or 0 as default value and replace it ?
Or something more complex like `{ fiield: true }` => default `{ field: false }` => delete/disable `{ }` (field undefined) => inherited

Comment: "the test restricts the static type of `opt[k]` to `undefined`, to which we cannot assign another value." That's not what's happening here (if I understand you correctly).  It's much more likely to be [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693)

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMy5rm) look like an improvement at all?  It's the closest I can get to making this work with the maximum of type safety and the minimum of assertions.  You can even remove that assertion if you specify the actual keys to iterate [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w62A0w) since the compiler isn't sure that extra keys don't show up somewhere.  I sort of doubt any of this is better than just using assertions the way you're doing.

Comment: No indeed, not really much better but thanks anyways.