# Convert Record to Map in type safe way - TypeScript

Tags: typescript

This is my function that converts record to map:

```
type MyReturn<Str> = Map<Str, Map<number, number>>;
export const mapRecordToMap = <MyString extends string>(data: Record<MyString, [number, number][]>)
    : MyReturn<MyString> => {
        const myReturn = new Map<MyString, Map<number, number>>();
        Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            myReturn.set(key as MyString, new Map(value as [number, number][]));
        });
        
        return myReturn;
};
```

The problem I have is that I have to use `'as'` here:

```
myReturn.set(key as MyString, new Map(value as [number, number][]));
```

to have proper type checking. How to avoid that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extra helper for typing `Object.entries`:

```js
type Entries<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T][];

const entries = <Obj,>(obj: Obj) => Object.entries(obj) as Entries<Obj>

export const mapRecordToMap = <MyString extends string>(
    data: Record<MyString, [number, number][]>) =>
    entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        acc.set(key, new Map(value));
        return acc
    }, new Map<MyString, Map<number, number>>());
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/FAFwngDgpgBAogOxAJwJZQM4B4AqA%20GAXhgG9gYKYBtAaRlQRgGsowB7AMxhwF0AuajQA03Wjx4BuYAF8qLdl15VJwYAGM2CDCBhQkaTERhYA8gCMAVkLwAKNpYHmLASiIEnUNSAB0elOgw7S1cAQwx4fQDTSzxVKAAPCDZkHQ0tHQBbEIgAJU9kgBMcNgBZbKMsErAAZX8EAHNdeJA9AvDtNAbbckoCkJAQgTyNZALKmrr6kSoEAFcMsyhkETmFpZ5lPFdCWMpdSMwbPoHnb2QoAtm1KBsbELU1afkRADcQgBtZqB5tgjI9vb3NTeDBQEA2Z4wBBQADuMDKEBsb0%20UGczikAMo5xAs2QjCBPQo0hWsPh2XGtU6UzJECwq0Wyyh8wZeFsaIkQA)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742597/preserve-key-type-when-using-object-entries) you can find more approaches of typing `Object.entries`

P.S. If you have a deal with `[].map, [].reduce, {}.keys, {}.entries` and you want narrow return type you almost always need to use `as` type assertion. This is the minimum evil :D

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add a type argument to `Object.entries`:

```
type MyReturn<Str> = Map<Str, Map<number, number>>;

export const mapRecordToMap = <MyString extends string>(data: Record<MyString, [number, number][]>)
    : MyReturn<MyString> => {
        const myReturn = new Map<MyString, Map<number, number>>();
        Object.entries<[number, number][]>(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            myReturn.set(key as MyString, new Map(value));
        });
        
        return myReturn;
};
```

This may be prettier but effectively it isn't much different from what you did already ... Really your casting is pretty safe, because if the type doesn't match the argument it produces an error. (A sign of unsafe casting is when you have to do something more like `as unknown as [number, number][]` ...)