# Is it possible to get an array types of the record's values in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to obtain all the types of the record's values. For example if I have an object like this:

```
{
  'a': 1,
  'b': false
}
```

I would like to have a type which contains `number` and `boolean`.

I'm trying to achieve some sort of function mappings without losing types:

```
type MyContext = { store: number[]; };

const obj: Record<string, (context: MyContext, ...args: any[]) => void> = {
    log(ctx: MyContext, msg: string) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    add(ctx: MyContext, value: number) {
        ctx.store.push(value);
    }
};

const convert = <TContext>(context: TContext, objectWithFunctions: Record<string, (context: TContext, ...args: any[]) => void>) => {
    //omit the first parameter and return a new object with modified functions
    const result: Record<string, (...args: any[]) => void> = {};

    Object.keys(objectWithFunctions).forEach((functionName) => {
        const func = objectWithFunctions[functionName];
        result[functionName] = (...args) => func(context, ...args);
    });

    return result;
};

const context = { store: [] };
const newObj = convert(context, obj);
newObj.log('some message');
newObj.add(12);
newObj.add();//should give an error
newObj.foo();//should give an error
console.log(newObj, context.store);
```

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCB7AdsCAPYUC8UDeUAzsIgE4QBcUyArgLYBGEpA2gLoDcUAvhwFB8AximJREDAFZUAShGGkAJgB5ipAJbIA5gBooACmGoMwKnCRHMugHQ2AhqU2Eqt5CHYBKHAD4oAN0RqCj64eHxQ4VAANoiaBsDopggoaJZQdISaVKoamp6hEQVQhoSIkRBW0bHpufwF3NphEbYKCnEJsEkWwLq+tpE0lNT0TKR5jYVF8VbEZOVgNIQAFnq9-RDutRHcfLwCxViGvsxYuEoAKuYpwF4GycZUF3ep4hJywADqasCLAGI0yIJgGoRDI5GRlNktLpbl0HpdjNY7A4nFAXG42J5sD5-IEvJifPkIgB6ImIOhfKDfaAAMzUpFEYHstjoEDQpFRyAUUHIwBopGQqOoEAA7mJJG8oMKvos0ogFGpaRAudT-oDgchCOMiiIsORCDRIiYoLJ5BDgOoofobFZ7I5nK4PN4-AEgjh8LstQB5cWAqwAawgIEIeheb0+3z+AKBIncVmpZAAorZBMs9Cqo+qAHLM9ZOwkTfZQdOCN2hwHh36q6MaljF6vZlmcLUFPUG4C1qtZnNsN16a22wj4ouqmFXRE25EbLXcKdanl8gWtw38D2FwxXN0EGbkKjsHj8QvIEXeiRuw7HUcIsUSKdH4UnioxPQAchKLLSEEIhFsmggz9vx6SDaLR6AAjAATAB95Ac0rQbCSSyIAaXKaGoRwclAzCkGQfB3g+8aIHo8FEohyFQKh6EuJhpDYaQQgiKU5SVHoeGSLo67GNMJDkBsQA)

This implementation works but it's lacking of types because `any[]` constraint is used for the second argument in all the object's functions. Is it a way to somehow infer the types and return some more stricter type rather than `Record<string, (...args: any[]) => void>`?

Comment: I may not have time to write this up, or finish it, but this is _closer:_ https://tsplay.dev/Nn4ZeW

Comment: I'm a bit confused how the `{a: 1, b: false}` example at the top relates to the kind of inference you're looking for in the rest of your question, but hopefully my answer is still applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `obj` as being of type `Record<string, (context: MyContext, ...args: any[]) => void>` without throwing away all information about the particular method names and arguments in the initializer.  If you want the output type of `convert(context, obj)` to know about `log` and `add`, then you should probably just assign to `obj` without annotating at all; let the compiler infer its type:

```
const obj = {
    log(ctx: MyContext, msg: string) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    add(ctx: MyContext, value: number) {
        ctx.store.push(value);
    }
};
```

Later, if the compiler doesn't complain about calling `convert(context, obj)`, then you know `obj` is of an appropriate type.

---

Next, in order for `convert()` to strongly type its output, it must be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) not only in `T`, the type of `context`, but also in a type parameter related to the method name/argument mapping in `objectWithFunctions`.  My approach here would be to make the new type parameter `A` be an object type whose keys are the method names, and whose values are the argument lists not including the initial `context` parameter of type `T`.

For example, for `obj`, `A` would be specified as

```
{
    log: [msg: string];
    add: [value: number];
}
```

Note that you will never actually be using a value of type `A`, but it will be inferrable from the `objectWithFunctions` input, and it's straightforward to represent both the type of `objectWithFunctions` and the return type in terms of `A`.  Here are the typings:

```
const convert = <T, A extends Record<keyof A, any[]>>(
    context: T,
    objectWithFunctions: { [K in keyof A]: (context: T, ...rest: A[K]) => void }
) => {
    const result = {} as { [K in keyof A]: (...args: A[K]) => void };

    (Object.keys(objectWithFunctions) as Array<keyof A>)
        .forEach(<K extends keyof A>(functionName: K) => {
            const func = objectWithFunctions[functionName];
            result[functionName] = (...args) => func(context, ...args);
        });

    return result;
};
```

So, `objectWithFunctions`'s type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where the array `A[K]` in each property `K` of `A` is transformed to a function type with an argument of type `T` followed by a rest argument of type `A[K]`.  It turns out that because this type is of the form `{[K in keyof A]...}`, it is a *homomorphic* mapped type and the compiler is good at [inferring from homomorphic mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types).  The return type, as given in the annotation of `result`, is the same mapped type without the initial `T` argument.

Inside the body of the function I had to use a few [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that some values had certain types.  The initial value of `result` is an empty object, so I had to assert that it would be the final type (because `{}` certainly isn't of that type).  And the return type of `Object.keys()` is just `string[]` (see [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)) so I had to assert that it returns an array of `keyof A`.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const context: MyContext = { store: [] };
```

It's useful to annotate `context` here as `MyContext`, since otherwise the compiler assumes that `store` will always be an empty array (of type `never[]`).  And here goes:

```
const newObj = convert(context, obj);
```

You can use Quickinfo via IntelliSense to see that the call to `convert()` caused the compiler to infer `MyContext` for `T` and the aforementioned `{ log: [msg: string];  add: [value: number];}` type for `A`:

```
/* const convert: <MyContext, {
    log: [msg: string];
    add: [value: number];
}>(context: MyContext, objectWithFunctions: {
    log: (context: MyContext, msg: string) => void;
    add: (context: MyContext, value: number) => void;
}) => {
    ...;
} */
```

And when you hover on `myObj`, you can see that it is exactly the type you want it to be:

```
/* const newObj: {
    log: (msg: string) => void;
    add: (value: number) => void;
} */
```

So it behaves as desired:

```
newObj.log('some message');
newObj.add(12);
newObj.add(); // error
newObj.foo(); // error
console.log(newObj, context.store); // {}, [12]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCB7AdsCAPYUC8UDeUAzsIgE4QBcUyArgLYBGEpA2gLoDcUAvhwFB8AximJREDAFY58fKHKgAbRAHMAFIODoqcJKgzAANFDqFlVYqQCWyZQEoZ8x1GHJCiBRAB0StSbv9HbgNZeQBDABNw9U1tBBQ0TCMAN1CFGkpqeiZSezwQp2dNT2IyLzAaQgALVRS0iFsA+W4+XgEXURck5ixcAB4AFSMAQSh9CGRwwigAJQhhUnDegGsIEEQAMygho1DkEHYAPgPVfOd4-SpB0-EJOeAAdUtgSoAxGmQNSxEqAhYAaSg1igKzWmyGbCo6nOmEuRk88PIxCoQ3+bHs2AOUCSiEs4R4fHRmLyjnaWERNAUPXw3CgoSmvwBQJBGy2EKgqnhnlCpGUhGRqMJWJxeNap1UAHlJHdPCDCKobndHs83h9gF9XPY6VtSKRQiBlqsWUMDrZTo5POsyABRUKCaq9AFjCZTZlg47rd6fFAAOVCdAyf0FxIKTlJUA9H2kCo0StenrVIhYEa9yF9-s4ZpD5MpSfj6rTEDY0g58O5vMFyahekSUE5ZcIDUzcm4jdO5GANFIyCg2eA-FFYZcCWAsV0w+kBBK5Co7B4-DDyAgAHdJVJcJ1ulXh0Ybq2APQAKjOriwG9II6gvR00MMDnkPhnfnMwCsNgzjgi4RntXSVFojGYDNuGOIcLlgOJq1vaMHieONVXVPk7zkB92VAmFwLHfQjCfIgX2sOwcExbFcUaORP0hNCL2vSDklSX9MgAnJCKFEiWiDU5OX7KADz3ARD2PURFxXSQflOFDVBwix8MFYjwlI2lIkhH8Mn-bIZOFLieIEITV28FRVAAcjcf1jAgQhCFCZQIAMxsdMkLlIlUABGAAmWzl10z9VAaKA9z3UYdTIPg7IkC1EEQbyuD8gLSCC9p3C8HxVBCoxKOKEhyB86K8CCKAWFctggA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for all the references and explanations. I need to read about mapped types more in order to fully understand your approach.