# Make key required only in certain cases in a TS interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an interface for an "order". An order for a "book" is a special case where it should have a required "title" field. So how do I create the IBookOrder and combine it with IOtherOrder to make a generic order interface?

```
type productType = "book" | "pen" | "notebook"

interface IOtherOrder {
    product: productType, //all productType(s) except book
    amount: number,
    productCode: number,
    description: string
}

interface IBookOrder {
    product: productType, //how do I fix this to "book" type
    amount: number,
    productCode: number,
    description: string,
    title: string,        //required field only for order of "book"
}

//need to combine these here
interface IOrderValues extends IBookOrder, IOtherOrder {} 

const penOrder: IOrderValues = {
    product: "pen",
    amount: 5,
    description: "ink pen",
    productCode: 123,
    title: "This should not be allowed" // <<= incorrect
}

const bookOrder: IOrderValues = {
    product: "book",
    amount: 15,
    description: "Awesome TS book",
    productCode: 321,
    title: "Typescript 101" // <<= this should be required
}
```

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/m0LGrm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the example to demonstrate the failing use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly mark the `product` properties of `IOtherOrder` and `IBookOrder` to be the subsets of the `ProductType` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) you want:

```
interface IOtherOrder {
    product: "pen" | "notebook" // or Exclude<ProductType, "book">
    amount: number,
    productCode: number,
    description: string
}

interface IBookOrder {
    product: "book"
    amount: number,
    productCode: number,
    description: string,
    title: string,
}
```

Note that you don't need to use `ProductType` at all in these definitions, but if you think you might dynamically add more string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) to the union later, then something like `Exclude<ProductType, "book">` (using [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion)) will automatically add them as well.

---

When it comes to your `IOrderValues` type, you cannot make this a specific (non-generic) [`interface` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces); interface types are required to have statically known members, and the conditional inclusion of `title` is not possible.  You certainly don't want it to extend *both* `IBookOrder` and `IOtherOrder`, because then every `IOrderValues` would be required to be *both* of them (which is impossible now since their `product` properties are mutually exclusive).

Instead you probably want it to be a union of the `IBookOrder` and `IOtherOrder` interfaces; if you want to give it a name, you can do so via [a `type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases):

```
type IOrderValues = IBookOrder | IOtherOrder;
```

(Note that this makes your `I` prefix a misnomer; it's up to you whether you need such prefixes, and naming conventions are probably out of scope for this question so I won't go on about that here.)

---

Now your example code behaves as desired:

```
const penOrder: IOrderValues = {
    product: "pen",
    amount: 5,
    description: "ink pen",
    productCode: 123,
    title: "This should not be allowed" // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Object literal may only specify known properties, 
//  and 'title' does not exist in type 'IOtherOrder'
}

const bookOrder: IOrderValues = {
    product: "book",
    amount: 15,
    description: "Awesome TS book",
    productCode: 321,
    title: "Typescript 101" 
} // okay
```

Keep in mind though that the error you're seeing on `penOrder` relies on [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), which only kicks in when you assign an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) directly to a place expecting a type with fewer properties.  You can end up with extra properties if you do things differently:

```
const obj = {
    product: "pen" as const,
    amount: 5,
    description: "ink pen",
    productCode: 123,
    title: "My wonderful rainbow ink pen",
    numberOfColors: 7
}
const penOrder: IOrderValues = obj; // no error
```

Excess properties are not, by themselves, a violation of the type system; TypeScript has [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), so while `IOtherOrder` is required to have the properties in the declaration, it is *not prohibited* from having extra properties.  Indeed, such allowance for extra properties it what supports [interface and class extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types); without that, interface and class hierarchies would not form *type* hierarchies, and things would be a lot harder to use.

Personally I think this is fine and you should not worry about excess properties sneaking in there; you cannot really prevent all possible excess properties, so you should probably make sure your code does not rely on their absence (e.g., it should simply ignore them if they are there; it should not expect that `Object.keys()` will return only the known keys... see [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)).

If you want to explicitly exclude `title` from appearing in `IOtherOrder`, you could change the `IOtherOrder` declaration:

```
interface IOtherOrder {
    product: Exclude<ProductType, "book">
    amount: number,
    productCode: number,
    description: string
    title?: never; // <-- add this
}
```

to say that `title` is an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value would be [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  And thus the only valid value of `title` would be `undefined`.  This is probably overkill, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwAq5oF4oBEARgggNYFQA+hkAdpTQXQsBCeQQFBcCWdbOADMAhmmgBJAPLAAFhDhS4SBVADeXKFqhhEqDAC4oAUQAeaADYoVAHnjJ0WHABpCHCgD5N2kQFsEKAJGdCi+RArO3lq6DhgAwsgQwaHhcJHaUCoAzmhwvGDAvAh0RlnAeXQA5lFQAPS1UIXAFhAA-MEQAG4KANxa9VCBaAi+vhACjQhQviJk0HLQCEQAVlBLyxAYUOEWCADuUKK8FpONOFBo8mhkXAC+PPyCouJQEgBCpGRKKnDqNTH6YBGYifbgZPwBIJQEJhCL-PSOBIqZKwtI1bK5fKFYqlcr8SrpbRNFq4ioEu48UCQV7fBQANREVggWSg+Hen1pvxo0gWimUvR4wzoZR0405Rmk-LgDKZLPwGgyAMcwPoBEJWghgSBUAArOrMszMQUiiVCPwyKKGPqlfFEkYAIwAJgAzPriUlCJhZLwWVlZAELEhoaxttBGbs9hAkJQBgpEHAAIQ1AZQAB+6Yzmaz2ZzOeTDSgUhWm2AUAsvEEjOmIhAazoFlrWUgaF4QlrZBYezoOkQkDghWZrhEdCDAHJ3aPMghmcHSxBTD7S-wztTRzz5HyfqOKVw6H5mWAxNAzOIsll7H2ByyFdohSL1qy-hlFQjDLRxpQRCy78B9eD-FqRh6jUGQYnkxo4madAWqqf7aDawBIh6TquiBRIViShAALK1nsxQ-EIKAnHAIj8CQBzmpaapoVoMKpFIQgJLscBZEYADsNT3BkP6WuKNJSjKKAzvg6x9AMLBQHGCBwDuPHuHxko-IJwlPvBr7aiCnD6pqUL2sBoGGuB2KmgQACCkZZCM0CYAAytsoLWupSFGM6jr2m6GEegQ2CQDkRlQPaAAM9rcLcdQNOQNZAA)