# How to change type of properties via key match in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object that is already dynamically typed. Those types are mostly correct except one thing which is not picked up by TypeScript itself.

I iterate over the object and I convert some properties into Dates if they and with `At`. `startAt`, `createdAt` and so on.

This way I end up with a wrong type.

```
 type UserRaw = {
    name: string;
    createdAt: string;
};

const normalizeUser = function (attributes: UserRaw) {
    const normalized = { ...attributes };
    Object.entries(normalized).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (key.endsWith('At')) {
            (normalized as any)[key] = new Date(value as any);
        }
    });
    return normalized;
}

export type User = ReturnType<typeof normalizeUser>; // this is wrong at this point
```

Can I use some modern TypeScript feature and correct this? I need to map over the keys of the type and detect if the key ends with `At` and then say the property type is `Date` instead.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NrvMzN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: The compiler will not be able to read your code and understand the implication it has on the types, so you will have to tell it explicitly.  Probably like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9JzMm), but without a definition of `UserRaw` in your example it's hard to tell.

Comment: heres a more complete example: https://shorturl.at/qDF38

Comment: Your `AtKeysToDate` seems like exactly what I'm looking for! I'll experiment with it. Thank you.

Comment:  That link brings me back to the code I posted.  I'm not sure what you were trying to show me, but your example code should be in your question anyway; please [edit] and put a definition for `UserRaw` in there.

Comment: sorry, not sure what happened, this should be working hopefully: https://shorturl.at/acfzB

Comment: Okay, so [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w6ByRw) works for your use cases?  If so I can write up an answer.  If not, could you edit failing examples into your question code?

Comment: yes, this is sufficient! and it should work for my usecase.

Comment: I was playing around with something like `{ [P in keyof T]: P extends `${string}At` ? Date : T[P] }` - could you explain how your `infer F` works and bascially, where that `F` is coming from?

Comment: You could do `\`${string}At\`` also if you want, that should work too.  The type `\`${string}\`` is a pattern template literal.  `infer F` would grab whatever it starts with (like `"created"`) and put it into `F`, which you could use later if you want.  But since you don't use it, your way is fine also.  I'm happy to write up either answer.  Let me know (might be a little while til I get a chunk of time to write the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's express the output type of `normalizeUser()` as the result of a type function `AtKeysToDate<T>` which [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) a type `T` to another type with the same keys, but whose values depend on whether or not the associated key ends in `"At`".

You can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to do some parsing and concatenation on string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  Here's one way to do it:

```
type AtKeysToDate<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: K extends `${string}At` ? Date : T[K] }
```

The value of the property with key `K` is [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) depending on whether or not it is assignable to `` `${string}At` ``, a "pattern" template literal (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) which captures the concept of "a string that ends in `"At"`".

You can verify that it behaves as you'd like:

```
type UserRaw = {
    name: string;
    createdAt: string;
};

type User = AtKeysToDate<UserRaw>;
/* type User = {
    name: string;
    createdAt: Date;
} */
```

---

Note that if you cared at all about the part of the key before the `"At"`, you could use [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract it:

```
type AtKeysToSomethingElse<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: K extends `${infer F}At` ? F : T[K] }

type WeirdUser = AtKeysToSomethingElse<UserRaw>
/* type WeirdUser = {
    name: string;
    createdAt: "created";
} */
```

The behavior of `` K extends `${infer F}At` ? Date : T[K] `` and `` K extends `${string}At` ? Date : T[K] `` is pretty much the same, except that the former stores the matched part of the string in a new type parameter `F`, while the latter matches the string but throws away the matched part.  Since you don't need the matched part, you might as well just use the pattern template literal instead of conditional type inference.

---

Anyway, the compiler currently cannot and probably will never be able to inspect the implementation of a function like `normalizeUser()` and understand that its output type is `AtKeysToDate<UserRaw>`.  It's not even able to *verify* that if you tell it so.  So if you want the implementation to compile, you will need to tell it the types it can't figure out, or tell it not to worry about types it can't verify, via something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const normalizeUser = function (attributes: UserRaw) {
    const normalized = { ...attributes } as any as User;
    Object.entries(normalized).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (key.endsWith('At')) {
            (normalized as any)[key] = new Date(value as any);
        }
    });
    return normalized;
}
```

Here we assert that `normalized` is of type `User`, so the compiler will understand that `normalizeUser()` returns a `User`.  In three places I wrote `as any` to silence the compiler's warnings, since it cannot understand that `normalized` will end up being a `User`; nor does it understand that `key` will necessarily be a key of `UserRaw` (see [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)), nor does it understand that `value` will be the right sort of argument with which one can construct a `Date`.  Assertions abound.  But as long as you're confident that the implementation does what you want, callers of `normalizedUser()` will have a proper strongly typed result.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAgsDSEQGcAqB7AIgQ2BAPKgHxQC8AUFFVAN5QDa8UAlgHZQDWS6AZlKgF0AXFCYQAHnlYATZFAAGAEhrJgAJzYBzAL5x5UAPxQceKCNSMBUbeXKhIUAKrIIagErYA7mVqVqrbABbCBFVDVZNAG4-KgBjNQhcCGk4UPUtaO1ou3BoZ1cfOEQUDBMCfPcvImiAegAqKHs8lzUfGhioAOC08KiO+MS8FOARMsyoOprbJtgEJDR0AGV0YOAACy0AUQAbF0ISCmpaBiY2Tm4+QRExSQgZOSUaNh4CgDFdYH0jV7N+S2tprkoAB1CDMNTSCqFOYlJYrCDrLa7cotDyeIjkeqNIGg8GQlptDpdEJQMIZfoJJLDEQAIgGVJp40mtnIsXQrFUnXQakC2G2zAAXhAoaQoDwAK6sWLAZjsqAAClw6QARuK8MgRBU0QBKXxHNkc4Bcnl8wXJNpQAB01qVGlV6usUGwcmwrBATrkFWiRwA8sqAFYQaWWu7pCDIeWsbm8-lC6Tay08bmbbCxNby+X0LggAA0UAAbnzxRABLrSCR2kcjsw+PLsyH7sDmOt5QByOCt7W6ytV3uR6OmuMep1u7VZpBWUWsCDeMrywvbYvD10gbXe3sAo7aNcdBLAcVqdhRk2x5KZFlAA)

Comment: What a brilliant answer. Thank you very much! I suspected template literals could help somehow but I had no idea how to use them well. Thanks again.