# TypeScript errors when trying to create product filters

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a product page, with a sidebar that has some product sorting links.

What I've written seems to work, but I'm getting some TypeScript errors that I'm not sure how to fix.

```
const SORT_KEYS = {
  BEST_SELLING: "Best selling",
  CREATED_AT: "Created at",
  PRICE: "Price",
  PRODUCT_TYPE: "Product type",
  RELEVANCE: "Relevance",
  TITLE: "Title",
  UPDATED_AT: "Updated at",
  VENDOR: "Vendor",
} as const;

type SortKey = keyof typeof SORT_KEYS;
type SortLabel = typeof SORT_KEYS[SortKey];

// Value of `query.sortKey` that comes from `getServerSideProps` in Next.js
let queryKey: string | string[] | undefined;

const sortKey: SortKey | undefined = Object.keys(SORT_KEYS).find(key => key === queryKey);

interface SortLink {
  href: SortKey;
  label: SortLabel;
}

const sortLinks: Array<SortLink> = Object.keys(SORT_KEYS).map((key) => ({
  href: key,
  label: SORT_KEYS[key],
}));
```

There are two values that I need — `sortKey` and `sortLinks`.

`sortKey` is the value I pass to the GraphQL API which accepts an enum of the values `SORT_KEYS` (or undefined). The code I've written for this is giving me the following TypeScript error:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"BEST_SELLING" | "CREATED_AT" | "PRICE" | "PRODUCT_TYPE" | "RELEVANCE" | "TITLE" | "UPDATED_AT" | "VENDOR" | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"BEST_SELLING" | "CREATED_AT" | "PRICE" | "PRODUCT_TYPE" | "RELEVANCE" | "TITLE" | "UPDATED_AT" | "VENDOR" | undefined'.(2322)
```

`sortLinks` are the links that are used in the sidebar. The href property would actually be `/products?sortKey=${key}`, but just so I understand how to type this properly, I've left it as just the key. Currently this value is coming through as a string, which probably fine for my purposes, my main concern is the label, currently I'm getting the TypeScript error below:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ readonly BEST_SELLING: "Best selling"; readonly CREATED_AT: "Created at"; readonly PRICE: "Price"; readonly PRODUCT_TYPE: "Product type"; readonly RELEVANCE: "Relevance"; readonly TITLE: "Title"; readonly UPDATED_AT: "Updated at"; readonly VENDOR: "Vendor"; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ readonly BEST_SELLING: "Best selling"; readonly CREATED_AT: "Created at"; readonly PRICE: "Price"; readonly PRODUCT_TYPE: "Product type"; readonly RELEVANCE: "Relevance"; readonly TITLE: "Title"; readonly UPDATED_AT: "Updated at"; readonly VENDOR: "Vendor"; }'.(7053)
```

I'd really love a bit of help understanding and resolving these issues

Comment: `Object.keys` will always return `string[]`. See [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrst of all, you need to create custom typeguard for `queryKey`.

```js
const isString = (key: any): key is string => typeof key === 'string'

const isSorkKey = (key: string | string[] | undefined): key is SortKey =>
    isString(key)
        ? new RegExp(Object.keys(SORT_KEYS).join('|')).test(key)
        : false
```

I assume that if `key` is either `string[]` or `undefined` - it is invalid. If it just a `string` we can check with regexp help.

Now, you can define `sortKey` as :

```js
const sortKey: SortKey | undefined = isSorkKey(queryKey) ? queryKey : undefined
```

There is an alternative version of getting `sortKey`, even less verbose. Since `find` method expect predicate function (function which returns boolean), you can use it as a user defined type guard:

```js
declare var queryKey: string | string[] | undefined

const sortKey = Object.keys(SORT_KEYS).find((key): key is keyof typeof SORT_KEYS => key === queryKey)
```

It works in the same way and is much faster.

And `sortLinks`:

```js
interface SortLink {
    href: SortKey;
    label: SortLabel;
}

type SortKeysTuple = Array<keyof typeof SORT_KEYS>

const sortLinks: SortLink[] = (Object.keys(SORT_KEYS) as SortKeysTuple).map((key) => ({
    href: key,
    label: SORT_KEYS[key],
}));
```

Most of the time it worth using type assertion along with `Object.keys`, just like I did here:`Object.keys(SORT_KEYS) as SortKeysTuple)`. However, you should be aware that it is not the safest approach because it allows duplicates, like `["BEST_SELLING", "BEST_SELLING"]`. From the other hand, there is a safest approach:

```js
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];


type Keys = TupleUnion<keyof typeof SORT_KEYS>;
```

But `TupleUnion` will eat your CPU on breakfast :D. Hence, I would stick with the first one.

Finally, the whole code:

```js
const SORT_KEYS = {
    BEST_SELLING: "Best selling",
    CREATED_AT: "Created at",
    PRICE: "Price",
    PRODUCT_TYPE: "Product type",
    RELEVANCE: "Relevance",
    TITLE: "Title",
    UPDATED_AT: "Updated at",
    VENDOR: "Vendor",
} as const;

type SortKey = keyof typeof SORT_KEYS;
type SortLabel = typeof SORT_KEYS[SortKey];

let queryKey: string | string[] | undefined;

const isString = (key: any): key is string => typeof key === 'string'

const isSorkKey = (key: string | string[] | undefined): key is SortKey =>
    isString(key)
        ? new RegExp(Object.keys(SORT_KEYS).join('|')).test(key)
        : false


const sortKey: SortKey | undefined = isSorkKey(queryKey) ? queryKey : undefined

interface SortLink {
    href: SortKey;
    label: SortLabel;
}

type SortKeysTuple = Array<keyof typeof SORT_KEYS>


const sortLinks: SortLink[] = (Object.keys(SORT_KEYS) as SortKeysTuple).map((key) => ({
    href: key,
    label: SORT_KEYS[key],
}));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QHSW4kDoACxMjx4iIByMOfhxoLEEfOQPjh3WRz+kYuVwgKDiqTaN3URiMpmSAB4Tc8zR9od84NajqQBbAhQDGAGIIm2wHWTcFWLJYlZdmlZ9LXBVVs-cic3m2uqALamVLa3U2mAKsh+UPc-VXTKUOPiCNjutwuUoxTrVWq-ZAA)

Further, more, I suggest you yo use another function to generate `sortLinks`. Since, it is clear that `SortLink` object can be only one of several states. I mean, if `href` is  `"BEST_SELLING"`, then `label` should be `Best selling`. If this is true, you can use this:

```js
const SORT_KEYS = {
    BEST_SELLING: "Best selling",
    CREATED_AT: "Created at",
    PRICE: "Price",
    PRODUCT_TYPE: "Product type",
    RELEVANCE: "Relevance",
    TITLE: "Title",
    UPDATED_AT: "Updated at",
    VENDOR: "Vendor",
} as const;


type Mapped<T extends Record<string, string>, Key extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Key extends any ? { href: Key, label: T[Key] } : any

const links = <
    Key extends string,
    Value extends string,
    Obj extends Record<Key, Value>
>(obj: Obj) =>
    (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof Obj>)
        .map(
            (key) => ({
                href: key,
                label: obj[key],
            })) as Mapped<Obj>[];

const result = links(SORT_KEYS)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygeQEoBUD6BpAogTTjAXhgG8AoGCmAISznTiwBlGBJAOQHEAuGAIioCm0GBAEAbMQEswAc14AacpQDCSLAEEUWACJpNPXsoBOAgIZQBAExjmFSigAUkLZVgMOjk4ALuUYThG0AVWV0FBwHNz4PEEsAV2BYKABPAAcfRT81RiwANXU2VwMkcQEAN1Mwb19KFBYUHIMUSSgxDPsYIIdtTR09FAMg1MtzKxsoGopcrDZtZANcgTBLECM7AF8bCBhQSCgAblIjlPSYAFlTVPTLAB4UGAEADwtl7ZLQI1voT1l5ESgfjIAHx-DACZIPZ5LSzbADW4JAADMYPciPDkkiUUDCB0wRCni8YTYwBCAPwkGAACxMiJ4eL%20YlMACNxDwUABtPEAXRgmx4lWSR12wikYFh2yIN1x4MhhO232kMkylFypjEcQEsuh8oBiuVFAQTIAVlrXjB3qtbvSYKr1QIgaQgQAKEDGniGo0ASkIDr8To9AkSADp0RAXcbvaZtuojEZTMkbujMR6gZ6On4gwBbS5O9N%20ShO9HegjYp1kfMV-PUgS0mDo-WViuMlliHiuo3s9FchuN9aeyPbC5XKw3FPsrmHUjC2AmCBxMSwIii8VOxCoTC4OCeoA)

Comment: @LukeBennett I made an important update, please take a look

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate such a detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the compiler needs a little help as some of the functions used return `string`. e.g. `Object.keys` has the signature `(method) ObjectConstructor.keys(o: {}): string[] (+1 overload)`

Since the `queryKey` type doesn't match the type used in the rest of your code if you're certain it's of a certain type then you can use the `as` assertion.

```
const SORT_KEYS = {
  BEST_SELLING: "Bes0t selling",
  CREATED_AT: "Created at",
  PRICE: "Price",
  PRODUCT_TYPE: "Product type",
  RELEVANCE: "Relevance",
  TITLE: "Title",
  UPDATED_AT: "Updated at",
  VENDOR: "Vendor",
} as const;

type SortKey = keyof typeof SORT_KEYS;
type SortLabel = typeof SORT_KEYS[SortKey];

// Value of `query.sortKey` that comes from `getServerSideProps` in Next.js
let queryKey: string | string[] | undefined;

const sortKey = Object.keys(SORT_KEYS).find((key) => key === queryKey as SortKey) ;

interface SortLink {
  href: SortKey;
  label: SortLabel;
}

const sortLinks:SortLink[] = Object.keys(SORT_KEYS).map((key) => ({
  href: key as SortKey,
  label: SORT_KEYS[key as SortKey],
}));
```