# how to handle Typescript error Object.ts (7053) in newer version of typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have code function which is working fine one of my previous project, when I tried to copy it another project it started giving me following error. I have no idea what this mean. Can someone suggest what change is requires to make it work

my first guess is TS version or tslint.

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.ts(7053)*

[image]

```
   private convertDates(object: Object) {
        if (!object || !(object instanceof Object)) {
            return;
        }

        if (object instanceof Array) {
            for (const item of object) {
                this.convertDates(item);
            }
        }

        var dateRegex = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*)?)$/; ///^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?(([+-]\d\d:\d\d)|Z)?$/;

        for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
            const value = object[key];
            if (value instanceof Array) {
                for (const item of value) {
                    this.convertDates(item);
                }
            }

            if (value instanceof Object) {
                this.convertDates(value);
            }

            if (typeof value === 'string' && dateRegex.test(value)) {
                object[key] = new Date(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Object.keys(object)` returns `string[]` and not `(keyof typeof object)[]`. And TS cannot be sure that any `string` can be used to index `object` (for example, `object['thisdoesnotexist']` does not work).

For the reason why this is expected TS behavior, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012175/3083470)

To fix it, either use `Object.entries()` to get both the key and value at the same time or cast `key` to `keyof typeof object` like so:

```
const value = object[key as keyof typeof object];
```

This explicitly tells the TS compiler that you **can** use `key` to index `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because Typescript becomes more strict with newer version.

Regarding to Typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object) itself, you shouldn't use `Object` to type an object:

> Don’t ever use the types Number, String, Boolean, Symbol, or Object These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code.

Typescript recommends to use the type `object` instead but you'd have the same error in the console.

So, either you create an appropriate interface as type for your object or you can use the type `Record<Keys, Type>` (more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type))

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

Your function would look like this:

```
private convertDates(object: Record<string, any>) {
  ...
}
```

I know, `any` is also considered a bad practice, so use appropriate typing ;)