# Is it possible to constrain the types of generics to only allow known properties?

Tags: typescript

If you provide an object with too many properties to a function, you get an error:

```js
type Options = {
    str: "a" | "b",
}

function foo(a: Options) {
    return a.str;
}

const resultA = foo({
    str: "a",
    extraOption: "errors as expected",
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------ Object literal may only specify known properties.
});
```

This is nice, I want this. But since I know what type I'll be returning based on its input, I want to make the function generic like so:

```js
function bar<T extends Options>(a: T) {
    return a.str as T["str"];
}
```

But now extra properties are allowed on the input.

```js
const resultB = bar({
    str: "a",
    extraOption: "no error!?",
});
```

Is there any way to restrict this?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=23&ssc=4&pln=20&pc=1&filetype=ts#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKjWACcAuKAIgEMqoAfagIyoBo8BfPPAMwFcUAY0SoovJEgAUNSnFHoAlLgJFSEYP1IooNAHQlSAbi48hqElHVp%20AG2ABBLOMlT8RYmUq12qwhAAPMhp5ZBRvCFJSJFIMGgxAyBEIABNfAHp0wgA9XLz8gsKigoBaMvLYZgArCBEoWwRgSJpbKABbGhAoVFsutCSEXi6AaxQkAHcdMGjIUkQIND0uRRMeAWEFKGYaUgAeABUoQKaUFIxQiwA%20GUp95Xc1DS0dfUNdDH2AbSpDKgBdEzcPDmdDAKwLOzAABCzm2pDcfk8FGodA4HmOpBC8DC3jGRyiMQAhAB%20XycFZAA)

Comment: Do either of [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/N5312W) work for you?  Note that forbidding excess properties is more of a linter rule than a type safety measure.  You can do things to discourage them, but it is impossible to completely prevent them.  Let me know if I should write up an answer, or if there's something I'm missing about your question.

Comment: Thanks, these are some great solutions! I'm not looking for a super failsafe way to do this, just something that behaves at least somewhat similarly to a non generic function. Feel free to write it up as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case? Why do you want to forbid excess properties, if you could just not use them?

Comment: I have a rather complex system where the properties you can put in change depending on the values of other properties. Having excess properties is not really a huge problem, but I'd like to be a bit more strict on what can be put in so I can be more confident I'm doing the right thing. Since putting in a wrong property probably means I'm doing something I didn't intend to.

Comment: @Jespertheend I'm not sure I understand your question. You had `foo`, which only accepted `Options` (so no excess properties). Then you said you wanted not to limit `foo`'s input to `Options`, so you create `bar` that accepts any type `T` that extends `Options`. You then build a literal type `{ str: 'a' | 'b', extraOption: string }`, which extends `Options`. But then you don't want `bar` to accept it? It contradicts the generic type you defined as `bar`'s input, which is anything that extends `Options`. Why shouldn't `bar` accept that literal type?

Comment: @RafaelEyng I wanted `bar` to accept any value for its `str` option, not to have it also accept all kinds of other options. But I needed it to be a generic because I wanted its return type to match the `str` option.
When I asked this question I wasn't aware that there was a way to make only the `str` option generic, rather than the entire parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are not "sealed"; excess properties are allowed.  This enables all sorts of good stuff like interface and class extension, and is just part of TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system). It is always possible for excess properties to sneak in, so you should probably make sure that your `foo()` or `bar()` implementations don't do anything terrible if the function argument has such properties.  If you iterate over properties via something like [the `Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), you should *not* assume that the result will be just known keys.  (This is why [`Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218))

Of course, throwing away excess properties is often indicative of a problem.  If you pass an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) directly to a function, then any extra properties on that literal will most likely be completely ignored and forgotten about.  That could be indicative of an error, and so  [object literals undergo checking for excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks):

```
function foo(a: Options) {
    return a.str;
}

const resultA = foo({
    str: "a",
    extraOption: "errors as expected", // error
});
```

The reason why this goes away for something like

```
function bar<T extends Options>(a: T) {
    return a.str as T["str"];
}
const resultB = bar({
    str: "a",
    extraOption: "no error!?",
});
```

is because generic functions do have the possibility of keeping track of such extra properties:

```
function barKT<T extends Options>(a: T) {
    return { ...a, andMore: "hello" }
}
const resultKT = barKT({ str: "a", num: Math.PI });
console.log(resultKT.num.toFixed(2)) // "3.14"
```

But in your version of `bar()` you are only returning the `str` property, so excess properties really will be lost.  So you'd like an error on excess properties, and you're not getting one.;

---

But this raises the question: why is `bar()` generic?  If you don't want to allow excess properties and you only care about the one `str` property, then there's no obvious motivation for `T extends Options`.  If you only want to possibly narrow the type of `T["str"]`, then in fact you only want *that part* of the input to be generic:

```
function barC<S extends Options["str"]>(a: { str: S }) {
    return a.str;
}

const resultC = barC({
    str: "a",
    extraOption: "error", // error here
});
```

---

But if you really do neet `T extends Options` for some reason, you can discourage excess properties by making the function input be of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where excess properties have their property value types mapped to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Since there are no values of type `never`, the object literal passed in cannot meet that requirement, and they will generate an error:

```
function barD<T extends Options>(a: 
  { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof Options ? T[K] : never }
) {
    return a.str
}

const resultD = barD({
    str: "a",
    extraOption: "error", // error here
});
```

Hooray!

---

Again, while this discourages excess properties, it does not  absolutely prevent them.  Structural subtyping requires that you can widen a `{str: "a" | "b", extraOption: string}` to `{str: "a" | "b"}`:

```
const someValue = {
    str: "a",
    extraOption: "error",
} as const;

const someOptions: Options = someValue; // okay

barC(someOptions); // no error
barD(someOptions); // no error
```

So again, you should make sure your implementations don't assume that excess properties are impossible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&filetype=ts#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-UVDz-Ecxygcw7APdQAEd+AQdR1W6QREjqZoDxGCAQAwHUaAAN2gZdV3XbpQEgHpeE4gzSGfLkxFxAARQVT2Ei80GAygcCgKFeVvKBNNHSyHnhShfJc95-K0pBLLcqAmSlHyb0oFAIGs-0AQJOUQV0OCbO4PAg3NDF7Ac9CHKwogcJ8Ul8KCClCOoSJohIjgA0rDY3wcAA1I4HAeQdxk9BAUAjMTx0nKAJgQA0V3UAyFyFIRFgwYzIg3cQ7D6J8CqQ4N2ggLrWn4aBsEBQgqpJAkCKPIjmtZCEJLNNZCuIJB9rcuQjwwbA9oOo6ICMKANiQEYuh4d8pF+tzViB7JaSamI8EcyG3ogaHAY2eHiJ4DZg3RdjuhY4gdTHWwDyDBAUkiXQhCWqkRsW5bZrXNaEEWdUD06EZhtGmxFJY0gh3aMBQ32hcPW5QdJ0WHc0SEW5DOYMc0U9CBEyAA)