# Taking a typescript object and converting each property into a union of separate objects

Tags: typescript

My objective is to take a typescript object and convert each property into a union of separate objects.

For example:

```
{
 200: number;
 500: string;
}
```

into

```
{
 200: number;
 500?: undefined;
} |
{
 500: string;
 200?: undefined;
}
```

I believe I was able to get this level except anytime I add a random property along with a valid property, it doesn't error out. How do I make it error out?
ie

```
{
 100: "why no error", // this should error error...
 200: 100,
}
```

Full code sample:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
type _ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends unknown
  ? Id<T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>>
  : never;
type ExclusifyUnion<T> = _ExclusifyUnion<T, AllKeys<T>>;
type split_return_type<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { [P in K]: T[P] };
};
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
export type SchemezLayoutReturnType<T> = Promise<
  ExclusifyUnion<ValueOf<split_return_type<Required<T>>>>
>;

function TestFnx<T>(input: T, handleAsync: () => SchemezLayoutReturnType<T>) {
    return {
        input,
        handleAsync,
    }
}

type required_return_type = {
    200: number;
    500: string;
}
const rrr: required_return_type = {
    200: 100,
    500: "00"
};
TestFnx(rrr, async () => {
    return {
        100: "200",
        200: 100,
        // 500: "oii",
    }
});
```

Reference: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggGwQaSmAzgHgCoD4YC8M2MUAHiFAHYAm6MArlQNZUD2A7lTAPwzNo2AM2IwAXDCpQAblABOAblCRYASRo58REuUq16ASypD5MAKq8YAbxgBtZDCP9BIswF0JZ%2025gBfcZIy8krg0DAA%20gCiZADGCAzoBkJgZlQGbFQ4ADQwDrrUdDAACnJs0HLgqGBaovn6jCzsXMAwluo4MABkxQCGFQY9CJgASlAxbHIa0XEMNFCYyDkCYMLEuDlSsnK4Oy0Bm8HKYdPxicmp6Zl4hBEnCUkpaRnZ8EhVWHi4ISow6BAIBhA4TkUBADDkVHCoXm1yIVj29kc3GWq2wHmsdiKSNy6OwtiKPl8SiJR1gADVBgwoAB5ISaG54lEiNFKcgQCYgGDQmAAZRiAAsoABbKAALwAMj0VgwQKMwRDsCp6UQSmwhQZ0PM9nczo9LpgKfEaXS-gCgSD5ZDoSMoABHBgGEEaT67L7AYBCJgxECXYhQdAgABiVDImgAFEYIDKJNgcvyerQEFA4OgwFQYhIwwBKQj4PmCkUSqVsGVy8FURXQTQ5%20GtVoW8vWPZ1uuRmVZZstmDxxPJ1Ppjst3zAYekmAg%202OqA0YGg8tQn5wzsAJgADKuJFQGEKAEaHFsAVnXEgDciMAHNicBxlQA%20O5HIJBOHU7Z5aF2Ely21xuYABGddBzrI9fwAInXUCRyUbB-SDEMwwfOQch6fsYhgbNcybFsGwhLCu1aACwJ-UCgPwn8JEI0iuwAemomAQIkUC2AMAwSM7YdfCzBQgA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w217YW) meet your needs? I simplified your type and added the constraint to prohibit (well, discourage) excess properties

Comment: @jcalz Wow! Still wrapping my head around how u did it but yes, this is what I was looking for. Add as solution so I can give pts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Object types in TypeScript are not sealed, and for that reason excess or unexpected properties cannot be truly prohibited. The best you can do is discourage them.  See [Is it possible to constrain the types of generics to only allow known properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70689538/2887218) for examples and a discussion.

---

First we can simplify your type to turn an object type like `{a: string, b: number}` into a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of one-property types like `{a: string, b?: never} | {a?: never, b: number}`:

```
type MakeUnion<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> & { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never }
}[keyof T]
```

That's called a "distributive object type" (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and immediately [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union of all the properties.  `{[K in keyof T]: F<K>}[keyof T]` is equivalent to `F<K1> | F<K2> | ⋯` for all the keys `K1` and `K2` in `keyof T`.

The `F<K>` there is `Pick<T, K> & {[P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never}`.  Meaning for each property key in `K`, we are producing the type `Pick<T, K>` (using [the `Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to grab the one property we do want), and [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with `{[P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never}` (using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion)), prohibiting all the keys of `T` which are *not* `K`. Well, technically it makes them [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), but that's pretty close to prohibiting it.

Let's run a test:

```
type RequiredReturnType = {
  200: number;
  500: string;
}
type UnionOfOneProps = MakeUnion<RequiredReturnType>;
/* type UnionOfOneProps = 
    (Pick<RequiredReturnType, 200> & { 500?: undefined; }) | 
    (Pick<RequiredReturnType, 500> & { 200?: undefined; }) */
```

That might not be displayed exactly like `{200: number, 500?: never} | {200?: never, 500: string}`, but it's equivalent.

---

Next you want to prevent or discourage all excess properties when calling `testFnx()`. We can do it this way:

```
function testFnx<T, U extends MakeUnion<T> &
  { [P in Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>]: never }>(
    input: T, handleAsync: () => Promise<U>) {
  return {
    input,
    handleAsync,
  }
}
```

I've added a second [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `U`. The compiler will still infer `T` from `input`, and now it will infer `U` from `handleAsync`'s return type. Then since `U` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `MakeUnion<T> & { [P in Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>]: never }`, it will require that `handleSaync` return something that satisfies both `MakeUnion<T>` (which is the part we already know about), and `{ [P in Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>]: never }`. This is similar to the key-prohibiting type above.  Here we say that whatever keys are in `U` and that are not in `T` should be prohibited.  Again, you can't say "prohibited", but you can say "of the impossible `never` type".  Unless the excess properties have type `never`, which shouldn't happen, you'll get the error you expect.

Let's test that too:

```
const rrr: RequiredReturnType = {
  200: 0,
  500: "x"
};

testFnx(rrr, async () => { return { 200: 1 } }); // okay
testFnx(rrr, async () => { return { 500: "z" } }); // okay
testFnx(rrr, async () => { return { 200: 2, 500: "y" } }); // error

testFnx(rrr, async () => { return { 700: 3, 500: "x" } }); // error
// Types of property '700' are incompatible.
```

Looks good.  `testFnx()` still allows the single-prop types you wanted, and prohibits mixed-prop properties, but also prohibits objects with extra properties.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=22&pc=17#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQwNZQKoDsCWB7dAeAFQD4YBeGAb2BhgG0BpGTdGFMbAMxgIF0AuGAAVMAYySEANDHokAZJTqCmLAKIAPEQBsArgBMoeNp25SZPAPwD0UAG5QATjAC+wJ7SNdewUJFgAlKABHbUx7KF0AkG17dAJfMkpqGAAmAAZUq20AWwAjBwBuJIBWdIEAZxB7ZgBzQpdwaBgMHHQAeQ5W60F7bAgyhMQUZtw8AODQ8Mjo2N8iQoB6ACoYBthhto6unr6EgAphMVGgkLCIqCiYuOgpNNS5RJoaEtTLGG10fQ5mcLqAShgAD4wfaicRjE6Tc7TK5QKTPe5UR4pdKvd6fb66P4wRbzbwcd4iEAtFZQCoAMXQakkTRgUDUICgH36gzQWBGxBgsiSFEUyhg6i0egMHiaUhFxH4MGsdkcTiIuySNGYEG0IAEBCkAAsEB9NFAAIJlMDoEQCXb-UgkbrYLKYMoGVBEf6ImBhC4sF1K9AqkASRUwbW6g1Gk1+mguFzeES4Cqu+z2ATgiZnd0whIu24CVJhmDPAQAIjU+dchVApJAFLUu3j9ikCBDImBFpIPLd0wUmZgAEZnM5fvkYPN5jBsEgEGAy+TKdX43WG02yC3XVCYgo8zB8wAvfO9pz9wfD0fjycV6c1ufGxvmxcKNurnmd5Jw0obsA7px9gdD2nx7D2bwMlOVbnjA9aXgulq3iuHowAA7C+ADMz4ZBuRa7vu34OD0-7fjC-TGBA2wOOAMAAOTwakpGgWEyjRlkEAIESOR6gAdN4QA)

Comment: In my new [sample](https://tsplay.dev/NrE7ow), do you know why if I directly use the return type in the function like I did for the second TestFnx, it directly highlights the error? Even in your example, if I directly apply Promise<MakeUnion<RequiredReturnType>>, it directly highlights the error but not if its setup in the generic function.

Comment: Because you explicitly annotated the return type and so you get [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks). See the answer to the question I linked above, or look up "excess property checking" to see the various issues around it.