# traverse keys of enum gives typing issue

Tags: typescript, enums

Suppose you want to print all values of an enum

```
enum AnEnum {
    a = 'a',
    b = 'b'
}

const keys = Object.keys(AnEnum);

keys.forEach(key => {  
     console.log(AnEnum[key]);
});
```

This gives the following error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof AnEnum'.   No index
> signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof
> AnEnum'

[image]
[DEMO](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCi5oG8BQUNQIZQLxQHIsCAadTAIz0IoNQF9VUBjAexAGcAXKAa2ACeHagHkKAK2DMuAOn5CAFHESQAlAG4m8jjIBmrAE7wszABYL5eAHxRkGcpjadWAG2AyXrAOZKESANryALoaDKFAA)

I was only able to fix this is with adding `any`

```
(AnEnum as any)[key]
```

but I guess there should be better solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAvpkW) meet your needs?  If not, please elaborate.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz You should've posted that as an answer, because it works beautifully :)

Comment: Yes, that will work, thnx. I've updated my post too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is given a [typing in the TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/818962087cadaae70a44303678ef166c61ca0bb1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L261) like this:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  keys(o: object): string[];
}
```

The return type is `string[]`.  That means `Object.keys(obj)` is a value of type `Array<string>` and *not* a value of type `Array<keyof typeof obj>` (where [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) represents a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the known keys of an object type).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218) for a thorough explanation of why.  Here I'll just say that the compiler cannot guarantee that an object has *only* the keys it knows about.

And that means if you try to index into an object with a key only known to be  `string`, that will only work if that object is known to have a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  If not, then the compiler will complain that it has no idea what property may or may not be a `string` index, and it will produce a value of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) and a compiler warning.

---

In cases like this where you are sure that your object only has the known keys (e.g., a [string `enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) where there's no reverse mapping), you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that:

```
const keys = Object.keys(AnEnum) as Array<keyof typeof AnEnum>;
```

And then your loop will work:

```
keys.forEach(key => {
    console.log(AnEnum[key]); // okay
});
```

---

Do note that `Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>` is not a panacea.  If it turns out that `obj` does have more keys than the compiler knows about, and worse, the property values at these keys are not the same type as the values at the known keys, then you can write something that compiles fine but explodes at runtime:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string,
    b: string
}
const f = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye", c: 123 };
const foo: Foo = f; // okay, f is a valid Foo

(Object.keys(foo) as Array<keyof Foo>).forEach(k => console.log(foo[k].toUpperCase()));
// HELLO
// GOODBYE
//  RUNTIME ERROR! foo[k].toUpperCase is not a function
```

So be careful!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCi5oG8BQUNQIZQLxQHIsCAadTAIz0IoNQF9VUBjAexAGcAXKAa2ACeHagHkKAK2DMuAOn5CAFHESQAlNmEwATlqwCAPPNYAzKFwEAHYCdgIkAPgDcTeRxnHWW+FmYALBfJ49lBomFBsnKwANsAyUawA5kp2kADa8gC6qs702UyoAJYgXMBaxj7AUABirKwh5BhYAFxQ3FpFCWRhFC1tHQws7NxQpvjI2C0ARL7AUfGTJFA9UJMJtQAmFALAC+EtAIwATADMUPTOEcMerC01dfjGjlAA9M9QrLx6qApiktJygg4Cmu6iwmh0ekMghsd3sqncnm8fgCQXCQ2isXiSWu6QyMi4rAAqhYrFoAMJg4AKVQ05yvKAACXgABlmSJUPSAOIiEQAEQAQgBNeAct6AXg3AKU7UAASoSAHIAFQAkgBZeBQeDS6UiaUAQhGtVx+KJJNKFI4lQKwhArB4OGMYBA0gK7CAA)