# Typescript: Generic function should not return union of all types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I managed to type the object `currentProps` so TS knows which properties it haves AND each property has its individual type (not an union of all possible types).

So far so good.

Then I have this generic function `overrideForIndex` which gets one of the possible properties, and should return its value. But it can't be assigned, because its return-type is a union, and not the specific type.

Now I could just cast it as any and call it a day, but I am curious if there is a way to handle this properly without casting to `any`.

Here is the "simplified" example:
([open in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiAKUJgM5wC8cA3gLABQccAlgCYD8AXHAHYCuAtgEbBQDclajBowANsGZw8MKDVYBzQRQC%20lSgGMIrGXDA58LAErAtUOgB4A1sEQQAZuiwG8AGjgBDVogB8RUkK0dCwAjABMAMyugSLiwCwA5PYQEAmUahSUoJCwcFo68Pq4AHIenMAExADy3ABWpjAAdDaIeAAURfgAlJ4EAIJQUB6I1rYOTti4eD7Kmtq6dB4wHsam0JYcPHzuGJP4fsQkcAAMLEf0oZHusRKJyalwKiqzFPm63Ow0YnQAMksVMD2lTgbS6ZzgAG1MLRWHAWuMTABHT5QYCWXYuHwAXRYGKmUKxjyIfnIVDy83gCmAMD%20MAB-gsABU4KA6aw6AR4Y48fsOgZSuUWIyeoQ-ItlhDjliIZ0BcAscpqKiYOwoLCavUNE17DhOABRViyGgVPklMoVRqcDxgNqw0WQ1juKk0-4yW1dLFdHoeAheRDKZ7qV4UvKq1GGoH%20D5fX6uwEuUEvN7wCAANz4cjowAAYtAAJLs0AM5ms4DszljbnOKY%20U1gOVC9zyLMgFibXhQMETFwQxmE0WBcUeCHN0DS2XmhVBiflPCNZJQPUeDQAC1txJBGjDZfj%20NY-bgaYz9Bz%20cLIFt7mOPQA9AAqXqebxwO83r38IA))

```
export type MyProps = {
  id?: number;
  title?: string;
}

const props: Record<keyof MyProps, any> = {
  id: 123,
  title: 'foo'
}

export const propNames = Object.keys(props) as Array<keyof MyProps>;

const data: Record<number, MyProps> = { 0: { id: 123, title: 'foo' }};

const buildLatestProps = (): { [P in keyof Required<MyProps>]: MyProps[P] } => {
  const getLatest = <T extends keyof MyProps>(propName: T) => data[0][propName];
  return Object.fromEntries(propNames.map(n => [n, getLatest(n)])) as any;
};

const currentProps = buildLatestProps();

const overrideForIndex = <T extends keyof MyProps>(propName: T, index: number): MyProps[T] =>
  data[index][propName];

propNames.forEach(n => (currentProps[n] = overrideForIndex(n, 0) /* as any */)); // ERR: Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

Comment: The reason this is safe, is that there is a correlation through `n` between `overrideForIndex(n, 0)` and `currentProps[n]`. If instead of `n` you would use two different variables that come from different source, then this would not be safe, as they could hold different property names and thus have different types. Unfortunately typescript is not yet able to reason about such correlations.

Comment: From my experience, TS does not like mutations. You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/mutations) and/or related questions/answers which you can find at the bottom of article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at these lines, the types are acting how you are expecting them to.

```
currentProps["id"] = overrideForIndex("id", 0);
currentProps["title"] = overrideForIndex("title", 0);
```

However, when you use the forEach loop, you are effectively using the following, where `n` is the union type of the key names of `MyProps`:

```
propNames.forEach((n: keyof MyProps) => { currentProps[n] = overrideForIndex(n, 0) });
```

Currently, TypeScript cannot untangle this. In addition, there is a [great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174) on why such a change could lead to unintentional consequences.

You should avoid using `any` in 99% of "use cases" for it as you are effectively turning TypeScript off. In most instances where you would use `any`, `Record<KeyType, ValueType>` is sufficient like so:

```
propNames.forEach(n => ((currentProps as Record<typeof n, unknown>)[n] = overrideForIndex(n, 0)));
```

In that block, you effectively suppress the error without relying on turning TypeScript completely off. It will also throw an error if you did type `propNames` as `Array<keyof MyTypeExtendingMyProps>`.

Comment: First of all: thanks for explaining this! What's your opinion on using `any` within the `buildLatestProps` function? I tried to apply the Record approach there too, but with no success. Not sure if it is needed though, since this is somewhat "closed". But I would love to get rid of this `any` too if there is a way?