# Change values of keys of an object in an object array (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

I want to change the values of keys of the 1st object in an object array.

Following is the attempt I followed so far.

The object array:

```js
const objArray: FoodItems[] = [
  {
    apple: 4,
    banana: 7,
    'mango & grapes': 9,
    Cherry: 7,
  },
]
```

The above object is of the type of `FooItems[]`:

```js
export type FoodItems = {
  apple: number;
  banana: number;
  'mango & grapes': number;
  Cherry: number;
}
```

The new value of key I need to assign:

```
const newValue = 34;
```

The code I tried to modify each key:

```js
objArray.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  ...{
    apple: newValue,
    banana: newValue,
    'mango & grapes': newValue,
    Cherry: newValue,
  },
})),
```

Please, may I know a simpler way of doing this, instead of changing each key individually?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're setting new values for each key, so what other possible alternative is there to changing each one? I don't understand the question

Comment: objArray.map(item => ({
  ...item,
    apple: 44,
    banana: 67,
    'mango & grapes': 19,
    Cherry: 47,
  },
))


Keep ...item if you want to preserve other properties or else its not required to do ...item


.So, objArray.map(item => ({
    apple: 44,
    banana: 67,
    'mango & grapes': 19,
    Cherry: 47,
  }
))

Comment: yes, @CertainPerformance . I put my question wrong. I modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to map the keys of the existing object into an array of entries to create a new one and return the `newValue` in the value section.

```js
const objArray = [
  {
    apple: 4,
    banana: 7,
    'mango & grapes': 9,
    Cherry: 7,
  },
];
const newValue = 34;
const newArray = objArray.map(item => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(item)
    .map(key => [key, newValue])
));
console.log(newArray);
```

To get the new type to be an array FoodItems too - TypeScript works best with static keys. Performing the same operation on all keys of an object to produce a new one is pretty weird, but that's your assignment here. I think the easiest way to do it would be to just assert that the `Object.fromEntries` result is of the required type:

```
const newArray = objArray.map(item => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(item)
    .map(key => [key, newValue])
) as FoodItems);
```

And then `newArray` is equivalent to `FoodItems[]`.

Unfortunately, `Object.keys` and related methods [don't return the `keyof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) the object - just `string` - so you have to either assert the type of the result (as done above) or list out each individual property (as you were doing originally).

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `'Type '{ [k: string]: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'FoodItems[]'`. I think the new array's type is different from the original? Because the type of original array is `FoodItems[]`. Thank you for the answer btw

Comment: What is FoodItems? This is the first time you've mentioned that, I don't see it in the code in the question or as one of your requirements

Comment: I'm really sorry about it. I added the type also. again really sorry for the inconvenience. I tried to provide a minimum code, to avoid distractions. but now I understand that I missed some vital parts. I think now all complete. Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Yep, I see it. See edit

Answer (score 0):

> Properties in the target object are overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key. Later sources' properties overwrite earlier ones.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```js
const objArray = [
  {
    apple: 4,
    banana: 7,
    'mango & grapes': 9,
    Cherry: 7,
  },
]

const newObj = {
    apple: 1,
    banana: 2,
    'mango & grapes': 3,
    Cherry: 4,
  }
  
  newObjArray = objArray.map(item => Object.assign(item, newObj))
  console.log(newObjArray)
```

Comment: what I need to do is assign a new value to each key of the 1st object in the array. thank you for the answer btw

Answer (score 0):

We could iterate over each obj's keys and assign new value to each key without changing object reference or creating new obj's.

```js
const objArray = [
  {
    apple: 4,
    banana: 7,
    'mango & grapes': 9,
    Cherry: 7,
  },
]

const newValue = 34;
  
  newObjArray = objArray.forEach(item => Object.keys(item)
  .forEach(key => item[key] = newValue))
  console.log(objArray)
```