# How to list all possible properties of a class in typescript

Tags: typescript, object

In my Angular application I have the istance of a class, and I need to loop through some form values and, if the form field doesn't match the possible property of the class, inserting it in a `data` object.
Here's what I arranged, that doesn't work.

```
class CustomClass {
  prop1?: string;
  prop2?: string;
}
const myObj: CustomClass = new CustomClass();
const data = {};
const formValues = {
  prop1: "should go to myObj",
  prop3: "should go to data"
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(formValues)) {
  //I want to check if key could be in CustomClass, e.g. prop1 && prop2
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    myObj[key] = value;
  } else {
    data[key] = value;
  }
}
```

I see several approaches of listing properties of an object, like `myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)`, but they don't seem to work with possible properties the object can have.
From my understanding, using `for ... in` should list even the inherited properties, but not the optionals!

Comment: Did you try `if (key in myObj) {`?

Comment: Yes, without any success

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your code to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now I get [a bunch of errors](https://tsplay.dev/Wyllnm), none of which seem to be what you're asking about.  If you do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.

Comment: @jcalz sorry I only used the code to better describe the intention, now it should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` method does not act as a type guard. So even if in runtime, we use it to ensure the given key does exist in the object, TypeScript does not acknowledge it.

The reason is essentially similar to the same explanation for `Object.keys`, see [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) and [ms/TS#12253](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) for more explanations about this design choice.

Usual workarounds include:

- Type asserting the `key`, since we now know that it as an own property, so it is now safe to use it to access a property in `myObj`:

```
if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // Type assert, now that we know it is safe
    myObj[key as keyof typeof myObj] = value; // Okay
}
```

(but beware that the type of `value` may not actually match at runtime, as explained in the above linked resources)

- Using a "type safe" replacement of `hasOwnProperty`, e.g. using [`ts-extras`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ts-extras) or the suggestion in [ms/TS#18282](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18282#issuecomment-327635002):

```
// Use a type-safe version of hasOwnProperty (which really acts as a type guard)
if (objectHasOwn(myObj, key)) {
    myObj[key] = value; // Okay
    //^? const myObj: CustomClass & Record<string, unknown>
}

// Custom implementation of hasOwnProperty as a type guard, as suggested in ms/TS#18282
function hasOwnProperty<T extends object>(obj: T, v: PropertyKey): v is keyof T {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(v)
}
if (hasOwnProperty(myObj, key)) {
    myObj[key] = value; // Okay
    //    ^? const key: keyof CustomClass
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzhARgKwKYGMYAkCGAzgPIDuAdgDTLrYwCi5MUwGhcAvnAGZQQhwARDEIBaDAA9mRQQChZWADZF2AYQCuhGP1XLC7BLLjG4YPmACMAfgBccLS3IBzANxGTZiGABMt+82BnNw4FCHItOBAAT2J0Ow0tHT12AF44cgxSOATtEF0VAAoASjcsMIiAE3wYfDsAJWxoCoAeB0CnanVyAGtyCAoAPjg0hA5S8vhuaBAANXxFdTZhxHdjT0s7QUIACwh1RQq4Jwg4bUiY9EFKVdNzAGZNnb2Do5Ozqpq5ENluLpxgMJwbZEMjkAAK5gwsCizQAKnBJDAMOQKuxUJgcAMCui7LDqAA3OwQrxQmBRADSGCiRTs+LgwHY3SpEG4cHhhhMcCgGBg6ig5BoaAAdMCSBRiWBSVECviirJvlMoHACmVwvAANpMqIE+aLAC6yFZsQxMCFyICbAKitmurYRSKK05AHonQBJOCkfBMU4nLDbbDdemsrVwMr7Q4oDD0gU5JIqagYIVOIW3LwWOAAMgzqZ8N2ArIK0WNIpB4sh0IKWvtjs5JiL6E1VINaXxtpccBdcHoUD4UDs9EUGBA5vp4EUwCwwBgiiiQKIcC9cAA5F6okvTlFJXBI1h8Joo5IzGxCACBSyN1ul21nOvd+Ql-BI3B94czoEKpIL1Gl7G8sklymAByJzvp+J5OOQ1R8lGpBTtsC6mPgUD4MOSJKueZKXteTjrp67BTF0hyAph36-vk+gAQUADsAAMACsdxypyXAYIohBRhytbGB8+CNlEzZwK2CwYG4zHyJy+bKvWwqiqCEpSpWVLVpxXGdrCm5RiopLUH0WQwMC8CkFGvT9PS8AMvY+DcBgNyctJfELoyzKsiR57SQJQmLO2nbEN0+BRDcLFsRxtkmDxfEeW2gXiSYnYAKrsQhJGiIQVlRviUInoC56yWWJLQsqpDbBO8HcvMM4Ljg7DzvgX5HOoSEVExJiSditA4AQYrkIWFxoNQVYOiptb2VqkXCd5TpwL5-mhcYLoAHpWIFCLBTWXHhaNyyeSJ0U3J2v6jmAg7Dkw1Snoac5dfJBU1XVTgNVAFTUPOhDqE4ThsEihyBJEhBOrCADKADEFgABzeODeYFrl4LlmSPXGv1SmDbN5zGhFW1th2k3TQFXFzZNJiLctrGJUNnIbU2mPjdFIRAA)